# Alphabetically permute a string

Tags: code-golf, string, permutations

### Task

Your goal, should you choose to accept it, is to write a program, that, given an input string (or array of characters), outputs every possible permutation of the letters in that string. I'm finicky with my output, so it should be sorted alphabetically, with no duplicates.

**Example:**

Input: `buzz`

Output:

```
buzz
bzuz
bzzu
ubzz
uzbz
uzzb
zbuz
zbzu
zubz
zuzb
zzbu
zzub
```

### Rules

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code wins.
- Trailing spaces on each/any line are ok
- A single newline after the last line is allowed (but no more)

Comment: Can output format be `["buzz" "bzuz" "bzzu" "ubzz" "uzbz" "uzzb" "zbuz" "zbzu" "zubz" "zuzb" "zzbu" "zzub"]`?

Comment: Sorry, as I mentioned, I'm finicky ;) output must be on separate lines, rather than in a list format

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. I just wanted to see if I could remove one byte from my CJam answer (`N*` to `p`) :-)

Comment: Can the input be an array of characters instead of a string?

Comment: Hmmm......I'll allow it

Comment: A solid first challenge!

Comment: So many builtins!

Answer (score 23):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ṢŒ!QY
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bmixZIhUVk&input=&args=J2J1enon)

#### Explanation

```
Ṣ         Sort
 Œ!       All permutations
   Q      Unique
    Y     Join by linefeeds
```

Comment: And... we have 100000 posts! Congrats!

Comment: @ETHproductions Heh! Thanks! :-)

Comment: Congrats from my side as well :) @ETHproductions how did you get to that result? I am just curious...

Comment: @geisterfurz007 Click the "share" link at the bottom of the post. That has ID of the post in the URL.

Comment: Oh so it is the 100000th post of ppcg! I thought Luis Mendo was at that number already. My bad. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: It's quite fitting for the 100000th post to solve "print sorted unique permutations of x" with code `sort(unique(permutations(x)))`

Comment: +1 only for being the 100'000th post! :)

Comment: Wait, @LuisMendo, did you just made it to PGCC history and you were not using MATL??? :( :( :( :( :P

Comment: @AnderBiguri :-D The truth is I had no idea about the post number. Anyway, MATL is [99999](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/99999/36398)

Answer (score 12):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E),  <s>4</s>  3 bytes

Updated, since an update to `œ` broke the old version,
which also saved a byte as suggested by *Magic Octopus Urn*.

```
œê»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6OTDqw7t/v@/qqo0CQA)

**Explanation**

```
œ     # get all permutations of input
 ê    # sort and remove duplicates
  »   # join list by newlines
```

Comment: `œê»` is fine for non-legacy.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: It is actually required for both versions as `œ` now returns a list of string in both.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
Y@Xu
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=WUBYdQ&input=J2J1enon)

#### Explanation

```
Y@    % Implicit input. Push 2D array of all permutations, each on a row, sorted
Xu    % Unique rows. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 10):

## [CJam](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cjam/), 5 bytes

*Thanks to [@EriktheOutgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) for a correction (`q` instead of `r`)*

```
qe!N*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@Yquin9f9/UmlVFQA)

#### Explanation

```
q        e# Read input as a string
 e!      e# Unique permutations, sorted
   N*    e# Join by newline. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 10):

### Python 3.5, 79 bytes

```python
def f(s,w=''):
 s or print(w)
 for c in sorted({*s}):t=s*1;t.remove(c);f(t,w+c)
```

A function that takes input as a list of characters and outputs by printing.

Recursively makes every distinct permutation by taking each possible next character alphabetically out of the remaining distinct characters, and appending it to the output in progress `w`. Then, we recurse with this character removed. Once the input is emptied, we print `w`.

Comment: Take in a list of chars, not a string.

Answer (score 8):

## Pyth - 5 bytes

```
jS{.p
```

[Try it online here](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=jS%7B.p&input=%22buzz%22&debug=0).

```
j        Join. Implictly joins on newlines.
 S       Sort
  {      Uniquify
   .p    All permutations, implicitly run on input.
```

Comment: Is `S` really needed?

Comment: @LuisMendo It's needed if the input isn't already sorted.

Comment: @isaacg Thanks! I just realized I need that in my Jelly answer as well

Comment: @LuisMendo whoops.

Answer (score 6):

### Haskell, 46 bytes

```
import Data.List;unlines.sort.nub.permutations
```

2 bytes saved thanks to nimi

Comment: You don't need a name for the function, so you can drop the `f=`.

Answer (score 5):

## J, 19 bytes

```
/:~@~.@:{~!@#A.&i.#
```

### Test case

```
   f =: /:~@~.@:{~!@#A.&i.#
   f 'buzz'
buzz
bzuz
bzzu
ubzz
uzbz
uzzb
zbuz
zbzu
zubz
zuzb
zzbu
zzub
```

### Explanation

This is a 4-train:

```
                     /- ~ --- /:
               /- @ -^- ~.
  /- ~ --- @: -^- {
  |
  |            /- !
--<     /- @ --^- #
  |     |
  \-----<      /- A.
        >- & --^- i.
        \- #
```

Basically:

```
/:~@~.@:{~!@#A.&i.#
          !  A.&     get permutations
           @#   i.#  of range (0..length)
        {~           map indices to chars in string
      @:             then
    ~.               unique
   @                 then
/:~                  sort
```

Comment: I think `[:~.i.@!@#A./:~` should save you a few bytes

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (Firefox 30+), <s>129</s> 124 bytes

```
f=(a,i=-1)=>a[1]?[for(x of a.sort())if(a.indexOf(x)==++i)f([...a.slice(0,i),...a.slice(i+1)]).replace(/^/gm,x)].join`
`:a[0]
```

Not too bad for a language with no permutation built-ins...

Comment: I converted this to operate on strings; despite taking 23 bytes just to sort the characters into order I still got the job done in 120 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3.5, 81 bytes:

```
from itertools import*;lambda i:'\n'.join(sorted({*map(''.join,permutations(i))}))
```

Really...81 bytes when the next longest answer is 48 bytes...*sigh*. Well, I will try this golf this more as much as I can, but golfing tips are still very much appreciated.

Also, here is the shortest solution I could get in Python 2 at **86 bytes**:

```
from itertools import*;lambda f:'\n'.join(sorted({''.join(i)for i in permutations(f)}))
```

Apparently in Python 2, `[*...]` returns a `Syntax Error`, and since `permutations` returns `itertools.permutations object at 0x...`, the next shortest way (that I know) of extracting the *unique* permutations is using `{''.join(i)for i in permutations(f)}` where `f` is the input string.

Finally, note that these are both lambda functions and thus must be called in the format `print(<Function Name>(<Input String>))`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](http://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
:pfdo~@nw
```

[Try it online!](http://brachylog.tryitonline.net/#code=OnBmZG9-QG53&input=ImJ1enoi)

#### Explanation

```
:pf         Find all outputs of p - Permute with the main Input as input
   d        Remove Duplicates
    o       Order
     ~@n    Concatenate into a single string with linebreaks as separator
        w   Write to STDOUT
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>49</s>  44 bytes

String as input

```perl6
*.comb.permutations.sort».join.squish.map: *.put
```

List of characters as input

```perl6
*.permutations.sort».join.squish.map: *.put
```

## Expanded

```perl6
*\              # Whatever lambda
# .comb\        # split into a list of characters
.permutations\  # returns a list of lists
.sort\
».join\         # join the second level lists
.squish\        # remove adjacent repeated values
.map: *.put     # print each on its own line
```

Comment: every time I see perl 6 code I wonder why I haven't installed it yet

Comment: @GabrielBenamy There is an irc bot that runs Perl 6 code on the freenode.net `#perl6` channel.

Comment: You can do `».say` instead of `.map: *.put`

Comment: @JoKing Technically `».say` is allowed to do them in any order, and at one time it was purposely done out of order.

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 5 bytes

```
pᵘoẉᵐ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@Dh1hn5D3d1Ptw64f9/paqq0iQlAA)

Find `ᵘ`nique `p`ermutations of input, s`o`rt them, `ᵐ`ap `ẉ`riteln (write with newline) over that array.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>34</s> 23 bytes

```
Print@@@Permutations@#&
```

The input must be a list of characters.

**Explanation**

```
Permutations@
```

Find all permutations of the input, sorted and duplicate-free.

```
Print@@@
```

Print them one by one.

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, <s>77</s> 85 bytes

Now sorts!

```python
import itertools as i
for a in sorted(set(i.permutations(input()))):print("".join(a))
```

Comment: To shorten this, you could do `from itertools import*` as opposed to `import itertools as i`. You'd be able to save a byte by replacing `i.permutations` by `permutations`.

Comment: Using `{*...}` instead of `set(...)` saves you two more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell v3+, 171 bytes

```
param([char[]]$x)$a,$b=$x;$a=,$a;while($b){$z,$b=$b;$a+=$a|%{0..($y=($c="$_").Length)|%{-join($c[0..$_]+$z+$c[++$_..$y])};"$z$c";"$c$z"}}$a|?{$_.length-eq$x.count}|sort -u
```

PowerShell v3 introduced the `-Unique` flag on the `Sort-Object` cmdlet, so it's a few bytes shorter than the below v2 version, since we don't need to `Select` first.

v2 version, 178 bytes:

```
param([char[]]$x)$a,$b=$x;$a=,$a;while($b){$z,$b=$b;$a+=$a|%{0..($y=($c="$_").Length)|%{-join($c[0..$_]+$z+$c[++$_..$y])};"$z$c";"$c$z"}}$a|?{$_.length-eq$x.count}|select -u|sort
```

---

PowerShell doesn't have any built-in permutations, so I borrowed my code from [Prime Factors Buddies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94323/42963) and slightly tweaked it for use here.

This is essentially three portions, which I'll expand on below.

`param([char[]]$x)$a,$b=$x;$a=,$a` Takes input `$x`, casts it as a `char`-array, strips off the first letter into `$a` and the rest into `$b`, and then recasts `$a` as an array with the comma-operator.

`while($b){$z,$b=$b;$a+=$a|%{0..($y=($c="$_").Length)|%{-join($c[0..$_]+$z+$c[++$_..$y])};"$z$c";"$c$z"}}` Loops through the remaining letters (`$b`), each iteration  taking the next letter and storing it into `$z` and leaving the remaining in `$b`, then array-concatenating onto `$a` the result of sending `$a` through its own loop -- each item of `$a` (temporarily stored into `$c`) is looped over its own `.length`, and then `$z` is inserted into every position, including prepending and appending with `$z$c` and `$c$z`. For example, for `$c = '12'` and `$z = '3'`, this will result in `'132','312','123'` being concatenated back into `$a`.

The final portion `$a|?{$_.length-eq$x.count}|select -u|sort` takes each element of `$a` and uses `Where-Object` clause to filter out only those that have the same length as the input string, then `select`s only the `-u`nique items, and finally `sort`s those alphabetically. The resulting strings are all left on the pipeline, and output via implicit `Write-Output` happens at program completion.

```
PS C:\Tools\Scripts\golfing> .\alphabetically-permute-a-string.ps1 'PPCG'
CGPP
CPGP
CPPG
GCPP
GPCP
GPPC
PCGP
PCPG
PGCP
PGPC
PPCG
PPGC
```

Comment: If you are willing to go 3.0 You can change `|select -u|sort` to `|sort -u`. Pretty sure 2.0 does not have that.

Comment: @Matt Thanks - you're correct. That was introduced in v3.

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 119 bytes

```
f=(s,t=[...s].sort().join``,p=``)=>t?t.replace(/./g,(c,i)=>t.indexOf(c)==i?f(s,t.slice(0,i)+t.slice(i+1),p+c):``):p+`\n`
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Port of @ETHproduction's answer to use strings instead of arrays. Reversing the output, or moving the trailing newline to the beginning, saves 3 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

### R, 113 bytes

```
x=scan(,"");cat(sort(unique(apply(matrix(x[permute:::allPerms(l<-length(x))],,l),1,paste,collapse=""))),sep="\n")
```

Reads input from stdin. The `permute` package is assumed to be installed in order to call the `allPerms` function.

Will add an explanation as I get home from work.

Answer (score 1):

## Java <s>302</s> 300 bytes

```
import java.util.*;class M{public static void main(String[]a){for(Object s:p(new TreeSet(),"",a[0]))System.out.println(s);}static Set p(Set l,String p,String s){int n=s.length(),i=0;if(n>1)for(;i<n;p(l,p+s.charAt(i),s.substring(0,i)+s.substring(++i,n)));else if(!l.contains(p+=s))l.add(p);return l;}}
```

**Ungolfed & test code:**

[Try it here.](https://ideone.com/PiGtqI)

```
import java.util.*;
class M{
  static Set p(Set l, String p, String s){
    int n = s.length(),
        i = 0;
    if(n > 1){
      for(; i < n; p(l, p + s.charAt(i), s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(++i, n)));
    } else if(!l.contains(p+=s)){
      l.add(p);
    }
    return l;
  }
  
  public static void main(String[] a){
    for(Object s : p(new TreeSet(), "", a[0])){
      System.out.println(s);
    }
  }
}
```

**Input:** test
**Output:**

```
estt
etst
etts
sett
stet
stte
test
tets
tset
tste
ttes
ttse
```

Comment: The permutations are supposed to be alphabetically sorted

Comment: @Ikaros Thanks, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

### Racket 82 bytes

```
(sort(remove-duplicates(map list->string(permutations(string->list s)))) string<?)
```

Ungolfed:

```
(define(f s)
 (sort
  (remove-duplicates
   (map
    list->string
    (permutations
     (string->list s))))
  string<?))
```

Testing:

```
(f "buzz")
```

Ouput:

```
'("buzz" "bzuz" "bzzu" "ubzz" "uzbz" "uzzb" "zbuz" "zbzu" "zubz" "zuzb" "zzbu" "zzub")
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

```
uOP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v9Q/4P///0mlVVUA)

No Unicode!

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 69 Bytes

```
{(it as List).permutations().unique().sort().each{println it.join()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 51 bytes

```
->s{puts s.chars.permutation.map(&:join).uniq.sort}
```

Comment: how to we can run it?

Comment: `puts s.chars.permutation().map(&:join).uniq` 43 Byte

Comment: That doesn't work. You need to sort the output, and you can't refer to `s` without prior definition.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](http://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 8 bytes

Golfing suggestions welcome! [Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=O2xA4pWo4pmCzqPilZRp&input=ImJ1enoi)

```
;l@╨♂Σ╔i
```

**Ungolfing**

```
     Implicit input s.
;l   Get len(s).
@╨   Get all len(s)-length permutations of s.
♂Σ   Sum them all back into strings.
╔    uniq() the list of strings.
i    Flatten the list of strings.
     Implicit print the stack, separated by newlines.
```

Answer (score 0):

### [Pip](http://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 8 bytes

7 bytes of code, +1 for `-n` flag.

```
SSUQPMa
```

Takes a string as a command-line argument. [Try it online!](http://pip.tryitonline.net/#code=U1NVUVBNYQ&input=&args=LW4+YnV6eg)

Pip's scanner breaks runs of uppercase letters into two-letter chunks. So this code is `SS UQ PM a`--i.e. `SortString(UniQue(PerMutations(a)))`, with `a` being the command-line arg. The `-n` flag ensures the result list is newline-separated. That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 14 bytes

**Solution:**

```
?x@<x@:prm@#x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/377CwabCwaqgKNdBucJKKam0qkrp/38A)

**Explanation:**

Use the built-in permutation function, `prm`, to generate permutations of length of the input, apply these permutations to the input, sort alphabetically and then take distinct values.

```
?x@<x@:prm@#x: / the solution
            x: / store input as x
           #   / count length of x
       prm@    / apply (@) function prm
    x@:        / apply indices to x and save result back into x
   <           / indices to sort ascending
 x@            / apply to x
?              / take distint
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-R`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 bytes

```
á â n
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LVI&code=4SDiIG4&input=Inp6dWIi)

Comment: `û` is the centre pas method; I think you meant `n` ;)

Comment: @Shaggy I just put `sort` in the searchbar in your interpreter and clicked the first one I found. But `á` seems to give each permutation in alphabetic order already

Comment: Oop, that's a typo; should be `ü`. I'll fix it tomorrow. The permutations of "buzz" happen to be sorted because the word itself is - try it with "zzub" instead, for example.

Comment: @Shaggy, I see, updated answer with `n` (it's easier to type)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-MList::Util=uniq -F`, 68 bytes

```perl
$"=',';@b=sort@F;map{say if"@b"eq join$",sort/./g}uniq glob"{@b}"x@b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FyVZdR93aIcm2OL@oxMHNOjexoLo4sVIhM03JIUkptVAhKz8zT0VJByStr6efXlual1mokJ6Tn6RU7ZBUq1ThkPT/f1JpVdW//IKSzPy84v@6vqZ6BoYGQNons7jEyiq0JDPHFqTrv64bAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>132</s> 128 bytes

```cpp
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;int main(){string s;for(cin>>s;cout<<s<<endl,next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end()););}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FctBCoMwEEDRfU8hdJOgtQdI8ColGafpgBmDMwGx9Oyprt//UMojAbR2J4alzugjqTxFZ@j78TPdqhCnjkNGKQGwO8URa5cDsbFf0e1yce91M0A8TeJgreq9eI88LwPjrq@CW64alFY2MkZM1zzIeBbGWmfdr7VYj@MP)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clam](https://github.com/dylanrenwick/Clam), 9 bytes

```
p_D`Sq@~Q
```

### Explanation

```
          - Implicit Q = first input
p         - Print...
 _        - Sorted ascending value (alphabetical order)
  D       - Distinct from...
   `Sq    - Joined (map(q=>q.join(""))
      @~Q - Permutations of Q
```