# Get thee behind me Satan-Prime!

Tags: code-golf, primes

## Satan-Primes

who are they?
they are `Primes` containing `666`
these are Satan-Primes:`[46663,266677,666599,666683,616669]`
these are **NOT** :`[462667,665669,36363631,555]`

## Plot

*Every number bigger than 6661 has Satan-Primes behind him*

## The Challenge

Given an integer `n>6661` find the Satan-Prime **behind (or equal) and closest** to itself.

## Examples

Integer `n=30000` has 3 Satan-Primes(SP) behind it:`[6661, 16661, 26669]`.
Your code must return `26669` which is the closest behind it

## Test Cases

Input->Output

```
6662->6661    
10000->6661    
66697->66697 (a SP returns himself)  
328765->326663  
678987->676661
969696->966677
```

## Rules

Yor code should work for any `n` in the range of your language.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins!

Comment: define "about a minute." Is it +- 30 seconds? I personally think that 30 minutes and a minute don't differ that much... Also bonuses are generally frowned upon... also I think this *might* have been better as an `output the nth satan prime` challenge...

Comment: ok ok people... bonus will be removed...

Comment: Hope you don't mind the edit I made to the challenge title.

Comment: @Shaggy What point does the title change serve...?

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Rhyming and appearing archaic, I presume.

Answer (score 8):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 9 bytes

```
>ͻ:D+6S÷
```

Explanation:

```
>         Increment input
 ͻ        Start infinite loop
  :        Previous prime
   D       Duplicate
    +6     Push 666
      S    Swap
          See if 666 is a substring of the top of the stack
        ÷  If true, break
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/3@7sbisXbbPgD3Onzjq8/f9/MzMzS3MA)

Comment: So there's really a builtin to push "66 prepended to a digit"? O_O Neim has progressed.

Comment: How does `+6` push 666? Or is Neim just that metal?

Comment: @RobertFraser Apparently `+x` means 612 + character code of `x`. The code of `6` happens to be 54, so 612+54=666.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Well, Neim can represent all three digits numbers and a few four digits using two bytes.

Comment: @Okx Well, what are the builtins for that?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer [`'\+*` = `100,356,612,868`](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim/blob/master/src/main/java/me/okx/neim/token/TokenManager.java#L135) (plus the ordinal of the following char that is)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh thanks! Docs are missing stuff...

Comment: there's actually a little ascii satan in the code... ͻ:D

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 82 bytes

```
Last@Select[Prime@Range@PrimePi@#,!FreeQ[Subsequences[IntegerDigits@#],{6,6,6}]&]&
```

Comment: Wait, you mean there isn't a built-in for this one?

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

Saved 10% thanks to @Dennis!

```
ÆRwÐf666Ṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1D54QlpZmZmD3eu@m99uF3lUdMabyCO/P8/GihqpGNoAAQ6QKaluY6xkYW5mamOmbmFpYW5jqUZCMYCAA)

#### Explanation

```
ÆR          # All primes in range [2, input]
   Ðf      # Keep those which satisfy
  w        # truthy if y is in x
     666   #           ^ (this is y)
        Ṫ  # Tail (take the last element)
```

Comment: Alternative: `ÆRẇ@Ðf666Ṁ`

Comment: I love that the Tail (right after 666) looks like a cross.

Comment: `w` should work instead of `ẇ@`.

Comment: @Dennis s/sh/w/ of course it works :p

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 1 byte with help from Dave*.

Memory errors for `969696` and anything higher on my machine, but it is fine if it is given enough memory.

```
ef&/`T*3\6P_TS
```

**[Try it here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef%26%2F%60T%2a3%5C6P_TS&input=10000&test_suite_input=6662%0A10000%0A66697%0A76667%0A328765&debug=0) or check out the [Test Suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef%26%2F%60T%2a3%5C6P_TS&input=6662-%3E6661++++%0A10000-%3E6661++++%0A66697-%3E66697+%28a+SP+returns+himself%29++%0A328765-%3E326663++%0A678987-%3E676661%0A969696-%3E966677&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=6662%0A10000%0A66697%0A328765&debug=0)**

---

## How?

```
ef&/`T*3\6P_TSQ - Full program, with implicit input (Q) at the end

             SQ - Range [1,Q]
 f              - Filter.
          P_T   - Is prime?
  &             - And
   /`T*3\6      - It contains 666.
e               - Last element.
                - Implicitly output the result.
```

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 14 bytes

```
ef/`T*\63fP_TS
```

**[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ef%2F%60T%2a%5C63fP_TS&input=10000&debug=0)**

Comment: 14 bytes: `ef&/\`T*3\6P_TS`

Comment: I added the ending Q by mistake, its 14

Comment: `"666"` is a less efficient way to describe the string 666 that `*3\6`

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + Core Utils, <strike>51</strike> 49 Bytes

```
seq $1|tac|factor|awk 'NF==2&&/666/&&!a--&&$0=$2'
```

Takes command line argument. Can be quite slow with larger numbers.

Comment: This outputs all "satan primes" down to 6661, but it should only be printing the closest one below the input: [try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi1UEHFsKYkMbkmLTG5JL@oJrE8W0Hdz83W1khNTd/MzExfTU3FwFbFSP3////GRhbmZqYA). One fix would be to just add `|head -1` to the end.

Comment: @JustinMariner lol, whoops, fixed it

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 11 bytes

```
ƒNpN666å*iN
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//2CS/Aj8zM7PDS7Uy/f7/NzYAAgA)

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>64</s> <s>62</s> <s>61</s> 53 bytes

```
#//.i_/;!PrimeQ@i||ToString@i~StringFreeQ~"666":>i-1&
```

*-1 byte thanks to @KellyLowder*

*-8 bytes (wow) thanks to @Notatree*

### Explanation

Take an input. We decrement it under these conditions:

- the input is not prime, OR
- the digits of the inputs does not contain three 6s in a row.

We repeat that until a Satan prime is reached.

Comment: Very nice.  You can lose one more _  at the end since a prime can't end in 6.

Comment: @KellyLowder good point

Comment: This is even shorter with strings: `#//.i_/;!PrimeQ@i||ToString@i~StringFreeQ~"666":>i-1&`

Comment: @Notatree wow! nice!

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 14 bytes

```
õ fj w æ_sø666
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=9SBmaiB3IOZfc/g2NjY=&input=OTY5Njk2)

Seeing as there *was* a 50% time-based bonus: Completes test case `969696` in under half a second.

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of integer `U`.

```
õ
```

Generate an array of integers from `1` to `U`.

```
fj
```

Filter (`f`) primes.

```
w
```

Reverse.

```
æ_
```

Return the first element that returns a truthy value (in this case `1`) when passed through a function that checks if ...

```
sø666
```

The integer converted to a string (`s`) contains (`ø`) 666.

---

### Faster Alternative, 15 bytes

Again, seeing as there was originally a time-based bonus, here's an alternative, and much faster, solution which I can't seem to golf any further.

```
U-@j *U´sø666}a
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VS1AaiAqVbRz+DY2Nn1h&input=OTY5Njk2)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 47 bytes

46 bytes of code + 1 for `-p`

```perl
{$f=0|sqrt;1while$_%$f--;/666/*!$f||$_--*redo}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79aJc3WoKa4sKjE2rA8IzMnVSVeVSVNV9da38zMTF9LUSWtpkYlXldXqyg1Jb/2/38joLDlv/yCksz8vOL/ur6megaGBv91CwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 128 bytes

```powershell
param($n)function f($a){for($i=2;$a-gt1){if(!($a%$i)){$i;$a/=$i}else{$i++}}}for(){if($n-match666-and($n-eq(f $n))){$n;exit}$n--}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1RCsIwEESvUmGFhBJEPyJSepilJnYhTWqbohD27HHj55uZx6zp47Z9diHUuuKGi4Ko/RGnTCl2XgHq4tOmgMbbAGhe@aoLeXWS5gykdQGS/DICsQu7E@x7Zm7OfwjRLJin2VprMD4bu7fyndw0OQ7uS5klNVxrldXj/gM)

PowerShell doesn't have any prime factorization built-ins, so this borrows code from my answer on [Prime Factors Buddies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94323/42963).

We take input `$n`, then declare a new `function f` that calculates out the factors of input `$a`. If the input `$a` is prime, then this will return just `$a`.

The main part of the program is the infinite `for()` loop. Inside the loop, we check if `$n` `-match`es against `666` and whether `$n` is prime (i.e., `$n` matches all of the factors of `$n`). If it is, we place `$n` on the pipeline and `exit`, with implicit output. Otherwise, we decrement `$n--` and continue the loop.

Comment: Trimmed mine version down and just managed to hit half your byte count :D  - https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140539/571

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>77</strike> 76 bytes

**Edit:** -1 byte thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder)

Slow running time, runs in `O(n^2)`

```python
lambda x:max(q for q in range(x+1)if"666"in`q`*all(q%t for t in range(2,q)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzLDsIgEEXX9ismTUxAWViMPJr0S9SkqEVJKC0tC/x6hG68s7mT3HPmb/hMjibd3ZJV4@OlILajisiDnhbwYBwsyr0HFI8NNrpmjNXG9b4/KGuR34dtF/47SjzGOD3VOqzQwTUDlDSnHJKr5ORMBWcXwriQghPJyt2rYilMEW1sW@3mxbiANCp/Vv4A)

### Another 76 bytes solution

```python
lambda x:max(q*("666"in`q`*all(q%t for t in range(2,q)))for q in range(x+1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzRDoIgGIWv8yn@ubWBcRG0QNx8EnOTSopNUZALe3qCbjrn5uzbzrd@wnuxLOr2Fic1358K9mZWO3IVKjnnpbGDGyo1TcgdA@jFQwBjwSv7GhEjDmOcofvD/UQxjg@1jRu00CUJJfScQtKUglxYLfiVcFHLWhDJc/siS/Ine37frmF9UxxWb2xAGmWWtF8)

## With [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) 73 bytes

```python
lambda x:max(q for q in primerange(0,x+1)if"666"in`q`)
from sympy import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1NDsIgFITXcoqXrkBZtDU@2iY9iZoUtSiJ/JR2UU6P4MxmJpnJ5@P2cbZNarylrzSPl4R9MHKnCygXYAFtwQdt5iDte6Y1308N06pCxErbaZkYUcEZWKPxEbTxLmzH9JTrvMII1zxreVNn8Rx7wc9tJ/DCUXR9J3iPxXdSUOVTaP/vQA6ZajeqaOmMpR8)

Comment: 76 bytes: ``lambda x:max(q for q in range(x+1)if"666"in`q`*all(q%t for t in range(2,q)))`` - use `max()` instead of `[][-1]`

Answer (score 2):

## Bash + bsd-games package, 33

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @FedericoPoloni.

```bash
primes 2 $[$1+1]|grep 666|tail -1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##NYyxDsIgFEV3v@IObIakYHxA/JSmA9qnktjS8Bj777QMnrOc6TyjfNs7F1SW@orCSCuIyMIMJz2Dw816R3eQ88E7BOo@MOcLToQrtIb6H9pW0sICCzUqczXT/im89dNeY/pBmzbnldsB).

Comment: You can save 1 byte if you replace the last two commands with `tail -n1`.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni duh - can't believe I forgot `tail` here.  In fact `tail -1` is even 1 less.

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <strike>71</strike> <strike>69</strike> 64 bytes

```powershell
param($s)for(;$s-notmatch666-or(2..($s/2)|?{!($s%$_)});$s--){}$s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQ6VYMy2/SMNapVg3L78kN7EkOcPMzEwXKGSkpweU1TfSrLGvVgSyVFXiNWs1QQp1NatrVYr///9vaAAEAA)

- 328765 takes ~30 seconds on my machine, but times out the 60 second limit on Tio.run.
- 678987 takes ~1.5 minutes.
- 969696 takes ~4.5 minutes.

Comment: Clever way of doing the factors.

Answer (score 2):

## MATL, 16 bytes

```
ZqP"@V'666'Xf?@.
```

Try it at [MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=ZqP%22%40V%27666%27Xf%3F%40.&inputs=30000&version=20.4.0)

**Explanation**

```
         Implicitly grab input (n)
Zq       Compute the primes up to n (output is in increasing order)
P        Flip the array (so larger primes come first)
"        For each prime
  @V     Convert it to a string
  '666'  Push the string literal '666' to the stack
  Xf     Find the location of '666' in the prime
  ?      If it was present...
    @.   Push it to the stack and break
         Implicitly display the stack contents
```

Answer (score 2):

## C++ 389 bytes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/miller_rabin.hpp>
using namespace boost::random;typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_int Z;int main(int,char**v){mt19937 m(clock());independent_bits_engine<mt11213b,256,Z>g(m);Z n{v[1]},p;while(p++<=n)if(miller_rabin_test(p,25,g)&&p.convert_to<std::string>().find( "666" )!=-1)std::cout<<p<<" ";}
```

This is a full program!
You'll need Boost to compile it. (Or copy and paste into your favorite online C++ shell.)
Run it from the command-line giving ***n*** as argument.

Ungolfed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/miller_rabin.hpp>
using namespace boost::random;

typedef boost::multiprecision::cpp_int integer;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  mt19937 mt( clock() );
  independent_bits_engine <mt11213b, 256, integer> rng( mt );

  integer input {argv[ 1 ]};
  integer possible;

  while (possible++ <= input)
    if (
      // is_prime( possible )
      miller_rabin_test( possible, 25, rng )
    && 
      // possible has "666" in it
      (possible.convert_to <std::string> ().find( "666" ) != std::string::npos))

    std::cout << possible << " ";
}
```

Shortcuts were made in terms of random number testing. The original code started testing possible primes at 6661 and incremented by two. You'll also get a compiler warning because of that (-1) there instead of npos.

Still, this runs pretty quickly. It only took about 40 seconds to find all 214 satan primes under 1,000,000 on my old AMD Sempron 130.

:^D

Answer (score 2):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü>:Ñb/VP6─
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=813e3aa5622f565036c4&i=6662%0A10000%0A66697%0A328765%0A678987%0A969696&a=1&m=2)

Explanation (unpacked):

```
^w:pc$666$#! Full program, implicit input-parsing
^            Increment input
 w           do-while:
  :p           Previous prime
    c$         Copy and stringify
      666$     Push "666"
          #    Number of occurences
           !   Logical not
             Implicit output
```

Comment: Nice program.  Thanks for trying stax.  FYI, it's also possible to do multiple cases by using the "Separator" option like [this](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=813e3aa5622f565036c4&i=6662%0A10000%0A66697%0A328765%0A678987%0A969696&a=1&m=2)

Comment: @recursive ah, thx

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 57 bytes

```r
(a=conf.design::primes(scan():1))[which(grepl(666,a))[1]]
```

-42 bytes from Dominic Van Essen's enormous golf.

uses `grepl` to coerce values to string(since 666 cannot be considered a regex) and check for truthy values.

Runs through the array in reverse to save 2 bytes.

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + `conf.design`, <sup><s>81 78</s></sup> 99 bytes

```r
library(conf.design);function(n){a=primes(1:n)
a[max(which(grepl("666",as.character(a),fixed=T)))]}
```

[Try it on rdrr.io!](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=library(conf.design)%0Ax%3Dfunction(n)%7B%0Aa%3Dprimes(1%3An)%0Aa%5Bmax(which(grepl(%22666%22%2Cas.character(a)%2C%20fixed%3DT)))%5D%7D%0Ax(6666))

My first R solution.

+21 bytes after including library name.

A simple filter. grepl returns true at indices with 666, which returns the truthy indices, and max gets the required index of the prime.

Comment: Congratulations on your first R golf!  The good news: you can make the code shorter (58 bytes) like this ```function(n)(a=primes(1:n))[max(which(grepl("666",a,f=T)))]```, and then even shorter (52 bytes) by using ```scan()``` for input like this ```(a=primes(1:scan()))[max(which(grepl("666",a,f=T)))]``` (but I don't know how to make ```scan()``` work correctly on rdrr.io...

Comment: The bad news is that the current consensus (that I only recently learned of) is that we need to include either the code to load the library (```library(conf.design)```) or to specify the library for the function (```conf.design::primes```) in the byte-count, which brings the shortest version back up to 65 bytes: ```(a=conf.design::primes(1:scan()))[max(which(grepl("666",a,f=T)))]```.

Comment: Actually, 57 bytes: ```(a=conf.design::primes(scan():1))[which(grepl(666,a))[1]]```, by letting ```grepl``` coerce both arguments to character, leaving-out the ```fixed=TRUE``` which isn't required here (because 666 can't be mistaken for a regex), and running-through the series in reverse order, so we can take the first (```[1]```) element instead of the ```max()```.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include the right solution.

Comment: 56 bytes using ```match(T,x)``` (that always returns the first matching element) instead of ```which(x)[1]```: ```(a=conf.design::primes(scan():1))[match(T,grepl(666,a))]```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>85 83</s> 80 bytes

[Halvard's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140505/59487) is 4 bytes shorter because it's done in Python 2.

```python
lambda k:max(x for x in range(k+1)if"666"in str(x)*all(x%i for i in range(2,x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjexQqNCIS2/SKFCITNPoSgxLz1VI1vbUDMzTcnMzEwJKFZcUqRRoamVmJOjUaGaCVabiVBrpFOhqan5v6AoM69EI03D0AAIgHwA)

Give it some time, it's extremely slow because of its `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @ThePirateBay.*

```js
f=n=>/666/.test(d=n)&eval("while(n%--d);d<2")?n:f(n-1)
```

**Very** slow with large inputs. Primality test adapted from [this code golf answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/91309/69583).

### Timings

- Input `10000` took 10 seconds
- Input `328765` took 3 minutes
- Input `678987` took 9 minutes
- Input `969696` took 16 minutes

### Tests

Some of these will hang your browser for several minutes.

```js
f=n=>/666/.test(d=n)&eval("while(n%--d);d<2")?n:f(n-1)

function test(n) {
  O.value="Working..."
  setTimeout(_=>{
    let t = Date.now()
    O.value=`f(${n}) = ${f(n)} in ${(Date.now()-t)/1000}s`
  }, 10)
}
```

```html
Tests<br>
<button onclick="test(6662)">6662</button>
<button onclick="test(10000)">10000</button>
<button onclick="test(328765)">328765</button>
<button onclick="test(678987)">678987</button>
<button onclick="test(969696)">6662</button><br>
Result<br>
<input id=O type=text size=25 readonly>
```

### Faster Version, 56 bytes

Completes each test case in under a second.

```js
f=n=>/666/.test(n)&&eval("for(d=2;n%d++;);d>n")?n:f(n-1)

;[6662, 10000, 328765, 678987, 969696].forEach(n=>console.log(`f(${n}) -> ${f(n)}`))
```

Comment: You should never do that. This is code golf and the performance is totally irrelevant. I strongly suggest rolling back to your previous 55 byte answer. Also, you can reduce it to 54 bytes by replacing `d==1` with `d<2` since `n>6661`.

Comment: 52 bytes: [`f=n=>/666/.test(n)&(g=d=>n%--d?g(d):d<2)(n)?n:f(n-1)`](https://tio.run/##Dck7DoAgDADQ02jaAfwMDEbwLMYCUbEYICaeHn3rO9ZnzVva7yLyvZNNV@TTvrU6zdp0SqlOFpsLMLbgNWnDjRC0eCCcaB7xj4UnBywGrFvkHIOVIXpwMPQ/xPoB) but will throw a recursion error for larger numbers.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>67</s>, <s>66</s>, <s>58</s>, 56 bytes

Includes `+7` bytes for `-rprime`

```
->z{z.downto(1).find{|x|/666/=~x.to_s&&x.prime?}}
```

It's pretty fast, computing values up to `~2^52` in about a second and `2^64` in under 5 minutes (2011 MBP, Ruby 2.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 148 bytes

```php
<?php $p=[2];$s=[];for($i=3;$i<=$argv[1];$i++){foreach($p as $q)if($i%$q===0)continue 2;$p[]=$i;if(strpos($i,'666')!==false)$s[]=$i;}echo end($s);?>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcpBCsIwEEDRq0QYaUJd1Ba6ScceJHQRamIC0kwz1Y149hjwb9@nQKVMMwUSQGj6RQOjWbRPWULEQUOcEGx@vM21Wmxb9anm7BokkLAsYFfR1/cMOyJ2ak3bEbeXE70GMgtC1NX5yJS4bpdmHMdGnRC9fbJTwP/n69aQhNvuEljp@VZKGbraDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 35 bytes

```
my&f={/666/&&.is-prime??$_!!f $_-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtLCoAgFEW3chNx1s/oqfRbijRQCIrERhGt3eyeyeHADS7ulNJxCz89NRHVQlTbVYa4HW5ZuC0KD27L9k0DrvUG4xbTjOevL4M/I8Z8k2ibPGQ1Cp3UinqQ0kYrGPqZh/QB)

Straightforward recursive solution.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>117</strike> <strike>115</strike> 112 bytes

```cs
f=>{for(int i=f;i>1;i--){int p=1,j=2;while(j<i)if(i%j++<1)p=0;if(p>0&$"{i}".Contains("666"))return i;}return 0;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY5BS8QwEEbPza8YikrCbku7YhXS9CJ4Uljcg@eQTXRKTUqSrkjpb6@p6G2@x4N5KhTKeb1OAe07nL5D1J@cqEGGAEcykyxEGVHBxeEZXiRaykiWcHaRHiwIQBvLo/RB00dngxt0@arl@RmtpozxJD5NVrXJ2m9qByZNEKsR3Wycp4kBCsOxqzkWBZs3MIp634sD//rAQdO@RYaG4nW/27U1G0XF0xy76uYqn3HJy/Q4prJA86Zpcsa8jpO3gHz5uyq@rFvKf@Gbx6jpVkLtb@RClvX28HDf3P0A)

- 2 bytes saved by removing unnecessary braces.
- 3 bytes saved by combining `int` declarations.

I'm sure this could be made shorter; maybe by recursively calling `func f` and removing the outer `for`-loop.

#### Recursive Approach, 85 bytes

```cs
i=>{int p=1,j=2;while(j<i)if(i%j++<1)p=0;return p>0&$"{i}".Contains("666")?i:f(--i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY7BSsQwEIbPzVMMRSVht6XdQw@mqQfBk8KiB88hm@qUOC1JuiKlz15TwTkN838z85lQmNHbbQ5IH/D2E6L9ksw4HQKc2cKyEHVEA9cRL/CikbhgWRpnV@2BQAFSLM/aB8sfRwqjs@Wr1ZdnJMuFkAl8msm0iTruaAd92qHZuT1K/YaqW1IAk6qPgzrJ7090lg8tCuw53g6HQ1uLSVXS2zh7gqmr7m7yBde8TA9jMgo8b5omFw943/OiQCHXbb/@7/PuMVrec/rzWdm61VWqXw)

I'm unsure how well this approach fits within the bounds of code-golf due to having to set the `Func<int,int> f = null` first, and that `f` is called again, but not counted towards the bytes. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÅPR.Δ666å
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cGtAkN65KWZmZoeX/v9vaAAEAA) (No test suite with all test cases, because it's a bit too slow.)

**Explanation:**

```python
ÅP         # Push a list of primes below or equal to the (implicit) input-integer
  R        # Reverse this list
   .Δ      # Find the first value which is truthy for:
     666å  #  Check whether it contains "666" as substring
           # (after which the found result is output implicitly)
```

The `666` can alternatively be `Ž2ć` (compressed 666) or `Ƶé·` (compressed 333 and then doubled).

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 77 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=++n;i>1|!(n+"").contains("666");)for(i=--n;n%--i>0;);return n;}
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PZDBbsIwDIbvPIUXaVKjNhUwLW2J2svO48KRcchCmMKKixqXaWJ99i7tYLZk2b@s77d81BctjvvPwdTae3jVDq8zAIdk24M2FtbjOAlgorEiV0HpZ6F40uQMrAGhHFBU10PTTjuujGNUrlr8PEQYM8ZT0yAFto@YlJJxxafVUghU@CiEq@aKq9ZS1yKg6gc18s/dex34N5tL4/ZwCpBoQ63Dj@0ONP@77u5L1tOL9hZWgPZrPHq7uwbDZbKYh0hCW2TJ0zLP5HMis7zIs6SQY/Z8AgFsvj3ZU9p0lJ6DC9UY3akxW70RizE1/xK/PaMffgE)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{               // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int i=++n;   //  Increase the input by 1
                   //  Set `i` to this input+1 (setting `i` to anything above 1 is fine)
      i>1          //  Continue looping as long as `i` is not 0 nor 1
      |!(n+"").contains("666");)
                   //  or if `n` as String does not contain "666" as substring:
    for(i=--n;     //   Decrease `n` by 1 first
                   //   And then set `i` to this new `n`
        n%--i      //   Decrease `i` by 1 before every iteration
             >0;); //   And continue looping as long as `n` does NOT evenly divide `i`
  return n;}       //  After both loops, return the modified `n` as result
```

If `for(i=n;n%--i>0;);` results in \$i<2\$, it means \$n\$ is a prime number (note: [this prime checker](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/100149/52210) only works for \$n\geq2\$, which is fine in this case).

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 12 bytes

```
ḟo`€d666dfṗṫ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@GO@fkJj5rWpJiZmaWkPdw5/eHO1f///zc0AAIA)