# Array Factorization

Tags: code-golf, array, primes

Given an array of positive integers, output a stable array of the distinct prime factors of these integers. In other words, for each integer in the input in order, get its prime factors, sort them, and append any primes not already in the output to the output.

## Test Cases

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] -> [2,3,5,7]
[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1] -> [2,5,3,7]
[100,99,98,1,2,3,4,5] -> [2,5,3,11,7]
[541,60,19,17,22] -> [541,2,3,5,19,17,11]
[1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,45] -> [2,3,5,13,7,17]
[6,7,6,7,6,7,6,5] -> [2,3,7,5]
[1] -> []
[8] -> [2]
[] -> []
```

Output can be as an array or list of integers or strings, delimited output, or any other standard means of outputting an ordered list of numbers.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/13814#13814)

Comment: This is one of those challenges that I think is “too simple”. Almost every answer is gonna look like one of these: (a) a loop over the input, and Ye Olde Prime Factorization Code with a conditional append; (b) a chain of four built-ins. There just isn’t much room for creativity. Maybe the answers will prove me wrong, but I doubt it. There’s very little more to golf than prime factorization here, and that’s been done to death.

Comment: @Lynn it's trivial for golfing langs, but non-trivial for nearly everything else. Not sure if that's grounds for triviality here :/

Comment: Can you tell me which are "the distinct prime factors" of 1?

Comment: @Jenny_mathy there are none, therefore `[1] -> []` - `1` is not prime.

Comment: Can we output as a list of strings (i.e.: `['2', '3', '5', '13', '7', '17']`)?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `Output can be as an array or list of integers or strings`

Comment: Does the output list order matter?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma Yes. Otherwise it would just be "output the set of all prime factors of the input"

Answer (score 9):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

Outputs as a list of Strings.

```
f˜Ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/7fScwzP//4821DHUMdIx1jHVsdAxNNYxMtQxNtExMY0FAA)

## [2sable](https://github.com/Adriandmen/2sable), 3 bytes

Yes, this also works in 2sable. Also returns a list of Strings.

```
f˜Ù
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MypOTMpJ/f8/7fScwzP//482NTHUMTPQMbTUMTTXMTKKBQA)

Comment: Hah... `f U`. Love it.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 3 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to [@Zgarb](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32014/zgarb).*

```
uṁp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/v/ThzsaC////R5uaGOqYGegYWuoYmusYGcUCAA)

---

## Explanation

```
uṁp    Full program.

  p    Prime factors of each.
 ṁ     Map function over list and concatentate the result.
u      Unique.
```

Comment: `Σ†` can be `ṁ`.

Comment: @Zgarb Thanks a lot. As you can tell, it's my first Husk answer ever :)

Comment: It's nice to see new people using Husk. :)

Comment: @Zgarb It seems very nice (especially when it outgolfs Jelly :P)

Answer (score 5):

## Bash + GNU utilities, 37

- 21 bytes saved thanks to @muru (wow!)

```bash
factor|tr \  \\n|awk '!/:/&&!a[$0]++'
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0xuSS/qKakSCFGQSEmJq8msTxbQV1R30pfTU0xMVrFIFZbW/3/f1MTQy4zAy5DSy5Dcy4jIwA).

Comment: I think the `nl|sort|...` can be done using `awk`: `awk '!a[$0]++'` (print if not seen before; so order is never lost), saving 15 bytes. Then the `sed` command can be eliminated using a slightly longer `awk` one: `factor|awk '!/:/&&!a[$0]++' RS='[ \n]+'` (split records on spaces and newlines, skip records with `:`), saving another 4 bytes.

Comment: I just realised I can save another two bytes on the previous comment by using `tr`: [`factor|tr \  \\n|awk '!/:/&&!a[$0]++'`](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py0xuSS/qKakSCFGQSEmJq8msTxbQV1R30pfTU0xMVrFIFZbW/3/f1MTQy4zAy5DSy5Dcy4jIwA) (that's two spaces after the first backslash)

Comment: @muru awesome - thanks! (I wouldn't have been upset if you'd posted this as your own answer, that significantly out-golfed my original)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
{smP
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BsmP&input=%5B541%2C60%2C19%2C17%2C22%5D&debug=0)** or **[Verify all test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BsmP&input=%5B541%2C60%2C19%2C17%2C22%5D%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%0A%5B10%2C9%2C8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B100%2C99%2C98%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D%0A%5B541%2C60%2C19%2C17%2C22%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13%2C21%2C34%2C45%5D%0A%5B6%2C7%2C6%2C7%2C6%2C7%2C6%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%5D%0A%5B8%5D%0A%5B%5D&debug=0)**

Alternative: `{sPM`

---

## Explanation

```
{smP      Full program with implicit input (Q).
  m       Map over the input.
   P      Prime factors.
 s        Flatten.
{         Deduplicate.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
"@Yfvu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X8khMq2s9P//aEMDAx1LSx1LCx1DHSMdYx0THdNYAA)

Explanation:

```
"      % Loop over input
 @     % Push the array element
  Yf   % Prime factors
    v  % Concatenate entire stack vertically (does nothing the first iteration)
     u % Stably get distinct (unique, in MATLAB terminology) elements. Does so every loop but this is code golf, not fastest code.
```

Interesting MATL tidbits: generally, all functions apply to vectors (arrays) just as easily. But in this case, the number of factors is variable for each input, and Matlab and by extension MATL generally only deal in square matrices, so I had to use a for loop `"`.

Furthermore, MATL has two main concatenation operators: `h` and `v`, horizontal and vertical concatenation. Their behaviour differs significantly: `v` concatenates the entire stack, even if it has only one element like in our first iteration. `h` takes exactly two elements and will fail if only one is present, making it unsuitable for this application.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḋᵐ↔ᵐcd
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7odbJzxqmwIkk1P@/482NNCx1LHQMdcx0zHVMdEx1jHSMYz9HwUA)**

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḋᵐoᵐcd
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7odbJ@QDcXLK///RhgY6ljoWOuY6ZjqmOiY6xjpGOoax/6MA)**

---

### Explanation

```
ḋᵐ       Map  with prime decomposition (which returns the factors in reverse order).
  ↔ᵐ     Reverse each (or oᵐ - order each).
    c    Concatenate (flatten).
     d   Deduplicate.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

1 byte thanks to clap.

```
ÆfFQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYwrEsIwEIY9Z/lFNt2kyQXwSCYTCYLpBZAgwKNwXADNFN3hIO1Flu3yEPuY73/sNl23FxlO2@VKhvN0vL8u4/Oqdz32t@nwECmF4NGAERDRIiGDXMWikNM3KYoqsVo86MNVyMgJ/@SMAxOiA2m8hffm/DqC1pDmCQ2DzR2t9zeGrDzNq9Y3)

Comment: Not surprised .

Comment: Don't think you need to force vectorization on `Æf`, so you can probably drop a byte with `ÆfFQ`

Comment: @clap I'm an idiot...

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 102 bytes

```powershell
param($x)$a=@();$x|%{$a+=(2..($z=$_)|?{!($z%$_)-and'1'*$_-match'^(?!(..+)\1+$)..'}|sort)};$a|select -u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcZLCoMwEADQq1QYyUwdA/EDBRE9SKkMNuDCH2qp1Hj21Ld68/S1y9rZvvd@lkUGhJ1AyhqpgN2FB0hUYqI1wq@Ehlx1BFfDq7GMb2XUHZp4kK3t1AurALWO6GkiIK3V6dZp2egsQNxqe9tut/jjva/RsOGEU875wSblxHCacZbTHw)

*(Borrows factorization idea from TessellatingHeckler's [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/140539/42963) over on "Get thee behind me Satan-Prime!")*

Takes input as a literal array `$x`. Creates a new empty array `$a`. Loops over `$x`. Each iteration we loop from `2` up to the current number, checking whether that is a factor `-and` is prime, then `|sort` the output of that, and append it to `$a`. When we're done going through `$x`, we then output `$a` but `|select` only the `-u`nique numbers thereof. This exploits the fact that the uniqueify goes left-to-right, keeping the first occurrence, which matches the problem description. Those numbers are left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 11 bytes

```
{:mfe__&1-}
```

Function that takes array of ints and outputs array of ints.

[Test Version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q'%2CSer~%7B%3Amfe__%261-%7D~'%2C*&input=%5B6%2C7%2C6%2C7%2C6%2C7%2C6%2C5%5D)

Comment: How would I differentiate output with multiple characters? At least for my (online) testing it outputs a string, not an array of ints.

Comment: As a function, it's output datatype is an array of ints. CJam automatically prints ths stack, and it prints arrays w/o delimters. I don't know if that's good enough for your purposes. If you want delimeters add `S*` inside the close bracket.

Comment: I believe stack-based langs can output by ToS anyway, so it's fine, I was just wondering. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), 4 bytes

```
ḍ¦_u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz//@GO3kPL4kv/pz5qm/g/2tTEUMHMQMHQUsHQXMHIKBYA)

---

## Explanation

```
ḍ¦      Prime factors of each.
  _     Flatten the list.
   u    Remove duplicate elements.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
MPs}
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=MPs%7D&input=%5B541%2C60%2C19%2C17%2C22%5D&warnings=0&hex=0)

---

## Explanation

```
MP       Prime factors of each.
  s      Flatten.
   }     Deduplicate.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
Select[DeleteDuplicates[First/@FactorInteger@#~Flatten~1],#>1&]&
```

**input**

> [{100, 99, 98, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]

Comment: `Select[#&@@@Gather[#&@@@Join@@FactorInteger@#],#>1&]&`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ethproductions/japt/), 6 bytes

```
mk c â
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=bWsgYyDi&input=WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwLDExLDEyLDEzXQotUQ==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of array `U`. Map (`m`) over it, getting the factors (`k`) of each element. Flatten (`c`), get the unique elements (`â`) and implicitly output.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 77 bytes

```haskell
import Data.List
x!y|y>x=[]|x`mod`y<1=y:(x`div`y)!y|1<2=x!(y+1)
nub.((!2)=<<)
```

#### Explanation:

- the `x!y` operator returns a list of all prime factors of `x` that are greater than or equal to `y`
- the `(!2)` function returns a list of all prime factors of its argument
- the function on the last line implements the required functionality

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##bY9di4JAFIbv51ecZC@UzkZjfiVOsMvuQmzQRZcROKKhbGWbtin4393Tl1l0YAY9z3l4z8Qy@4lWq7pO1tt0l8OHzGVvkmQ5KzplVY4KMV9Uhb9OQ7/0uChdtfDD5M8vNcLc00XRUcsu19hSbPZBT1U7uiY8T6vXMtmAgDBlQLWEOUcdB2igiRba6OAQeX8Bfhan@1X4HvkwP3IT7UVj9GnIoWGL2gZBHfmjYVK7bZAyxKGDTdozgfOWYxocrT5y2sdGXb@fP8LzWmfO@S0Lr4jSaDeOAwMN89mTCJN6i7ROb7qeJ4pNzSbnHjd950FrwOM8Y9dfcF1QP39BIszi9ABSAzECCa@XazwFVWOy7QdQgRQigFMJ2O7zWb6bbECZfisM7quCNI@j3SHJovboCyhfb@OJCwp0u6Bml2j6VuCcBEHUhoHG6n8)

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
ḋᵐoᵐcd
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//@GO7odbJ@QDcXLK///RhgY6ljoWOuY6ZjqmOiY6xjpGOoax/6MA)

#### Explanation

```
ḋᵐ         Map prime decomposition
  oᵐ       Map order
    c      Concatenate
     d     Remove duplicates
```

Comment: Fais for `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`. It should be `[2, 5, 3, 7]`, not `[2, 3, 5, 7]`

Comment: You can fix that for +1 byte: `ḋᵐoᵐcd`

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thanks, fixed. Pretty non-sensical requirement imo though.

Comment: It's not really non-sensical, as it is a *tiny, tiny* bit less trivial. I posted my own answer too, but I used reversed first instead of order. Not sure why the prime factors are generated in reverse order?

Comment: @Fatalize well - the challenge is not "sorted distinct prime factors of the list," it's "iterate through the list and append distinct prime factors."

Answer (score 2):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 3 bytes

Yet another 3-byter (thanks to languages with auto-vectorization).

```
m{U
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr/P7c69P//aEMDHUsdCx1zHTMdUx0THWMdIx3DWAA)**

---

## Explanation

```
m      Prime factors. Auto-vectorizes over the input.
 {     Flatten.
  U    Uniquify.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>128 125</s> 116 bytes

This is a pure Python solution. No packages. *Thanks to Halvard for saving 9 bytes.*

```python
def f(l):y=[k for i in l for k in range(2,i+1)if i%k<1*all(k%x for x in range(2,k))];print(sorted({*y},key=y.index))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpLDsIgEADQq8ymCVMnRlr/2pM0XTQBdAKBBllAjGfH2JW7t3hLSc/g@1qVNmCEw2sZRgsmRGBgD26l/THO/qFFR7yRyAa4sXfZzs4J2@R15f9lEafbEtkn8QoxaSXebfmQ1WUoW/ZKZ8RqxCh3dKEznehIB9pTTx3JCesX)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>133 127</s> 126 bytes

```python
def f(l):y=sum([[k for k in range(2,i+1)if i%k<1*all(k%x for x in range(2,k))]for i in l],[]);print sorted(set(y),key=y.index)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcpLCsMgEADQq8wmMNMOpab/30nERSDaDloTjIV4eku66vbxxpJfQ2xr7a0Dh4Gu5TF93qi1Bzck8CARUhefFluWtSJxII2/q1UXAvpm/q35f3kis6AsGAxrQ7cxScwwDSnbHiebsRB7Wx5lI7G3M1WHWm35wmc@8ZEPvOcdt6wM1S8)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>142 138</s> 134 bytes

```python
l=input();r=[]
for i in sum([[k for k in range(2,i+1)if i%k<1*all(k%x for x in range(2,k))]for i in l],[]):r+=[i]*(i not in r)
print r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcw5DsMgEEDR3qeYxhJjTxHIvnASROEiTkYQQARLzumJ7CJK@/X006c8Y1C1es0hTUXgNWtjmzFmYOAA7@kljHGwBLeEPITHXSjiXiKPwK27yW7wXrh2XtX8rxyi/b28JWPxkntt2HaCIcSyYmxS5lAg12rkhs50oiMdaE872pIiab8)

Very surprised there was no Python answer yet. Working on golfing.

Comment: [116 bytes Python 3](https://tio.run/##TcpLDsIgEADQq8ymCVMnRlr/2pM0XTQBdAKBBllAjGfH2JW7t3hLSc/g@1qVNmCEw2sZRgsmRGBgD26l/THO/qFFR7yRyAa4sXfZzs4J2@R15f9lEafbEtkn8QoxaSXebfmQ1WUoW/ZKZ8RqxCh3dKEznehIB9pTTx3JCesX)

Comment: @HalvardHummel Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/SatansSon/Deorst), 16 bytes

```
EDkE]EQFPkl1FeE_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f/f1SXbNdY10C0gO8fQLdU1/v//aEMDHUsdCx1zHTMdUx0THWMdIx3DWAA)

Done with help from @Mr.Xcoder. This is way too long for a pseudogolfing language.

#### How it works

```
EDkE]EQFPkl1FeE_ - Full program, implicit input: [1,2,3,4,5]

ED               - Get divisors. Vectorizes. STACK = [[1], [1,2], [1,3], [1,2,4], [1,5]]
  k              - Turn off sorting for the next command
   E]            - Flatten the stack. STACK = [1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 4, 1, 5]
     EQ          - Deduplicate stack in place. STACK = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
       FP        - Filter by primality 1 is considered prime. STACK = [1, 2, 3, 5]
         k       - Turn off sorting for the next command
          l1     - Push 1. STACK = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1]
            Fe   - Filter elements that are equal to the last element. STACK = [2, 3, 5]
              E_ - Output the whole stack
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Deorst](https://github.com/SatansSon/Deorst), 16 bytes

```
EDkE]l1FeFPkEQE_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0nNLyou@f/f1SXbNTbH0C3VLSDbNdA1/v//aEMDHUsdCx1zHTMdUx0THWMdIx3DWAA)

Done with help from @cairdcoinheringaahing in the [Deorst chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64858/deorst) (note that the solutions are different).

---

## Explanation

```
EDkE]l1FeFPkEQE_   Full program.

ED                 Push the list of divisors of each element.
  k                Prevent the stack from reordering.
   E]              Flatten the stack.
     l1Fe          Remove 1s from the stack (because caird rushed and made 1 prime!) - Should be removed in future language releases.
         FP        Keep the primes.
           k       Prevent the stack from reordering.
            EQ     Deduplicate.
              E_   Output the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 3 bytes

```
ǐfU
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyIiLCIiLCLHkGZVIiwiIiwiWzU0MSw2MCwxOSwxNywyMl0iXQ==)

```
ǐ   # prime factors
 f  # flattened
  U # uniquified
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rprime`, 50 bytes

```ruby
->x,*r{x.map{_1.prime_division.map{|b,|r|=[b]}};r}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TZBfaoNAEIfJq6dYQiFtGcUx_qWYt55iEYlE2wWTympSJXqSvpTSPvVE7Wk662rxYWHm229_M-zbpzxn3Tdfm7KS4pivk48i_jo3hRn-OOauhXt5ba3jvrqmaI1GehAXUYuX00j7DHrZxzxLhuFBDtPLx9dnUebsKW9qg7XQsZjdpFZdlaJhG2bu2MZgkmDB88u-ZG1isIpJYDKOFbjt7oz8dNBh77-rFUdwYAsueOBDACFEgHaigrjiHgSJwdEmHNK1T8Al7ADOjketdkiKIArhP3GpII6W5yL4NiBNCcBxtKGgHqY5osqDGVIiTUTYuuB6y9UIk6xi_XG3-SykgBrK0oCqcLqicmL6K_4A)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyke](https://github.com/muddyfish/PYKE), 4 bytes

```
mPs}
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=mPs%7D&input=%5B10%2C9%2C8%2C7%2C6%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D&warnings=1&hex=0)

```
mP   -   map(factorise, input)
  s  -  sum(^)
   } - uniquify(^)
```

Comment: Ouch, I ninja'd you badly - Good we have different approaches :)

Comment: :P One byte difference. I think it's allowed though or at least according to the last consensus I read

Comment: Yes, duplicate answers, even byte-to-byte are allowed

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, 61 bytes

```matlab
a=input('');b=[];for c=a(a>1)b=[b setdiff(factor(c),b)];end;b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DchLCoAgEADQq7RTYRYpfQixi4iL8QduNGzq@tZbvhYI3zQGmlKvhzhjQntjnc6tT8Egx1OKP/x0J4olZ54xUOs8CPDC6VSj9mPYdZGwzSAPkDso5T4)

Answer (score 1):

## MY, 17 bytes

```
⎕Ḋḟ’⊢f(‘53ǵ'ƒf(ū←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9tef//4o6V4biK4bif4oCZ4oqiZijigJg1M8e1J8aSZijFq@KGkP//WzEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEwXQ)

### How?

- `⎕` evaluated input
- `Ḋ` divisors (vectorizes/vecifies)
- `ḟ` flatten
- `’⊢f(‘` decrement, filter, increment (removes `1`)
- `53ǵ'` the string `'P'` in MY's codepage, which is primality testing. Sadly `0x35=53` is the 16th prime number, and there's not a command for pushing `16` to the stack >_< .
- `ƒ` as a function
- `f(` filter by that
- `ū` uniquify
- `←` output

Answer (score 1):

## C++, 118 bytes

```
[](auto n){decltype(n)r;for(int m:n)for(int i=1,j;i++<m;){j=m%i;for(int x:r)j|=!(i%x);if(!j)r.push_back(i);}return r;}
```

Needs to be passed the input in a `std::vector<int>`, returns another `std::vector<int>` for output.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 10 bytes

```
~.(#~*),q:
```

I'm sure some clever J-er could make this shorter.

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, <s>88</s> <s>119</s> 103 bytes

Here we go. With the correct sorting.

```python
def f(l,s=[]):[s.append(x) for x in sum([list(primefac(i)) for i in l],[]) if x not in s];print s
from primefac import*
```

Apperently I can't get it to work on TIO, because the package is not supported. It does run on my machine tho. Here are my Test outputs:

```
f([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],[])     #[2, 3, 5, 7]
f([10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1],[])     #[2, 5, 3, 7]
f([100,99,98,1,2,3,4,5],[])      #[2, 5, 3, 11, 7]
f([541,60,19,17,22],[])          #[541, 2, 3, 5, 19, 17, 11]
f([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,45],[])  #[2, 3, 5, 13, 7, 17]
f([6,7,6,7,6,7,6,5],[])          #[2, 3, 7, 5]
f([1],[])                        #[]
f([8],[])                        #[2]
f([],[])                         #[]
```

Somehow I was not able to make the function as a lambda-function. Whenever i try to return the list comprehention, it returns [None, None, ...]. If i am just overlooking something, could someone point that mistake out? Thanks for the feedback!

---

Edit:

Using Mr. Xcoders sorting algorithm I could cut down the code by 16 bytes. Thank you for that part.

```
from primefac import*
def f(l):a=sum([list(primefac(i))for i in l],[]);print sorted(set(a),key=a.index)
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be correct. The second test case should output `[2, 5, 3, 7]`. The order of the outputs matters.

Comment: `sorted(set().union(*map(primefac,l)))`

Comment: The order of the outputs is important. Re-read the explanation, or look at other answers - I don't really know how else to explain it.

Comment: @Stephen. Updated routine, with correct output. It took me a while until i noticed the differences in each line. Focus while reading helps a lot.

Comment: @Simon save three bytes by getting rid of spaces after parens - `s.append(x) for` -> `s.append(x)for`, `primefac(i)) for` -> `primefac(i))for`, `[]) if`-> `[])if`

Comment: You can save 1 byte: `def f(l,s=[]):[s.append(x)for x in sum([list(primefac(i))for i in l],[])if~-(x in s)];print s`

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 7 bytes

```
&(p)u=;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fTaNAs9Tb1vr///@G/43@G/83@W/63@y/@X@L/5b/DQ0A)

Oh look, it's *basically* a chain of 4 built-ins

### Explanation

```
&(p)u=;  Implicit input from commandline args
 (.)     Sandbox loop, sandboxes each item in a separate stack and runs the
         code within the loop.
&        Append the entire sandboxed stack when loop ends, rather than only the
         top of stack after each iteration
  p      Prime factors
    u    Unique
     =   Print stack
      ;  Suppress implicit output
```

## [Braingolf v2](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 5 bytes

```javascript
&pu=;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1TxZc9tG0s/UrxgpskGIhynZzkFZ8ic7TspVa8e1rtoXmgmHIChBIgEEB22Xwu@ve7t7bgCUSK@zVZuH0Jjp6enpe2Z6dM1XPA@yKC16cTILvwRJnBcszZIgzHN2xrLwzzLKwrYnmzz/dE/AzJ3uOfXIrj9yPg@h19v3FPQfWbgKs5xa/9@05tEijAtsPDSNl1kYzj5j40PTuExm0TwCFNA@ogm6GmlXIeqqwWM9TtL9On5fZFF8iaO9Dx@8LvMOvDFSvOCw0Be/vklmObvda9GwrAyKJGv72NAqrqK8v@KLEokfwZjWem@vxWez9hIAWDRn7X2CueI5NPnMDOinZX4FbadsvdfKwjwsECerYsReMRg6s7Aos5jlBS/CPo0h0p7baKM4WJSzkEYM2Zwv8hCRrM1y3hc8uKmuJ4qjIuKLfyGOhrXZ3eyvv8xaaRUAlXeRrKwQY3Hhxec0TObU57OzMxBZTmz2BEhrERasWKaAHEFOsQn/oRjZas2TjLURKoK2wSn8PMMBfZDmZXEF352OREUDBUMRILji2UvQ2IuiHfk@4QIuttYsBGawRtoO4nI5DbMDnyka8Jfo0IP2L7KMf@5HOf2KwSjRLPnIXmUZMHHyksdewUD@oLS3CLD2WJEgZ4KbfSa4tyxB96YhE9zoMo7YugwWK2josmlZsMukYIe3Np3rCVqR4K1ktSMi4gGINOBF23T4egkOsKUwcgjNoYSapGKKLguSMpZCRVGA0pWLQsuoSUQ0wpYO9q@gnzC6yppfRXPU@6FjGDC7kJqYTQh2RU0oR2kFopMobqVhePNfoXgUjR1iRxbdQi977ahz7I93on@vdRmtQqmOinAx@Zm0dvBxwosox0boaPaaCQqeFPwmbNPSAMnxbngJTjjqKhg2E4zUQ6dTeFiwCjVvjT2nhgGICbkk@VuXIXZKZtc0ktYInFvxTJAIk8EKZ@G0vJRurys/X8cz8P9DNoCGPCmzIByyEtrmURzOoC1KRV/4KSrMULLZfAhqgx8SZMmjmNyn@FwkSSo/CQxMaQZ@EtyqbEDODFkcfpRRpCtd/RtqV1NFMgDZk4tvz0O68oCn4cz08tmKx7gKcN74nQJw8Vv8iugXbetTwZokzQVjMLANGZja2bn20PtCfGp6X8YXFFE1xJzJSOLIXRLmS1fGOuDjYRrtcRwoVAYgDeUGJHvfITWRQ07EOuyYnSuVE6KSamPTRtbJF6wCaHt9xERKuiLetCdvw08FQwgW5eBX7YEjgh6vWZtc9tqf@IYDQgtG8iMd95WhWjBR2umoZR04TL6HizX@3zJJ78GL8DKKY2Sq4O0B5AkutOInJggmRm0WzIGRC/k4NZPEFiTLFBgbDg@E65XdigsiVAmetmqE6FXdyTUbl@9ASzSeZ7XaXJOKg16NuPx/rvKgQpBXuMgEmi67Rp/X1W7oGEd/vIJEUKjZNXj9Bi1jDx@ymmpcj/tLXgRX7UejQe@n8SNfBgk9Y@esaRAt5Zo0g7y@AJGma/NMKRFmWThSaYfCr2g7ZwMrPKmVpRx89muQlAIXnEUEbymdgHzlLX8ruqvpyltIMjjaUjSTycc@Ji4K1dqb6KAljS43VleVMcUb41eNn5ZRJ4OhQmP68yxZvpTm2udpuvjcjsvFostUEtJS2pf5yrL@cCyr5gMaqdFxCkANG499OXQyEhY//hBPtHHILuoZDcbriSFHmj2Rc1bzphtjIclM@qGR9j1EMGgWxLWzc2/kdVScvE6iuO11Pb/jjT1ffX6IPX89nvgmj70DrcUHwkkr9G0LOt3WT4kuK8JYnYSpozFlZfxbGmYctxMn0NUyEyh34r2NFnwWBSxdlJCuYOaCpn8y0Fly3/PvdSQnA7EWmoPXJpm8SWJrkllSThc4y@EtX/cn96PnYIXcmkHuEs6N8emcknLuLJyVQdhuc8jcCQ4RTB03OnknVyp2BUKoBwB24K8BzeGtwLg2bNiCTjFGidVHYfS@ShjLKLal0TveSRq94@2kIWfJy2mR8aBQEmHoDFhU5OFivp10ejtKh9Latt8kp952cup9azkdfZ2cAE0EztKI6ngw2M10cMCW4tKT5X@WPNvNgI7@UwM62k4wR99aMI@@SjCzaBXNQiOWpzvJ5Ol2AlGT0K@2nunnnWzn0beynTe8uOrPYQOUEdapv424Hn1rcf3@VeIKP6VJTEeCth19jSltbU1myoxH@ddK7@jobxHf0dGW8vv9W8vvwdf5wWRWOvnD8e6i29IJqpnoH8nXyu3B3yK2B1tK7cG3ltr5tsnjDlm64fxKr0ARmhUsmTsU35Xs9stYHCva6fqzb0ayc3B5J@VhPNuJbnWOp4nuNxBN@wu8YDAHcV/B5Z/LdBEFvLAITuJtKLWPP4jGbm1bNkJtHd9DzYnemnE6f9f7RrxcmLpNvusF/oG3T8UVj9kJGGG4zDXpXRZdxgmlKon0JcobmNOjtcWG9x9h86mNmoO8Dm@n6/sZIJaoeTDQPLhr0IBs53gr2GOCPdkK9oRgH28F@5hgn2wF@4Rgn24F@5Rgv98K9nuC/WEr2B8I9setYH8k2J@2gv2JYBc13V2E8X2Wb46xq15XHjAok@@CMkHTult1t3cRBgO0Ws0ag@PxvbnoJWzS8zDlAB8lsYmSu8VIK0LS2Uw9ct3jIsThxkqDE4OJOnS4q36RiNMgiHM5eCNYgqTKmCc2Kx@1ZtCWsNHhrcCBhyECXF4niGaadIaT6pOxmboDbNoCqusvCKVOjPu5phu00Hu0Q7ljENayLIj/uFjxSSegwY1vBfgcvDBaO5JHlKc4o7gvoIuFdurXdKZCg1qBPafWoXyzDokTt28kWy0y8MBoAUJgeNROKUsOze2Vr3ePSmZ2p5SRI4Xsv0Q@JWHo/8/sFIv@ic3JEog4YquKfv4axkgRBC0BJM9QMdGCb8gSw@JjCB5lIEPLqrZ@hGta979q2gc68V4qoK0eOgEwNRT33etFEFc/UX2GGPEc6Bu6GmV8HEZohaDOWrxVVYSNlR7aALab0Xdn5kzcuiWSM1MOpFA6KcvLLCRW4@qFKXK1lsNb@nUDN52nY7MyhVWNp9vzDCZ9Ldmm0Xc0Z4CFvWPg4bFOajT8Mzy0r4@22cx64nrCGXfeCOqgGpw6mUxUBOTllY8HrijgOmNUj@JNUOONLrTZcKyt77Dkt1AOcw6O05zp0Ur0vusuvIsFSBWmgQwOYVTgjJNeknqOqegqDpNvh9mluCATq1XzykBh8Emb28WHO1pO4SnQ91epvgdzVvusvtZKQ6@3KehqEHNTJrXfFloF9rRyFaB4qvjCFwsmzbTCEM8wRGNrZopFmOGNZmQtEqFXbcNuWVzNtSO236QCz5mqQ8Fb8nuC8ukGn6M9oEZs@R/0PLIEYzP/lAmpK5Hl9jc6VofcDtoaYrWTA/ptrocq1dluy3Z8p/9pchs7uBtnYjWkYYP35n@MLZ3/wJtuy5N/7nZ7tsF6CdW7pmvN/N7jB@KrHfzV4ZHsMTmmFSW8l8ky5aIGzw4eI1mrJjNqBQ25SQ0O0Cow5@CqTVVsr/4sAY@sRQJQH40dI@Ogab@08Txqu@MoYl/6dyaIQO8y/IVjfWROKXprhw1EucuJ033Z3TZxy1aKpio3weF68aQ0aehTZklfo2jsw6gIa7li2IRJ568otQIVQrpVDlUCxbIcvR@5JRx38EepzT@SJBWngZAFcqyOjNZGE2XBB1ZkvZSlEYPtij7sogq2uZSDSjJEHetIlbC29HQip7VLTCXsWMNioyGPqjn0p0wNrPIceR6Baz5TLS1a/ZBFXfkdxrOhKBqRLWuBxuUZnkPOYRbFNYRfq42I5LyuZBMZOH4qgCmkaDfi32udhJnCFpLmeBdln0dZXmxWZqoDpCq2Sg0XLYaqSkJZxkWY5FKQvRJz9TxRND870wU0FYyi8sk5C7f4oapRG3ItQgCuzMowpcQqWEZVrCYW22kKFQEhUJ8kbXP4uWsv4O1eqmJDvmhHXYv94hQWfMJ4myNhtRXFuLvvcO7hQ2o8l2mS9rnhrqRsfyCsiOF1Uqb1Jjw6ZlOXuFc7EkfUUJy/sLKI03r3i4Ykw/hOCbIp0XDRDBrGXqjtkoJTFY@6@M3Qc9HAS4WmIRiYgS82D3zRNFCTeKEUdl8R@aJSmGnVAOrgcy2Cz7UKPhc6@lyb0n0zx@h6bOGHrwbca0tJdFWgFv6wXhc4wppco3ymQrc/jxbgSNBPn7OgT7aNIoh8U4CHB0LuTYTZjKos6RfyrDjcc0b2Zabibs60MrKPPBe1uiy/icQtBNEQLHipcNlugXCG4rhoTcXPp3t78zIOCJud/ZCLhMwHD4Tx5jLGnzRZfObiKmXLUj5Rv6fYFNPBpGuDSCPl2TgTGuT@hq2BdCV6C4JMxY0KjiNV01GTqN0V1bEvVkmZ22gw1hjFotXThrXLr4pf0JqheYQo3iWQyQLX4fd0z040ENxONLbNM@5JM6zM4bmHsUt@hPbHK0@XoEoiZDSuZR9/eVaSZ0im5EN/yuTDyj3Egu2CVDsNWDdONfRQNBZbzky8lZy0ESISkUTg8wdR0UrnrzKB0HkOjgWrVihcBYTthepwa/pFaiTW0d1TLzGGRsptSOgxW6q5Bcp/8Jte2@jTR223RFuuE1DA3WFtYfHEkhqBky4DBRb8olEadj1hWOLvE44JHRIDxbkNFc9EelOngxIgy9EoUvatNjG79i@wzTq83UQqwHrkxZCmELd@ijxiBJ311fxazT81oTU9Q9uLrR2D1PXmGdjbpyLj4tUGWhc4rwyQfZKF4DSzVT5PbzwszywCSlb13KIAmUrM5bs/8HuzMMv6H7OogC2dnATYMPr5xa/jc@ZZ0vEY/OfB2tNQH3Fbj0tAqy2ipUDxSDJbf4hBMOR99FpNcbNaSjVj1nXo1rsbesXoWwu1lpGUhVyGKJm2OWvvzMW2VU7K7aA@3RTPm7aSvL6NJIT4OoqQ0eaxgoieOVqB26bR3mm3jQfGKU@k352LXvWQS/vbI6QI9peGjJg9wG1rJJyicWuxe7sTs0cy2LckbmH7kS6UltFNlIw7MHRJq9dHHZUFyRs/61KOCMQ3OSpy2beEkqHGVeE67X6ZluGjolYgjwnEO0QpNwzUC1Fk0IpEjLoByzndY8zi1jNmByNy3yg02ucTk27IST9gJ@TNoY8YlLrU6manqQJzU4e5IRhq7nQ08kg90HDeyzUsvrYNC8SsA4kxMoKrvLFzRMPpXIykId/A/LOktzb9fv/AcrYH78VjMbtt8iF2Xw@hfXfRR5Ga25CvxZNZeXZD2dSQVcr/hTAcF0/eVspLejh8mHZH9qCc8NicndmuqXJT9PqdoSJK15DJ4HdAz58C@xHVwHefQrk4SWDESnzI0Q4I0L6QolVDkLr3aQK9aTBOMMKrlAFmO/p705Mwwx3rcdlea28jE8ws9oMG8@jnrooP8/7G8szy3bY62Vjwuw42xJ7bqntwDjdwqLgVAaZ5h7eISz3AETDYQlsdYwFqW/EOf/AWjZgxi3I@XYTi9HYt3we2PXxCYmn3q09hUJJFqBOQ/QO/wVSkfHG@6hsmyfON5z02x/VzMUzuq0/vzav1wLeZbN6vBWbhiNO8@a8PVSy9mFGZtIIkLbcVWpfSBZU6Pol5aHTX3F3I029LBpufq@Emg5jX1bqsXlg3BP07lMsdIfnvM/v5YXVzI@cVbp2OpJI0HwVjaQXQUklUk5QiX038F9kl5A3wPx2VSbHV3uexDM9RnJb4ZkwFaCtxgMFYEqJxtHK6rMY7g8t@Xk6FkNvgQ0/02zoOzPV6K2@4Z84oyZ4t9tp7EjkgNwMMiboQyJ3vRF4u1t/KmdHVB3OvY/FYzvHpYKxVzMpwbRKB0xz3IGJOxS4R7Lh6t2fg10LsMhI0XeQ9syThN5dRmJsECitaUPYFaFVOmjQrsYPlyTeQv@MjSDbuHOp3kNZxArFB1HIxTx8dcHFPovIUvFnhToEWb7jmHRk6Ox3rYqaWAzRPf//s3I11u1JgPz@nqISPBr88TMuz0y@T0z3dJkOWUQ7Iy9w3pz065jZWV@b8MhT6RhxuVECUz/7eyyTLwqAQQ0CxDm/VngBYsRrho@Znc9w38GV4zkZJSlvcMUwJGU/OphkHipLFHDR5FtI9D6c9WxRb4xrR9iCVxEE21g1oZxHSuPgsHnoVVzjRcgmb3d4CJtv7TQwH6nur1irMpgn@0RbyxTn@JQ15RMOE9cNGB4TC8OwMEEV4FQD7NrwQAKeXA478O/lyH3Y6@IYaNt46zoHbuWLfydqFPvtZGGSO@@LHGFXihP68DT6zmZH9qmVjVKVrZ5A42oPNDmONjymTcGRrDkFsqd6JB5Kdx3qL5vD9ZCz@VElvfmBMs5mUJz5zJ1Q3L4vwLcgUnaKN@bFIHZXOzjH28NkvAP3@cxy01bAu88pi3vtRHE6a6ODQIHL1J77vBuzmlURyJXrqBrJ2m2cT/80UOua5YfzOaUSs0GFYoqoXqbt/DCYpFzNSKuSm1Iz9if7TFXZOqz3F6Z7Yn4gvgP3ypbf6cgz7scfsCXvKvmc/sB/ZT@x48G8)

Braingolf's v2 interpreter doesn't have the "sandbox loop" `(.)` implemented yet, however due to more consistent modifier behavior, it's not needed for this challenge, as the greedy `&` modifier works directly on the prime factors `p` instruction, causing it to factorize every item on the stack.

Comment: [Fails for `[10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1]`.](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fTaNAs9Tb1vr///@GBv8t/1v8N/9v9t/0v8l/4/9G/w0B) - The order matters: you should return `[2, 5, 3, 7]` instead of `[2, 3, 5, 7]`.

Comment: You can [fix that for -1 byte though](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@/9fTaNAs9TW@v///4YG/y3/W/w3/2/23/S/yX/j/0b/DQE). Since `K` only makes harm here.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh right yeah, didn't realise they were supposed to be in order of occurrence, not ascending order. Fixed

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 5 bytes

```
♂y♂i╔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8///RzKZKIM58NHXK///RhgY6CpY6ChY6CuY6CmY6CqY6CiY6CsY6CkY6CoaxAA)

Explanation:

```
♂y♂i╔
♂y     prime factors of each element
  ♂i   flatten
    ╔  deduplicate (stable)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 4 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
∪∘∊⍭
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn//1HHqkcdMx51dD3qXfs/7VHbhEe9fY/6pnr6P@pqPrTe@FHbRCAvOMgZSIZ4eAb/T1MwVDBSMFYwUTBVMFMwV7BQsFQwNOACChsAWRZAETOgjAlQhZGCIVgYKG6pYGmB0AcUNTUxVDAzUDAE6jVXMDICqYPKmwLNMARqNlQwNlEwAak1A5sJwyARkLkWAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.primes.factors`, 32 bytes

```
[ [ factors ] map-flat members ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHBTsMwDIbve4qfB1jVZE3XgsQVceGCOE0cwuRBRNpGSTiMac9e3LTVViGEpRzi/7N/Wz7ofex8//L8@PRwi0bHj8x501DIDkkJ2HeNM5Z89hWNNdFQwCf5lizeqSWvrfnW0XRtQKAY4DzFeOQebcTdanWCgMQGBRRKbFGhhshxBscN1vc4JVmxdB7gnPWKPyWnChYk1y9hxdkZZrpGXV15JHYJCzHxqhAocwieYAspJ/aKH4BxmpHhyuSDOc1OPJLApkAxeC02EMNcYrQq0wrzU7@tZNpCTf0v8jImeICq/yCZsL@gS69@hx3m477yyd36YHVEQ80bDam@Rquds0dkfH1L2vc/)

- `factors` Get the prime factors of a number.
- `map-flat` Apply a quotation to each member of a sequence, collecting the (non-scalar) results in a flat sequence of the same length.
- `members` Remove duplicates.