# Prime Factoral Roots

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, primes

Inspired by digital roots, the prime factoral root of a number is the number that emerges when you take the prime factors of a number, add them together, and repeat the process on the resulting number, continuing until you end up with a prime number (which has itself as its only prime factor, and is thus its own prime factoral root).  The prime factoral root of 4 is 4, as 2*2=2+2, and this is the only non-prime prime factoral root of an integer greater than 1 (which is another special case, as it has no prime factors).  The OEIS sequence formed by prime factoral roots is [A029908](http://oeis.org/A029908).

For example, the prime factoral root of 24 is:

```
24=2*2*2*3

2+2+2+3=9=3*3

3+3=6=2*3

2+3=5, and the only prime factor of 5 is 5.  Therefore, the prime factoral root of 24 is 5.
```

### Your Task:

Write a program or function that finds the prime factoral root of an input integer.

### Input:

An integer, input through any reasonable method, between 2 and the largest integer your language will support (inclusive).  Specifically choosing a language that has an unreasonably low maximum integer size is not allowed (and also violates [this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8245/69331))

### Output:

An integer, the prime factoral root of the input.

### Test Cases:

```
4   -> 4
24  -> 5
11  -> 11
250 -> 17
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins!

Comment: Can you add `4` in the test cases, since it's an exception and it's easy to forget about it while testing an answer?

Comment: Do we have to output 1 for 1?

Comment: @someone according to the linked OEIS sequence, it should output 0 for 1

Comment: @someone The challenge states that the input will be at least 2.

Comment: @someone Sorry for being off for a while. As Martin said, the challenge specifically says that the input will be greater than one, and therefore behavior when the input is 1 is undefined.

Comment: The name of this challenge seems like someone just took a bunch of random math terms and shoved them together.

Comment: I know.  It makes sense when you read the question, but not really before that.

Answer (score 19):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 61 bytes

```hs
import Data.Numbers.Primes
until=<<((==)=<<)$sum.primeFactors
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/PzO3IL@oRMElsSRRz680Nym1qFgvoCgzN7WYK822NK8kM8fWxkZDw9ZWE0hrqhSX5uoVgKTdEpNL8ouK/@cmZuYp2CoAxfJKFFQUchMLFNIUoo1MdBQMDXUUjEwNYv8DAA)

#### Explanation

`until=<<((==)=<<)` takes a function `f` and applies it to input `x` until a fix point is reached, that is `f x` equals `x`. `primeFactors` returns the list of prime factors of a number, `sum` yields the sum of a list of numbers.

*But wait, why does* `until=<<((==)=<<)` *the job and looks so weird?*

If we assume `f=sum.primeFactors`, a more natural definition  would be `until(\x->f x==x)f`, because `until` takes a predicate (a function which returns a boolean), a function which has the same input and return type (e.g. `Int -> Int`) and value of this type, and then applies the function to the value until the predicate is fulfilled.

`until(\x->f x==x)f` is the same as `until(\x->(==)(f x)x)f`, and as it holds that `g (h x) x` is the same as `(g=<<h)x`, we get `until(\x->((==)=<<f)x)f`. After [Eta conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion), this becomes `until((==)=<<f)f`. But if we now treat `(==)=<<` as a function which is applied to `f`, we can see that `until(((==)=<<)f)f` is again of the form `g (h x) x`, with `g=until`, `h=((==)=<<)` and `x=f`, so it can be rewritten to `(until=<<((==)=<<))f`. Using the `$` operator to get rid of the outer parentheses and substituting `f` with `sum.primeFactors` yields the solution from above.

Comment: `=<<((==)=<<)$` Whaaaaaat.

Comment: @icrieverytim I added an explanation. Feel free to ask in the [Haskell chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men) if you have further questions on how this sorcery works.

Answer (score 16):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 3 bytes

```
FÒO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f7fAk////jUwNAA)

**Explanations:**

```
FÒO   
F    Loops <input> times + 1
 Ò   List of prime factors w/ duplicates
  O  Total sum of the list
     -- implicit output
```

Comment: This seems to fail for `4`.

Comment: @Shaggy fixed while saving 2 bytes

Comment: Does this make anyone trying to beat this a FÒO-fighter?

Comment: At least it wasn't FOObar.

Answer (score 5):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ω(Σp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//3ynxrnFBf///zcyAQA)

Explanation:

```
ω(   -- apply the following function until the result no longer changes (fixpoint)
  Σ  -- sum
   p -- the list of primefactors
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 3 bytes

```
usP
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=usP&input=250&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
usPGQ The trailing GQ is implicit
  PG  Get prime factors
 s    Sum
u   Q Repeat until returned value no longer unique starting with the input
```

Comment: Did you forget to update your explanation?

Comment: @MCMastery No, the code and the explanation are the same. `The trailing GQ is implicit`

Comment: @MCMastery what i cri everytim said

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>175</s> <s>144</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> <s>139</s> 101 bytes

```java
n->{for(int i=n;i-->0;)n=f(n,2);return n;};int f(int n,int d){return n>1?n%d<1?f(n/d,2)+d:f(n,d+1):0;}
```

-38 bytes porting *@ovs*' Python answer, so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVDLboMwELz3K1aRKtnCUEyTCy7kC5pLjmkOLjaVU7IgY1JVyN9ObdJW2of2MaPZvcibTPtB40V9Lk0nxxFepcH5AcCg07aVjYZDLNcGNCRGpCJ0fPBgB0CoYMG0ntvernNToTBpWueCYtUSZAUVVrvJIqDwIq60dyIWo6Lz37Tme3xUL3wfUE8q4BJVRgKVcFrmwi8Aw/TemQZGJ11It94ouAbJ5OiswY/TGSS96/1XU6L@iupP57lgz2zLdoxzVmxZscs9XXcBjt@j09esn1w2BCLXITHJpnxzmyTC41cIzTALH6C/5/vlBw)

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int i=n;i-->0;)//  Loop the input `n` amount of times:
    n=f(n,2);        //   Change `n` that many times by calling the recursive method
                     //   with n,2 as parameters
  return n;}         //  Then return the potentially modified `n` as result

int f(int n,int d){  // Separated method with 2 integer parameters & integer return
                     // (`d` is 2 when we initially call this recursive-method)
  return n>1?        //  If input `n` is larger than 1:
          n%d<1?     //   If `n` is divisible by `d`:
           f(n/d     //    Divide `n` by `d`
             ,2)     //    Do a recursive call with n/d,2 as parameters
                +d   //    And add `d` to its result
          :          //   Else:
           f(n,d+1)  //    Do a recursive-call with the next `d` by using n,d+1 as
                     //    parameters
         :           //  Else:
          0;}        //   Simply return 0
```

**Original <s>175</s> <s>144</s> <s>142</s> <s>141</s> 139 bytes answer:**

```java
n->{for(int i,t=n,x;;n=t){for(i=2;i<t;)t=t%i++<1?0:t;if(t>1|n<5)return n;for(t=0,i=1;i++<n;)for(;n%i<1;t+=x)for(n/=x=i;x>9;x/=10)t+=x%10;}}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Nevay*
-2 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##PVBBbsJADLzzCgsJKasskKXkUJylLygXjpTDNoTKFByUGJqK5u3pbkBItmWPR9aMD@7qxuW54MPuu8uPrq7h3RHfBgDEUlR7lxewCmMPQB6Fygo90vr0UYsTymEFDBY6Hi9v@7LqaaTFsm4Q2Yq6o3aGlAkqsTKiOM7MW7IQpH0kS/PHWaqqQi4VA2Ogi000WYOByagChDyizKDEtulnntrGEjbLV2ym1iQqbEYmwbbtcODlnS@fRy/vofJa0g5O3mG0lor4a7MFp@72nqoXXPwEs5vtzeiZftFznWrj27mepUmrejbA@reW4jQpLzI5@1Ny5Iji4eJDhjFP/J/U40lt9w8)

```java
n->{                 // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int i,         //  Index-integer `i`
          t=n,       //  Temp integer `t`, starting at the input `n`
          x;         //  Temp integer `x`
      ;              //  Loop indefinitely:
      n=t){          //    After every iteration, replace `n` with the value `t`
    for(i=2;i<t;)    //   Inner loop `i` in the range [2,t):
      t=t%i++<1?     //    If `t` is divisible by `i`:
         0           //     Set `t` to 0
        :            //    Else:
         t;          //     Leave `t` the same
    if(t>1           //   If `t` is not 0 or 1 (it means it's a prime),
       |n<5)         //   or if `n` is below 5 (for edge-cases n=1 and n=4)
      return n;      //    Return `n` as result
    for(t=0,         //   Reset `t` to 0
        i=1;         //   Reset `i` to 1
        i++<n;)      //   Inner loop `i` in the range (2,n]:
      for(;n%i<1;    //    Inner loop as long as `n` is divisible by `i`:
          t+=x)      //      After every iteration: Increase `t` by `x`
        for(n/=x=i;  //     Reset `x` to `i`
                     //     And divide `n` by `i`
            x>9;     //     Inner loop as long as `x` contains more than 1 digit:
            x/=10)   //       After every iteration, remove the trailing digit of `x`
          t+=x%10;}} //      Increase `t` with the trailing digit of `x`
```

Comment: +1 for bothering to write an explanation as verbose as if this was a golfing language.

Comment: @someone Thanks! Since someone asked me about an explanation of a Java answer of mine once in the past, I've been adding them to all my answers. :)

Comment: `i,t=n,x` looks like it belongs in Python, haha

Comment: @ETHproductions Hehe, too bad I still have to add the leading `int ` (unlike Python). ;)

Comment: You can use `i++<n` instead of `++i<=n`.

Comment: Why are you summing digits of some number?

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d=2:n>1and(n%d and f(n,d+1)or d+f(n/d))
i=input()
exec'i=f(i);'*i
print i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1RCsIwEET/9xRLQJpYQRPan0o8hReo3YQu1G0JKerpY/o1zGN4s/3yvIor00rBK6VK9Mv4ftGIciHvBnnYUUjLibAmRl1xa82akNparmQMsGfZ9qwNhG@YGvZRs7k3Z4YtsWTkUsXwmXkJ@Ex7GADxWOJxWjpwHVgLrr/9AQ)

Comment: This may be a pretty dumb question, but how does `f=lambda n,d=2:n>1and(n%d and f(n,d+1)or d+f(n/d))` work? I've never programmed in Python (mainly Java and C#), so I'm unsure what the result of this function is. Does this function modify the input `n` and return it afterwards, or is it similar to a boolean where `n>1and(n%d and f(n,d+1)or d+f(n/d))` is either 0 or 1, or 0 or `n`, or something else? I'm trying to visualize how a port of this would look like in Java/C#, but I'm unable to because I don't really understand Python lambdas like this in general.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen this is equivalent to `n>1 ? (n%d!=0 ? f(n, d+1) : d+f(n/d)) : n>1`. In general terms `x and y` is equivalent to `x ? y : x`. `x and y or z` is equivalent to `x ? y : z` in most cases.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen a Java port would be something like `f=(n,d=2)->n>1?n%d>0?f(n,d+1):d+f(n/d):0`.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks for the explanation, now it makes a lot more sense. And I remember `x and y` being `x ? y : x` from JavaScript as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 30 bytes

```
{+`(\1|\b11+?\B)+$
$1;$#1$*
;
```

Input and output in [unary](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5343/can-numeric-input-output-be-in-unary).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qkaCnzaWi9b9aO0EjxrAmJsnQUNs@xklTW4VLxdBaRdlQRYvLmuu/pnsCl95/Iy5jLhMuUy5DQy4jEy4jUwMA) (Performs decimal/unary conversion for convenience.)

#### Explanation

```
{+`(\1|\b11+?\B)+$
$1;$#1$*
```

The `{` instructs Retina to run the entire program in a loop until a full pass fails to modify the string, i.e. until a fixed point is reached. Consequently, the program itself computes one step of summing the prime factors of the current value.

This stage itself computes the prime factorisation of the input. The `+` is similar to `{` but loops only this stage until it stops changing the string. The regex tries to match the final run of `1`s by repeatedly matching the same substring (i.e. the factor). The way this is done is a bit convoluted due to the forward reference `\1`. On the first iteration, group `1` hasn't captured anything yet, so `\1` fails unconditionally. Instead, we have to match `\b11+?\B` which is the smallest possible substring that starts at the beginning of the run, contains at least two `1`s and doesn't cover the entire run. Subsequent iterations will not be able to use this alternative again, due to the `\b`. So on all further iterations, we're matching `\1`, i.e. the same substring over and over again. This process has to hit the end of the string exactly (`$`) to make sure we've captured and actual divisor. The benefit of using this somewhat tricky approach is that group `1` will have been used exactly **n/d** times, i.e. what remains after dividing out the divisor **d**.

We replace this match with **d** (`$1`), a separating `;` and **n/d** (`$#1$*`, which inserts `$#1` copies of `1`, where `$#1` is the number of captures made by group `1`).

This process stops once the final run in the string is itself a prime, because then the regex no longer matches.

```
;
```

All we need to do to sum the primes is to remove all the separators.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ÆfS$¡
```

Explanations:

```
Æf    list of prime factors
  S   sum
   $¡ repeat n times
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1qwyqGF////NzI1AAA)

Comment: [5 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1qwyqGF////NzI1AAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
·ΘoΣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9D2czPyzy3@/9/I1OA/AA)

**Explanation:**

```
·Θ    evaluate the block until the result returned has already been seen
   Σ  sum
  o   the full prime factorization
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 7 bytes

```
⌠w♂πΣ⌡Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8//9Rz4LyRzObzjecW/yoZ2Hk//9GJgA)

Explanation:

```
⌠w♂πΣ⌡Y
⌠    ⌡Y  do this until output stops changing (fixed-point combinator)
 w         factor into [prime, exponent] pairs
  ♂π       product of each pair
    Σ      sum of products
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [pracma](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pracma/pracma.pdf), 53 bytes

```r
function(n){for(i in 1:n)n=sum(pracma::factors(n))
n}
```

[Try it online! (r-fiddle)](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=EgzwI0sK&version=1)

R doesn't have a prime factors builtin, but numerous packages (`pracma`, `numbers`, etc.) do, so I picked a conveniently short one.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

*Uses [scottinet's idea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144401/36398) of looping more times than needed. Thanks also to [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy) for a pointing out a mistake, now corrected.*

```
t:"Yfs
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v8RKKTKt@P9/I1MDAA)

#### Explanation

```
t       % Take input (implicit). Duplicate
:"      % Do the following that many times
  Yf    %   Array of prime factors
  s     %   Sum of array
        % End (implicit). Display (implicit)
```

Comment: This seems to fail for `4`.

Comment: @Shaggy Thanks! Working on that

Comment: @Shaggy Solved now

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

This answer uses one of Jelly's many prime factorization builtins, and the quick for `repeat until the results are no longer unique`.

```
ÆfSµÐL
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9wW1rwoa2HJ/j8///fyAQA)**

Comment: I think [you've been outgolfed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144400/66833) but, given your approach, I'm uncertain whether that answer works

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing I've just checked his answer (or rather, the Python equivalent) from 1 to 100000 and it works. I think `1` is the only case where the number of steps needed is equal to `n` (which is fine; with `1` we only need to run it once), and there don't seem to be any cases where the number of steps is greater than `n` (i.e. there don't seem to be any counterexamples). Ah well, I've been outgolfed :D

Comment: Well, it happens. Although +1 for being the exact same code I thought of when I saw this challenge

Comment: The sum of prime factors of n is always less than or equal to n, which makes it pretty easy to prove that n is always more than enough.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 124 bytes

```powershell
function f($a){for($i=2;$a-gt1){if(!($a%$i)){$i;$a/=$i}else{$i++}}}
for($x=$args[0];$l-ne$x){$l=$x;$x=(f($x))-join'+'|iex}$x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYzBCgIhFEX3fUXBi/Eh0jTQSvySaCGh0wvR0IkemN9u0vLec@59pY/L5eFC6N2/432jFPdegMXqUxZAZtFg1bqdsZIXh0GOQIgVaPQnA9RcKG5EKVtru/@IDdi8lut80xBUdMDDDwZYDyTGOyOqZ6I4yelLjhtw7325zD8)

PowerShell doesn't have any prime factorization built-ins, so this uses code from my answer on [Prime Factors Buddies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94323/42963) (the top line) to perform the factorization calculations.

The second line is the meat of this program. We take input from `$args` into `$x`, then `for` loop until `$l` is `-n`ot`e`qual to `$x`. (The first iteration, `$l` is `$null` and `$x` is an integer, so we'll loop at least once).

Inside the loop, we set our `$l = $x` to determine if we've hit the end of the loop or not. Then we get the factors of `$x` with `f($x)`, `-join` those together with `+` and `|iex` them (short for `Invoke-Expression` and similar to `eval`). That's stored back into `$x`. Thus, we've hit the "end" where the prime factorization summed together is back to itself. Then, we simply place `$x` on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
#//.x_:>Tr[1##&@@@FactorInteger@x]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcy7CsIwFADQ3a8IDXTxah/oUmm5iAqCgkO3EErsQ4NtAkmGQOm3x@6HMwn3la0NtWG@eUjreFGeR93@2NyVFzn1ykqtLPoFau3EyGrxHnt29c6I1jEPcpt2HGYJT6mwWzjnp81QBpoke98U1fpmlMaIeFu9Nnfl@k9v0PM4vIxUjlEgEdlVJAIyIOUxSZDM@QFIlgHJj@kS/g)

(Mathics does not support `Tr`. I have to implement it manually)

Comment: `1##&` is short for `Times` and `FixedPoint` can almost always be shortened with `//.`: `#//.x_:>Tr[1##&@@@FactorInteger@x]&`

Comment: @MartinEnder Thanks! I should have already known about `Times`, but I've not known about the `FixedPoint` trick.

Comment: Your code is written in Mathematica. This is not a Mathics function. You should either change the language name to Mathematica or Tr to Total

Comment: @{no one} Sorry, language name (Mathics) was a mistake. {i cri evritime} fixed that.

Comment: FYI, [I opened a PR to add `Tr` to Mathics a while back](https://github.com/mathics/Mathics/pull/710).

Comment: @Mego The current implementation wouldn't actually help here, because this (and most uses of `Tr` in code golf) relies on the generalisation to vectors.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 63 bytes

```ruby
->n{n.times{n=n.prime_division.map{|x|x.reduce:*}.sum};n}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOk@vJDM3tbg6zzZPr6AIyIxPySzLLM7Mz9PLTSyorqmoqdArSk0pTU610qrVKy7NrbXOq/1fUFpSrKBkYqWgXJ0WbRJbq8QFETGCChkhiRkaQsQMDZHUmRpAFZoaAEX//8svKAFaWfxftwjsCAA)

Uses the `-rprime` flag for +6 bytes to make use of [Prime#prime_division](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-prime_division).

`prime_division` returns pairs of `[prime, exponent]` (for example, for 24 we have the factors `[2, 2, 2, 3]` so it gives `[[2, 3], [3, 1]]`) so in each step we just multiply the members of those pairs together and sum the results.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), 63 bytes

```js
f=n=>(q=(p=(m,x)=>m<x?0:m%x?p(m,x+1):x+p(m/x,x))(n,2))^n?f(q):q
```

```html
<input id=i type=number min=0 value=0 oninput="o.innerText=f(i.value)">
<p id=o></p>
```

### Ungolfed:

```js
f=n=>(                  // Recursive function `f`
    p=(m,x=2)=>(        //   Recursive function `p`, used to sum prime factors
        m<x?            //     If m (the number to be factored) is less than x (the current
            0           //     iteration), return 0
        :m%x?           //     Else if m doesn't divide x
            p(m,x+1)    //     run the next iteration
        :               //     Else (if m divides x)
            x+p(m/x,x)  //     Divide m by x and repeat the current iteration
    ),
    q=p(n),             //   Set q to the sum of the prime factors of n
    q^n?                //   If q != n then
        f(q)            //     repeat f with q
    :                   //   else
        q               //     return q
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 33 bytes

```
[ [ factors Σ ] to-fixed-point ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeal5mcn5IK4RQUZeamFuulgZUVKyTn5yZl5iWC2QVFqSUllUAFeSUKxamFpal5yanFCtZc1QomCkYmCoaGCkamBgq1/6MVohVg@s8tVohVKMnXTcusSE3RLcgH6Y39n5tYoFBckpicrfcfAA)

- `to-fixed-point` Apply a quotation to an object until it stops changing.
- `factors Σ` Sum of prime factors.