# Find a Fixed Point

Tags: code-golf, math, integer, functional-programming

Given an integer \$x_1\$ and some [black box function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877) \$f: ℤ → ℤ\$ find a fixed point of \$f\$ in the sequence defined by \$x_{k+1} := f(x_k)\$.

#### Details

- A value \$x\$ is said to be a fixed point of \$f\$ if \$x = f(x)\$.

For instance if \$f(x) = \text{round}(\frac{x}{\pi})\$ and we have a starting point \$x_1 = 10\$ then we get \$x_2 = f(x_1) = f(10) = 3\$, then \$x_3 = f(x_2) = f(3) = 1\$, then \$x_4 = f(x_3) = f(1) = 0\$, and finally \$x_5 = f(x_4) = f(0) = 0\$ which means the submission should return \$0\$.

- You can assume that the generated sequence actually contains a fixed point.
- You can use the native type for integers in place of \$ℤ\$.
- You can use any language for which there are defaults for black box functions input in the [standard IO meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods). If there are no such default for your language feel free to add one in the sense of the [definition of black box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13706/24877), and make sure to link your proposals in that definition. Also don't forget to vote on them.

#### Examples

```
f(x) = floor(sqrt(abs(x)))
0 -> 0,  all other numbers -> 1

f(x) = c(c(c(x))) where c(x) = x/2 if x is even; 3*x+1 otherwise
all positive numbers should result in 1,2 or 4 (Collatz conjecture)

f(x) = -42
all numbers -> -42

f(x) = 2 - x
1 -> 1
```

Comment: Note that while it's implied in the details that the black box function will converge on the fixed point, the last example says otherwise

Comment: @phflack The blackbox only has to converge for the given input.

Comment: Oh, originally I thought that the submission is not given x_0, which caused me some confusion. I thought a solution should be (Jelly) `~Nƭ⁻Ç$¿`, which is something like, (pseudo code) `for x in [0, -1, 1, -2, 2, -3, 3, -4, 4, ...]: if (x == f(x)): break; print(x); `. That may worth another challenge.

Comment: Note for future visitors: Finding **any** fixed point doesn't work, you **must** find a fixed point reachable from x_0. It's guaranteed that there exists one.

Comment: And if not exist a fixed point, for a function f, and one initial value x0... What should be the value it have to return? And if x0=0 and f=int(9/(x-1)) with for x1=x0+1 f(x1)=f(1) is already one error... What should return the operator for that f , x0?

Comment: @RosLuP Your program just has to work *if* there is such a fixed point (see second bullet point in the details)

Comment: What if the program just repeatedly apply <the number of values in the native integer data type> times the function `f` on `x_0`? Is that abuse of native integer data type?

Comment: Yes, you can assume that the numbers required to compute the sequence are all in a reasonable range.

Answer (score 17):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 1 byte

```
Y
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8f2jx/8j//025lBwfdcx61NmhBAA)

`Y` is the fixed point function in Actually. In the TIO example, the function is shown being taken as a string, and `£` is used to transform it to a function on the stack. It's also possible to just push the function to the stack [like so](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/6hngeOjjlmPOjse9Sz8H/n/vykA). These are the only two ways to get a function input in Actually.

Comment: You just knew that some day this challenge was going to be posted, didn't you? :P

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I've actually used `Y` for several challenges. I'm apparently [extremely precognizant](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously/commit/b25a67753a05b8ca6ee4095c578ee336e8571371) :P

Answer (score 13):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 2 bytes

```apl
⍣=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBP6P2iY86l1sy1X9qKdLo@ZR71ZNLT3TWn8FQyNjhUe9cxXccvLzizSKC4tKNBKTihUqNDW5qo10gepAahSgAKTQSLeCq1rXxAgobmxohBAHCgEA)

**NB:** I define `O←⍣=` in the the input section due to a bug in that derived monadic operators can't be defined in the way that TIO likes to define things.

`⍣` Is an operator that can be used like `(function⍣condition) ⍵`

It applies the `function`, `f`, to `⍵` until `(f ⍵) condition ⍵` returns true.

`⍣=` is a derived monadic operator that takes a monadic function, `f`, as its left argument and applies it to its right argument, `⍵`, until `f ⍵ = ⍵`

Comment: Maybe note that `⍣=` is a *derived monadic operator* which takes a function as left operand and finds the fix point on the given initial value. I would use a different letter for `⍣=` than `f` as it is an **o**perator, not a **f**unction.

Comment: Yeah. I would. It is confusing that you call the "input" function `f` in your description, but then on TIO, `f` is your solution operator. You can also move the `O←⍣=` up in the Code field to let it be counted and to point out that that is the actual solution, and that the rest (Input) is just testing it.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I'll speak with relevant colleague tomorrow.

Comment: @Adám Updated. Let me know if the bug gets fixed

Answer (score 11):

### Haskell, 17 bytes

```
until=<<((==)=<<)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lcs9D4IwGATg3V9xIQ5UA5EPN@pu4ubKgvhWGkuLbVV@vbWOLibmhrvhuaFzV1IqCN6Gu/ZS8aZJU85ZbBbGTmpwnM0CmKzUHksIpEIZY3N3sz4X1ox77elCNu9ODgybP2y1rT/67o/eHjSS5PvbG@080qwuWbQ/ZR7DUJQVngNZQs/RztlOCtCDNGb4IdZZPuIsQcoRqtW8LsKrF6q7uJD10/QG)

Comment: In case someone is interested: [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/144402/56433) is an explanation why `until=<<((==)=<<)`  finds a fix point of a given function.

Answer (score 10):

## [MATLAB](https://matlab.mathworks.com/), 41 bytes

```matlab
function x=g(f,x);while f(x)-x;x=f(x);end
```

There is also [this beauty](https://tio.run/##FclLCoAgGEXh7dwLNqipCG7FHkoQWRmhSGu3v8kZfCdOt3uW1oKxCLTwKrNaMCtJEBIpfOvQoRiPTGMyX1D/r@l5TQfcnmBl@S3GC@m8brgxCZCqJ3X7AA) that does not need function files. Unfortunately it is a little bit longer:

```matlab
i=@(p,c)c{2-p}();g=@(g,f,x)i(f(x)==x,{@()x,@()g(g,f,f(x))});q=@(f,x)g(g,f,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP0@hwjZdI02nQtO6PCMzJ1UhTaNCU7fCusIWxLBOzUv5D8TWKZnFBRrpGg5AMSPdCh1DTU3r/wA)

Comment: This answer was meant as an example and does not prevent anyone from answering.

Comment: Of course, if you called this Octave, you could remove two `;`s. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP0@hwjZdI02nQrM8IzMnVaFCN02jQrPCFkRap@al/AdirnQNByA3LSc/v0ijuLCoRCMxqRgooKmpY6r5HwA "Octave – Try It Online").

Comment: And in your anonymous function, you can remove the `@()` before `x` for 50 bytes. Kudos too for the way you wrap your helper function (with the `g(g)` in the end), I only managed to do 51 bytes `@(g,x)(f=@(r,z){@()r(r,m),z}{(m=g(z)==z)+1}())(f,x)`. I'm wondering if there's any combination of both approaches that's shorter still.

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 11 bytes

```
#2//.x_:>#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X9lIX1@vIt7KTlntf0BRZl6JQ1q0W05@flF0cGFRSbRjUrFDRWysjkEsFx5ZE6PY/wA)

## Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
FixedPoint
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y2zIjUlID8zr@R/QBGQdEiLdsvJzy@KDi4sKol2TCp2UI6NVdMxiOXCJ21iFPsfAA)

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>36</s> 35 bytes

*thanks to JayCe for golfing down a byte*

```r
function(f,x){while(x-(x=f(x)))0;x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5NbsIwEIXX4RSvREh2sVUn7a7NCTiFSW1iyYqDbcQIxNlTkqo/WaHZjPS9983E8YAPOdpT32YXemYF8eu5c94wkoway4hzrt7pNh7Yb4p4LUlUHEVRlLjvqwWUb/UdzqwNfcq6z/jBq13zL7l2ds1os6nF6zNtK0EvNZ9b3ut8@Sst9Ds2zfTXfKVEjm7wBnoYvGv1lEKwDyTWhxBZOsbM9D5922SlOIASqQsn/4m9QQUbIghPDZSAQsidiWeXzGPb7Fra1PgF)

[Verify the example functions!](https://tio.run/##hY5NbsIwEIXX4RSvREh2sVUn7a7NCTiFSW1iyYqDbcQIxNlTkqo/WaHZjPS9983E8YAPOdpT32YXemYF8eu5c94wkoway4hzrt7pNh7Yb4p4LUlUHEVRlLjvqwWUb/UdzqwNfcq6z/jBq13zL7l2ds1os6nF6zNtK0EvNZ9b3ut8@Sst9Ds2zfTXfKVEjm7wBnoYvGv1lEKwDyTWhxBZOsbM9D5922SlOIASqQsn/4m9QQUbIghPDZSAQsidiWeXzGPb7Fra1PgF)

R port of [flawr's solution.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150189/67312)

Comment: For what it's worth... `function(f,x){while(x-(x=f(x)))0;x}` saves one byte.

Comment: Oh, `0`, nice. Thanks much!

Answer (score 7):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), 30 bytes

```ml
fun& $g=if$ =g$then$else&(g$)g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZDNbsMgEITvfopVhCxoFKvGlnqo/AA59JJcq1b4B4KKwbVJxCmvni6oihup4oD2YxhmWEazG4139ibPFlojuq/WhRICNCCNczN9E/5ULN@zp4dBmELObtxbT0W7QGCMZdnfizxd7Ghc8RQyYXvoEtUSt9H1wHF4Bn8aLIJeXxAMZhmgegrb8tGvgk8UX2v@iOtkyHchps6BqEZLAo0i0ZREs5wqwlQqNU2gUT3NGmNj9MK7o8dBIf6AzbvdYImLMOkpmqGe5pjv/hfs9ZfV/B9YVmv5O3xZC6zCNT1jtx8) Use as `& n blackbox`.

The black box functions are defined as following:

```ml
fun blackbox1 x = floor(Math.sqrt(Real.fromInt(abs x)))

fun blackbox2 x = c(c(c(x))) 
and c x = if x mod 2 = 0 then x div 2 else 3*x+1

fun blackbox3 _ = ~42

fun blackbox4 x = 2-x
```

**Ungolfed version:**

```ml
fun fixpoint n g = if n = g n then n else fixpoint (g n) g
```

Comment: Good to see SML in the wild! We use it for our functional programming class at our university.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

thanks to [@Mr.Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) for -2 bytes

```python
s=lambda k:s(f(k))if k-f(k)else k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcrBCsIwDMbx@54iFyGpVNeol@Ieppsrjs5smF18@rqJsCFILh/5/8bXdB@Ec9aqD4/6FiB5xYiJqIuQ7LLaXltIuWiggi8SL0eGWciO4QoOPuZkZO@KuGUNLidEVIzPTiZQdExbo35@Y6gVlYw5XP5C8fbMayzLn8pW1kr5DQ)

assumes the black-box function to be named f

Comment: Doesn't the function need to be passed as a parameter? I don't think pre-defined variables is an accepted input method.

Comment: I'm not sure you're allowed to assume the function is `f`, isn't that a form of assuming input is in a variable? (edit: ninja'd by mbomb)

Comment: @mbomb007 There is a [consensus which allows it for black-box functions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/64121)

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>25</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes

thanks [Herman Lauenstein](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70894/herman-lauenstein) for showing me [this consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/64121)
thanks to [@l4m2](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76323/l4m2) for -1 byte

Assumes the black-box function to be named `f`.

```javascript
g=k=>f(k)-k?g(f(k)):k
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcaxDYAgEADAniks/wsMtibgBA6BCKgQXoG4Pka96g5962LyflaeaLWteRmkchCQh8nDGxxDczJJNeu69S4SZfharlz/6aVAQkRmKBWKto/kgXWdh0EIZNge)

Comment: This can be shortened if [black-box functions to be taken as input can be assumed to be predefined under a given name](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/70894)

Comment: f(k)-k instead of

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
vÐL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/7/s8ASf////KxnFK/03BAA)

Takes the left argument as a string representing a Jelly link (`2_` for instance), and the right argument as an integer

### How it works

```
 ÐL - While the output is unique...
v   -   Evaluate the function with the argument given
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 24 bytes

```
(()){{}(({})<>[({})])}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU7O6ulZDo7pW04YLyNPQjK6ujdXksosGCcVq1lbX/v9vCAA)

(for the black box function `x -> 2-x` in the example below)

The provided black box function should be a program, that given `x` on the top of the stack, pop `x` and push `f(x)` - in other word, it should evaluate the function `f` on the value on the top of the stack.

Equivalent [Mini-Flak](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/110652) is 26 bytes (thanks to Wheat Wizard for saving 2 bytes):

```
(()){{}(({})( )[{}({})])}{}
             ^ put the function f here
```

(not counting the comments and spaces)

Take the function (inside the `<>`) and a number `x0` from input. (note that Brain-Flak is an esoteric language and can't take functional argument as input)

---

Example blackbox functions:

`x -> 2-x`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0NDU0Mzuro2VvP/fxMA)

---

Explanation:

```
(()){{}(({})<f>[({})])}{}   Main program.
                            Implicit input from stdin to stack.
(  )                        Push
 ()                         literal number 1.
                            Now the content of the stack: [1, x0]
    {                 }     While stack top ≠ 0:
                            current stack content: [something ≠ 0, x]
     {}                       Pop stack top (something). stack = [x]
       (             )        Push
        ({})                    Stack top = x. Current stack = [x]
             f                  Evaluate f. Current stack = [f(x)]
            < >                   (suppress the value of f(x), avoid adding it)
               [    ]           plus the negative of
                ({})            the top of the stack ( = -f(x) )
                              In conclusion, this change (x) on the stack to
                              (f(x)), and then push (x + -f(x))
                            If it's 0, break loop, else continue.
                       {}   Pop the redundant 0 on the top.
                            Implicit output stack value to stdout.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Swift](https://swift.org), <s>47</s> 42 bytes

```swift
func h(_ n:Int){f(n)==n ?print(n):h(f(n))}
```

Naive approach, assumes that [the black box function is named](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13707/70894) `f`

Comment: I am in doubt regarding your second attempt, because it is a complex closure and its type is ambiguous unless you explicitly cast it to `{...}as(<parameter types>)-><return type>`. If you don't specify its return type, it will throw build-time errors so I don't think it is valid as of now (note that the cast must be included in the byte count). Your first submission is fine, though.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 14 bytes

```apl
{⍵=⍺⍺⍵:⍵⋄∇⍺⍺⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/@f9qhtQvWjni6Nmke9WzW1Dm83qv2fBxbr3Wr7qHcXGG21AuJH3S2POtrhQrX//6cp5CkYcIFIQzBpCiaNjMGUiRGUMgAA)

The function at the header is equivalent to `f(x) = floor(sqrt(abs(x)))`

Thanks @Adám for pointing out that the original answer wasn't valid according to PPCG consensus.

#### How it works:

```apl
{⍵=⍺⍺⍵:⍵⋄∇⍺⍺⍵} ⍝ Main 'function' (this is actually an operator)
      :         ⍝ if
 ⍵=⍺⍺⍵          ⍝ the right argument (⍵) = the left function (⍺⍺, which is f) of ⍵
       ⍵        ⍝ return ⍵
        ⋄       ⍝ else
         ∇⍺⍺⍵   ⍝ return this function (∇) with argument f(⍵)
```

Comment: {⍵=f⍵:⍵⋄∇(f⍵)} would be ok for separate anonymous function from its name (n)

Comment: This assumes that `f` is preassigned, which I think is prohibited by PPCG consensus. `{⍵=⍺⍺⍵:⍵⋄∇⍺⍺⍵}` would be a valid operator solution.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 40 bytes

```c
f(n,b)int(*b)(_);{n=n^b(n)?f(b(n),b):n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY/RasMwDEXf@xUiMCqPCJo2ZbDQ7TP2UjYcr24NjtLZDhRKfn2evTG6ZHqR0D2SrhQdlYpRI5etMBzwvhX4Jpor7/i1RRbPGnNK6iM3Y0wIaC8x54uAK7hDGByD/3ABZevxIkQD4yLrXK//cVSvs/ytd9IwJm0BKc5D8FjoNA870LbvHf7dKQrR/HAujWosVkBPcGf2XJSgcVUmU2KG0HbC0HYCDUGdpMPlnpe31s1CMjo/WW02D5ONuVGmL@eH62qC1dUvNMZPpa08@ki2i/TCPZnubI0ygfTAKpie6f2grHQy118) Note that the flags are not necessary, they are there to aid with testing the fixpoint function defined above.

This is a function that takes an int `n` and a function pointer `b : int → int`. Abusing the fact that writing to the first variable argument sets the `eax` register, which is equivalent to returning<sup>†</sup>. Otherwise, this is pretty standard as far as C golf goes. `n^b(n)` checks for the inequality of `n` and the black box applied to `n`. When unequal, it calls the fixpoint function `f` again recursively with the application and black box as arguments. Otherwise, it returns the fixpoint.

<sup>†Citation needed, I vaguely remember reading this somewhere and google seems to confirm my suspicions</sup>

It declares input with K&R-style parameter typing:

```c
f(n, b)
int(*b)(_);
{
    n=n^b(n)?f(b(n),b):n;
}
```

The arcane bit on the second line above declares `b` to be a function pointer that takes an integer parameter—the default type of `_` is assumed to be an integer. Similarly, `n` is assumed to be an integer, and `f` is assumed to return an integer. Hooray for implicit typing?

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 46 bytes

```
import StdEnv
p x=hd[n\\n<-iterate f x|f n==n]
```

Assumes the function is defined as `f :: !Int -> Int`

It takes the head of the infinite list of applications of `f f f ... x` filtered for those elements where `f el  == el`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcutDsIwFAZQv6f4JBMVoLkOBAlukiJu@gNN2rtmK6QkPPsuHH9cDixaZv/KAYWTaCp1Xhqm5s/yHio6Pf1NrJWjSS0s3AIi@jdCiOSukXa2g3CAQR@HqfE/Eyr2urmY@bGquVz19BEuya0/)

If you want to change the function in the TIO, Clean's lambda syntax is:

`\argument = expression`

*(actually it's far more complicated, but thankfully we only need unary functions)*

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 37 bytes

```matlab
function x=g(f,x);while x-(x=f(x))end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP0@hwjZdI02nQtO6PCMzJ1WhQlejwjZNo0JTMzUv5T8QW6dkFhdopGs4AMWMdCt0DDU1rf8DAA)

Octave has inline assignment but MATLAB doesn't, so this is a golfier Octave port of [flawr's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150189/67312).

It also [ports nicely to R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/150195/67312).

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 50 bytes

```
{f,k->var a=k;var b=a+1;while(b!=a){b=a;a=f(a)};a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYm9DsIgFIV3n@K6XWJJ2sapCImjs09wm0glRTSANYbw7AirZzh/3/qM1riykYUwIV5cZFxV76BV4KolyJJ0t3K1kQeSq2g5SzoM4nM39obzXhJL9REkNRLLgnLRbwcPMg7JL2GCs/f0PV2jN25RLO2g6lVHtA4DppGbmDsYGPsn/Dg20PcV5fID)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/) (gforth), 36 bytes

This version just assumes `f` is predefined. It's not as cool as the solution below it. Both programs exit with a stack overflow if not found, or a stack underflow if found (after printing the result).

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf9jFFJS0zLzUhXSuKwU0hSMFIrLEwsUdBWsubhiFApKizMUKh41NXIZ/rdSSFdIKS0AqskvSy1SsFXwdFPQUwjxcPVTKEpNLi0qTlWw/p/@HwA)

```
: g dup f over = IF . THEN recurse ;
```

---

### Forth (gforth), 52 bytes

This allows a function's execution token to be passed as a parameter, and is definitely the cooler solution.

```
: g 2dup execute rot over = IF . THEN swap recurse ;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##PY2xCsIwFEX3fMXdqkMFO7Y4Kro4dewi9r2kCElIXmxW/VR/JFYKTpfDOXDZBTG15t@UASPxZAmsWjAaxPnmUaNTaoBP0SB/3i@1/6OYpa0ismBDme5JJmch7kF2qypwaaHRjMljtYTgBO5JAQdcTtihPx@v601YghAJXdHlCw)

#### Explanation:

```
: g             \ x1 f          Define g. Params on the stack. f is on top
2dup execute    \ x1 f x2       duplicate both params, execute f(x1)
rot over        \ f x2 x1 x2    move x1 to top and copy x2 to top
= IF . THEN                     compare, if equal, print
swap recurse ;                  otherwise, recurse
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>31</s> 28 bytes

```ruby
->x,f{x=f[x]until x==f[x];x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfbvtf165CJ626wjYtuiK2NK8kM0ehwhbMsa6o/V9QWlKskB5tqANUVW2kW1Eby5VsC2JXqBrZ2hrYV@gbWRlrVWgb1nJBlRYl5qVoGBoYGGjqKIAUJkeDYEVsbGxt7H8A)

Comment: 25 bytes - ->x,f{1while x!=x=f[x];x}

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure, <s>45</s> 43 bytes

Well, this is the shortest and ugliest:

```
#(loop[a + b %2](if(= a b)a(recur b(% b))))
```

`+` is there instead of a number so that it is not equal to any value of `x0`.

55 bytes and functional:

```
#(reduce(fn[a b](if(= a b)(reduced a)b))(iterate % %2))
```

Example:

```
(def f #(...))
(defn collaz [x] (if (even? x) (-> x (/ 2)) (-> x (* 3) (+ 1))))
(f (->> collaz (repeat 3) (apply comp)) 125)
; 1
```

Answer (score 1):

## [tinylisp](https://github.com/dloscutoff/Esolangs/tree/master/tinylisp) repl, 28 bytes

```
(d P(q((x)(i(e(f x)x)x(P(f x
```

Assumes that the function `f` is predefined.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYxBCoAwDATvecUeNzc9@I9@QdBCoIilHurrY1sUTC6zmyGXHXeycrpzQ2Amq9K4M6JqW4ZOrmNEmhQFzOieADQwgStq0zFPvfviwPI/vj8CFvUH) (The example function is `f(x) = (x*2) mod 10`.)

#### Ungolfed

```
(load library)
(def P
 (lambda (x)
  (if (equal? (f x) x)
   x
   (P (f x)))))
```

If `f(x)` equals `x`, then `x` is a fixed point; return it. Otherwise, recursively look for a fixed point starting from `f(x)` instead of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## APL NARS 65 chars

```
r←(f v)n;c
   c←0⋄→B
E: r←∞⋄→0
A: n←r
B: r←f n⋄c+←1⋄→E×⍳c>1e3⋄→A×⍳r≠n
```

v operator would return ∞ (or possibly -oo or Nan) for error, else one value x with x=f(x).
In test f=floor(sqrt(abs(x))), f1=2-x, f2=c(c(c(x))) with c=x%2==0?x/2:3*x+1

```
  f←⌊∘√∘|
  f v 0
0
  f v 9
1
  f1←{2-⍵}
  f1 v 1
1
  f1 v ¯10
∞
  f1 v 2
∞
  c1←{0=2∣⍵:⍵÷2⋄1+3×⍵}
  f2←c1∘c1∘c1
  f2 v 1
1
  f2 v 2
2
  f2 v 7
2
  f2 v 82
4
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 42 bytes

This takes a `Function<Integer, Integer>` or `IntFunction<Integer>` and an `int` or `Integer` (curried) and returns the fixed point.

```java
f->i->{while(i!=(i=f.apply(i)));return i;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jU9NS8QwED23v2L2lqINelqwpouXBQ@isHoSD9k2rVPTJCTT1bL0t9eIRVD24GFm3ny/18mDzK1TpqvfZjfsNVZQaRkC3Ek0cEyTpRhIUgwNGqmhi1t8INS8GUxFaA3fLuD6RO/W0E87YtUqX57D6cEnI/1475SXZH0JraItfqj6waIhEHOTl5iXx/dX1IrhSjAUDZfO6ZFhlmWFVzR4A1hMc1Kkf9kfLNbQR2FsRx5N@/wC0rch@9KZ/JM4eNm7R7sGAQh5GZ0QsIZNtKuYnMFlEY/txkCq53Yg7uIn0ob9krJwXm5l3@lNiE/YRZSRJlM6zZ8)

Takes advantage of the fact that Java evaluates subexpressions from left to right (so the old `i` is compared to the new), a property which I was unaware of while writing this!

Answer (score 1):

## x86 opcode, 8 bytes

```
fun:
        call    edx          ; 2B
        cmpxchg eax,    ecx  ; 3B, on 8086 use xchg and cmp instead
        jnz     fun          ; 2B
        ret                  ; 1B
```

Take input: `ecx` (value `x0`), `edx` (function address, take input from `ecx`, write result to `eax` without modifying the value of `ecx` and `edx`)

## 8086 opcode, 7 bytes (but slow)

```
    xor     cx,     cx
    call    dx
    loop    $-2
    ret
```

If there exists a fixed point, looping 65536 times always drive it there.
Take input: `ax` (initial value `x0`), `dx` (function address, take input from `ax`, write output to `ax` without modifying the value of `cx` and `dx`).
Output the fixed point in register `ax`.

Comment: It would certainly help if you make the answer more readable.

Comment: more edit to make it correct

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 30 bytes

```
[pq][Smrd3Rd3Rxd3R=mLmlmx]dsmx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@Hx1roKCcmZKaV5JZUqmglFaal1ySmZ@npJCYl6JQlVqU/z@6oDA2Oji3KMU4CIgqgNg21yc3J7ciNqU4t@L/fwA)

Takes as input the function in the form of a macro and initial value on the stack(pushed in that order). Prints the fixed point.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 3 bytes

```
^:_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY9BT4QwEIXv8ysmJKZUgbSFC9U1JCaePHl30RCaXd3IsqwGE@Nfx3mVCAde@948vnldkkKNvPGsMsOeTV7cPT7cL1vfLpooHIbhBPemoGk8nSEvPO1eDgEy9zTj@0T7qf/s36ENb9jxN89EHc6pvSovZ/2Mmab4y0mxhRfrGxRTcLjotr6kUEK2lUsMhQracY6@cz9FAgtQYg5HnD54FN13u4GVV9kPq5DOWihUJjDHfffGX2ugSRXLdeIzxfltVE046sQI5ZrU/12KdOSMf5VSsKZglXatrqXbsjXygH0NdSle8RGwpuSaq7jQ6ueVi5PR4FbGuba1q7DnGom7Ynr5BQ)

When a conjunction in J is missing an operand, it becomes an adjective. This program produces an adjective which takes as an argument a verb. `^:` is the *power* or "repeat" verb, and the idiom `f^:_`, that is, `f` repeated infinitely, is J's [*limit application*](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm), which exactly solves this challenge:

> An infinite power `n` produces the limit of the application of `u` .

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 18 + 1 (`-p`)

```
$_=f$_ while$_^f$_
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH97@Tq7ulXXVyapJBWnZlXomeqrRIfbRCrb6xnaFJb@18l3jZNJV6hPCMzJ1UlPg7I/v/f0OBffkFJZn5e8X/dAgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 1 byte

```
Ẋ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCLOuzIkLTtcbjEiLCLhuooiLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Builtin lol

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 3 bytes

J-uby has a built-in operator for this:

```ruby
:!~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWi60U6yCsm1ppCrYKunYV1QoaFfq-iSUZVlYBnpp6RfmleSkKtVxcBQpuehppOgqGBpoQHQsWQGgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 14 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
gOvV
¥W?U:ßW
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=CgpnT3ZWCqVXP1U631c&input=MTQyMzU0NgoiQFhhIHEgZn0i)

Japt doesn't have any built-in "repeat until the output is constant" functionality, or the ability to take functions directly as input. This program takes `x` as the first input, and a string defining a Japt function as the second input.

Explanation:

```
/n      # Store first input as U

/n      # Store second input as V

gOvV
 OvV    # Interpret V as Japt code
g       # Apply that function to U
        # Store the result as W

¥W      # Check whether U and W are the same
  ?U    # If they are, output U
    :ßW # Otherwise repeat the program with W and V as the inputs
```

A [theoretical alternative](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=pWdWID9VOt9VZ1Y&input=MTQyMzU0NgoiQFhhIHEgZn0i) would work if the function were assumed to already be stored in V, but there isn't really a good way to actually accomplish that in Japt so it's not really a reasonable input method.

Comment: Consensus allows for black box functions to be assigned to pre-defined variables, allowing you to get rid of the `eval`. Add in a couple of tweaks and you can get this down to [10 bytes](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=CshhIHEgZg&code=Z1U9Z1YpP986VQ&input=MTQyMzU0Ng)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Black-box function is preassigned to variable `V`

```
gU=gV)?ß:U
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=CshhIHEgZg&code=Z1U9Z1YpP986VQ&input=MTQyMzU0Ng)

```
gU=gV)?ß:U     :Implicit input of integer U
g              :Sign of difference with
 U=            :  Reassign to U
   gV          :  Value of U after being passed through V
     )         :End sign
      ?        :If truthy (not 0)
       ß       :  Recursive call with new value of U
        :U     :Else return U
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 70 bytes

```go
func f(O func(int)int,n int)int{x:=O(n)
for;x!=O(x);x=O(x){}
return x}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZJRa9swEMdhT8Wf4hoYkxsls5VQSlw9lEBeU9hjKUMVViaaSKksFw_Hn2QvodAPlX2anRQnY2OzsfS_k_w73Z1-vK3s_vBpK-SzWJWwEdokerO1zo8HauMHZ2Mj_LfBe-3V6OawULWRoMgSgiDa-BQ_aqBXbTPjS2LSRFlXNJeom7Ro4tR2iSt97Qw03ZH288OF_74tYQH8D1zyKhyoSsDJ35zxPQElWaytdeTLi_Pk7qkiam2Fv55ioPB0kSEn8A-GnPHo-X1orcB8ZJxnJ775zDoo11UJJ8_kygzzriugtyUJb3MOZaYM_krj9Otoyo57qvqJ_TclNmq6JIn1mEPlXS09tAoWBWhqw2ZcjTmJqqyQ8vA4b5MWq0Qho1lHe81oHjQeJ-gQGq0QmEIelxATexj6TVJoQ6fgK5Uw4-CEwZtwjNAm9w6jrg2RY01Bji3FvsuxClqnwHnwpZGHBD3jeaFvOcsKPRxCa7HIRE4o6PQMQgxCLOf5bocji-M0IPoLsd8f518)