# Implement the Thanos sorting algorithm

Tags: code-golf, sorting

The sorting algorithm goes like this:

While the list is not sorted, snap half of all items (remove them from the list). Continue until the list is sorted or only one item remains (which is sorted by default). This sorting algorithm may give different results based on implementation.

The item removal procedure is up to the implementation to decide, but the list should be half as long as before after one pass of the item removal procedure. Your algorithm may decide to remove either the first half or the list, the last half of the list, all odd items, all even items, one at a time until the list is half as long, or any not mentioned.

The input list can contain an arbitrary amount of items (within reason, let’s say up to 1000 items), not only perfectly divisible lists of 2^n items. You will have to either remove (n+1)/2 or (n-1)/2 items if the list is odd, either hardcoded or decided randomly during runtime. Decide for yourself: what would Thanos do if the universe contained an odd amount of living things?

The list is sorted if no item is smaller than any previous item. Duplicates may occur in the input, and may occur in the output.

Your program should take in an array of integers (via stdin or as parameters, either individual items or an array parameter), and return the sorted array (or print it to stdout).

Examples:

```
// A sorted list remains sorted
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// A list with duplicates may keep duplicates in the result
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3] -> [1, 3, 3] // Removing every second item
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3] -> [3, 4, 3] -> [4, 3] -> [3] // Removing the first half
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3] -> [1, 2] // Removing the last half
```

`[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]` could give different results:

```
// Removing every second item:
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [1, 4, 5]
```

or:

```
// Removing the first half of the list
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [3, 5] // With (n+1)/2 items removed
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [4, 3, 5] -> [3, 5] // With (n-1)/2 items removed
```

or:

```
// Removing the last half of the list
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [1, 2] // With (n+1)/2 items removed
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [1, 2, 4] // With (n-1)/2 items removed
```

or:

```
// Taking random items away until half (in this case (n-1)/2) of the items remain
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5] -> [1, 4, 3] -> [4, 3] -> [4]
```

Comment: Having a test case which actually requires multiple snaps for multiple different snapping algorithms would be very helpful.

Comment: Don't we need to sort and eliminate half of the answers...

Comment: Suggested test case: `[9, 1, 1, 1, 1]`. My own algorithm failed on this input

Answer (score 20):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>38</s>  <s>42</s> 39 bytes

```python
q=lambda t:t>sorted(t)and q(t[::2])or t
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9A2JzE3KSVRocSqxK44v6gkNUWjRDMxL0WhUKMk2srKKFYzv0ih5H9BUWZeiUahRrShjpGOcaymJhdcxBgoYggU@Q8A)

`-3 bytes` thanks to @JoKing and @Quuxplusone

Comment: [40 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9A2JzE3KSVRocSqRNG2OL@oJDVFo0QzMS9FoVCjJNrKyihWM79IoeR/QVFmXolGoUa0oY6RjnGspiYXXMQYKGIIFPkPAA)

Comment: [39 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9A2JzE3KSVRocSqxK44v6gkNUWjRDMxL0WhUKMk2srKKFYzv0ih5H9BUWZeiUahRrShjpGOcaymJhdcxBgoYggU@Q8A) thanks to [TFeld's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182239/11791) observation that any permutation `!= sorted(t)` must be `> sorted(t)`.

Answer (score 19):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 41 bytes

```r
x=scan();while(any(x-sort(x)))x=x[!0:1];x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v8K2ODkxT0PTujwjMydVIzGvUqNCtzi/qESjQlNTs8K2IlrRwMow1rriv6GCkYKJgrGC6X8A)

Comment: `is.unsorted` rather than `any(...)` would also be 41 bytes.

Comment: This base method is 44 bytes as a recursive function, might be golfable: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/P822oKiyyMoqTSMhMy1BI7NYrzSvOL@oJDVFo0JTJ02jIlrRwMowVlOnQlPzf5qGoZWhgSZXmkYymKVjqgnl6BjrwDFQIQA "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 39 bytes

```python
f=lambda l:l>sorted(l)and f(l[::2])or l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vcm7CoAgFADQva@4Y8JdfC1C/Yg4GCYFNxVz6evNsdZzytOOnETvcSF/bcEDGVrvXNseZmI@BYgzWWOEY7kC9VLP1IZZjiAQFIJE0I5NnxAoUeEP9QA5gjvWXw)

Answer (score 12):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (v2), 6 bytes

```
≤₁|ḍt↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnkkdNjTUPd/SWPGrb8P9/tKGOkY6JjrGOaez/KAA)

This is a function submission. Input from the left, output to the right, as usual. (The TIO link uses a command-line argument that automatically wraps the function into a full program, so that you can see it in action.)

### Explanation

```
≤₁|ḍt↰
≤₁       Assert that {the input} is sorted {and output it}
  |      Handler for exceptions (e.g. assertion failures):
   ḍ     Split the list into two halves (as evenly as possible)
    t    Take the last (i.e. second) half
     ↰   Recurse {and output the result of the recursion}
```

### Bonus round

```
≤₁|⊇ᵇlᵍḍhtṛ↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9icmFjaHlsb2cy///iiaTigoF84oqH4bWHbOG1jeG4jWh04bmb4oaw//9bMSwyLDQsMyw1Xf9a)

The snap's meant to be random, isn't it? Here's a version of the program that choses the surviving elements randomly (while ensuring that half survive at each round).

```
≤₁|⊇ᵇlᵍḍhtṛ↰
≤₁            Assert that {the input} is sorted {and output it}
  |           Handler for exceptions (e.g. assertion failures):
   ⊇ᵇ         Find all subsets of the input (preserving order)
     lᵍ       Group them by length
       ḍht    Find the group with median length:
         t      last element of
        h       first
       ḍ        half (split so that the first half is larger)
          ṛ   Pick a random subset from that group
           ↰  Recurse
```

This would be rather shorter if we could reorder the elements, but whyever would a sorting algorithm want to do *that*?

Comment: One byte per infinity stone.

Comment: @djechlin the infinity *byte* is why you must go for the head and especially the jaw.

Answer (score 10):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 30 bytes

```perl6
$!={[<=]($_)??$_!!.[^*/2].&$!}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwX0XRtjraxjZWQyVe095eJV5RUS86TkvfKFZPTUWx9n9xYqVCmkK0oY6CkY6CsY6CiY6Caaw1FxZhY3RhE7CMaex/AA)

Recursive function that removes the second half of the list until the list is sorted.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
$!={                         }    # Assign the function to $!
    [<=]($_)??                    # If the input is sorted
              $_                  # Return the input
                !!                # Else
                  .[^*/2]         # Take the first half of the list (rounding up)
                         .&$!     # And apply the function again
```

Answer (score 9):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 76 bytes

```cs
g=>{while(!g.OrderBy(x=>x).SequenceEqual(g))g=g.Take(g.Count()/2);return g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3RasIwFEDf/YrYp1x6jdipDGoCOhQEYQ8b7DntrtewLmKaYIf02@vm4@A8HTicup3UrRt2yder/danbwq2amjlfDT4Xxhx1ANrc7ueXENyzOo1fFLY/MhOmw7UG10S@Zq2l2QbyQCsWb3bL5KsXs7JRwnTAspAMQUvuOyHcjT6CC6SPEpPV3FwbXycbjMs8BnF/METigUu8c/NelBr5kBsf6ssQ2mxAm1snoksrwDK4Q4)

Answer (score 8):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 30 bytes

```
#//.x_/;Sort@x!=x:>x[[;;;;2]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277X1lfX68iXt86OL@oxKFC0bbCyq4iOtoaCIxiY9X@BxRl5pUoOASWZqaWOCikR1cb6igY6SiY6CgY6yiY1sb@/w8A)

@Doorknob saved 12 bytes

Comment: Instead of taking the first half, you could save some bytes by taking every other element (`x[[;;;;2]]`).

Comment: @Doorknob yes of course...

Comment: thought there could be some savings by using `OrderedQ`, but couldn't make it work

Comment: @GregMartin I used `OrderedQ` in my very first approach (see edits)

Answer (score 8):

## Java 10, <s>106</s> 97 bytes

```java
L->{for(;;L=L.subList(0,L.size()/2)){int p=1<<31,f=1;for(int i:L)f=p>(p=i)?0:f;if(f>0)return L;}}
```

-9 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##tZFNb8MgDIbv/RUcQXJY0g81LU2mHSexXnqcdqApVHQpjYB06qr89oxknTRN2i0FhMDG72ObgziL6LB7b4tSOIdehDbXEULaeGmVKCRad1eEDuEdrb0uKdfOr56Dfy9tjgr8n4cTFiKbUdicF14XaI0Myloe5Vd1spgxnnHq6m0XhmMIZ/0pMXkYE3INfFRlyWo1SUBlCesCOptecqKyKsdVpsljvFRMK6zymFjpa2sQZ03Tso5Z1dsyMG/o80nv0DEUhzfearN/fUOCfFe2uTgvj/RUe1oFly8NNrTARn78KvrJWnHpE/1jc1S43p7AGCYwhRkJgw2tPA3awytPIR1cM4UouUOis9CEFIZXnkA/B9ed9V82vkPGURJDWNECFhCloSnRHOZ3ofT68xus4/xQmlHTfgE)

Only leave the first halve of the list every iteration, and removes \$\frac{n+1}{2}\$ items if the list-size is odd.

**Explanation:**

```java
L->{               // Method with Integer-list as both parameter and return-type
  for(;;           //  Loop indefinitely:
      L=L.subList(0,L.size()/2)){
                   //    After every iteration: only leave halve the numbers in the list
    int p=1<<31,   //   Previous integer, starting at -2147483648
        f=1;       //   Flag-integer, starting at 1
    for(int i:L)   //   Inner loop over the integer in the list:
      f=p>(p=i)?   //    If `a>b` in a pair of integers `a,b`:
         0         //     Set the flag to 0
        :          //    Else (`a<=b`):
         f;        //     Leave the flag the same
    if(f>0)        //   If the flag is still 1 after the loop:
      return L;}}  //    Return the list as result
```

Comment: `n->{for(;n.reduce((1<<31)+0d,(a,b)->a==.5|b<a?.5:b)==.5;n=n.skip(n.count()/2));return n;}`  is shorter using streams, but I haven't been able to figure out how to avoid the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed` error after returning the stream

Comment: @EmbodimentofIgnorance this happens because `reduce` is a terminal operation that closes the stream. You won't ever be able to call `reduce` twice on the same stream. You can create a new stream, though.

Comment: [97 bytes](https://tio.run/##tZFNb8MgDIbv/RUcQXJY0g81LU2mHSexXnqcdqApVHQpjYB06qr89oxknTRN2i0FhMDG72ObgziL6LB7b4tSOIdehDbXEULaeGmVKCRad1eEDuEdrb0uKdfOr56Dfy9tjgr8n4cTFiKbUdicF14XaI0Myloe5Vd1spgxnnHq6m0XhmMIZ/0pMXkYE3INfFRlyWo1SUBlCesCOptecqKyKsdVpsljvFRMK6zymFjpa2sQZ03Tso5Z1dsyMG/o80nv0DEUhzfearN/fUOCfFe2uTgvj/RUe1oFly8NNrTARn78KvrJWnHpE/1jc1S43p7AGCYwhRkJgw2tPA3awytPIR1cM4UouUOis9CEFIZXnkA/B9ed9V82vkPGURJDWNECFhCloSnRHOZ3ofT68xus4/xQmlHTfgE)

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire That order looks so simple now that I see it.. Sometimes it takes a look from another angle to see the obvious others initially miss I guess. :) Thanks!

Comment: No worries, it wasn't obvious: I worked to get there. I tested at least 10 versions before finding that one ;)

Answer (score 7):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>49</s>  48 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @tsh*

Removes every 2nd element.

```javascript
f=a=>a.some(p=c=>p>(p=c))?f(a.filter(_=>a^=1)):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/f8/zTbR1i5Rrzg/N1WjwDbZ1q7ADkRratqnaSTqpWXmlKQWacQDlcTZGmpqWiX@T87PK87PSdXLyU/XSNOINtQx0jHWMdExjdXU5MIiZwKUxSYH0mUI1fcfAA)

Comment: `p++&1` -> `a^=1`

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>8</s> 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
[Ð{Q#ιн
```

-1 byte thanks to *@Emigna*.

Removes all odd 0-indexed items every iteration, so removes \$\frac{n-1}{2}\$ items if the list-size is odd.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/@vCE6kDlczsv7AWyDXUUjHQUTHQUjHUUTGMB) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/6MMTqgOVz@28sPd/rc7/6GhDHSMdYx0THdNYHQUwxwTIBXNMdCxAlIWOriGEawqUtdABc4x1wBDENAXrMIKI6xoa6ACRrqWOpY6uBVC1rrmOOUwCLGQOlQdJxcYCAA) (or [verify those test cases with step-by-step for each iteration](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX@mio@RfWgLkKZRnlmQoFJekFhQDJXT@Rx@eUB2ofG6n7YW9/2t1Dm2z/x8dbahjpGOsY6JjGqujAOaYALlgjomOBYiy0NE1hHBNgbIWOmCOsQ4YgpimYB1GEHFdQwMdINK11LHU0bUAqtY11zGHSYCFzKHyIKnYWAA)).

**7 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) alternative by *@Grimy***:

```
ΔÐ{Ê>äн
```

Removes the last \$\frac{n}{2}\$ items (or \$\frac{n-1}{2}\$ items if the list-size is odd) every iteration.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3JTDE6oPd9kdXnJh7///0YY6CkY6CiY6CsY6CqaxAA) or [verify some more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/c1MOT6g@3GV3eMmFvf9rdf5HRxvqGOkY65jomMbqKIA5JkAumGOiYwGiLHR0DSFcU6CshQ6YY6wDhiCmKViHEURc19BAB4h0LXUsdXQtgKp1zXXMYRJgIXOoPEgqNhYA) (or [verify those test cases with step-by-step for each iteration](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V@m5JlXUFpipaBkX@mio@RfWgLkKZRnlmQoFJekFhQDJXT@n5tyeEL14S67w0tsL@z9X6tzaJv9/@hoQx0jHWMdEx3TWB0FMMcEyAVzTHQsQJSFjq4hhGsKlLXQAXOMdcAQxDQF6zCCiOsaGugAka6ljqWOrgVQta65jjlMAixkDpUHScXGAgA)).

**Explanation:**

```python
[        # Start an infinite loop:
 Ð       #  Triplicate the list (which is the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
  {Q     #  Sort a copy, and check if they are equal
    #    #   If it is: Stop the infinite loop (and output the result implicitly)
  ι      #  Uninterweave: halve the list into two parts; first containing all even-indexed
         #  items, second containing all odd-indexed items (0-indexed)
         #   i.e. [4,5,2,8,1] → [[4,2,1],[5,8]]
   н     #  And only leave the first part

Δ        # Loop until the result no longer changes:
 Ð       #  Triplicate the list (which is the implicit input-list in the first iteration)
  {Ê     #  Sort a copy, and check if they are NOT equal (1 if truthy; 0 if falsey)
    >    #  Increase this by 1 (so 1 if the list is sorted; 2 if it isn't sorted)
     ä   #  Split the list in that many parts
      н  #  And only leave the first part
         # (and output the result implicitly after it no longer changes)
```

Comment: You can use `ι` instead of `2ä` if you switch to a *keep every other element* strategy.

Comment: Alternative 7 using the "remove the last half" strategy: `ΔÐ{Ê>äн`

Comment: @Grimy That's a pretty nice approach as well. Shall I add it to my post (crediting you of course), or do you want to post it as a separated answer?

Comment: Feel free to add it.

Answer (score 6):

## TI-BASIC (TI-84), <s>47</s> <s>42</s> <s>45</s> 44 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @SolomonUcko!*

```
Ans→L1:Ans→L2:SortA(L1:While max(L1≠Ans:iPart(.5dim(Ans→dim(L2:L2→L1:SortA(L1:End:Ans
```

Input list is in `Ans`.
Output is in `Ans` and is implicitly printed out.

**Explanation:**

```
Ans→L1                  ;store the input into two lists
Ans→L2
SortA(L1                ;sort the first list
                        ; two lists are needed because "SortA(" edits the list it sorts
While max(L1≠Ans        ;loop until both lists are strictly equal
iPart(.5dim(Ans→dim(L2  ;remove the latter half of the second list
                        ; removes (n+1)/2 elements if list has an odd length
L2→L1                   ;store the new list into the first list (updates "Ans")
SortA(L1                ;sort the first list
End
Ans                     ;implicitly output the list when the loop ends
```

---

**Note:**  TI-BASIC is a tokenized language.  Character count does *not* equal byte count.

Comment: I think you can replace `not(min(L1=Ans` with `max(L1≠Ans` to save a byte.

Answer (score 6):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 37 bytes

```ruby
->r{r=r[0,r.size/2]while r.sort!=r;r}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf166ousi2KNpAp0ivOLMqVd8otjwjMydVAcjNLypRtC2yLqr9X6CQFh1tqGOkY6JjrGMaG8sFFzAGCsEFTMHyRjqGsbH/AQ)

Comment: [36 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P81W166oukivOL@oRNG2SME@Lboo2kAHKJBZlapvFBtrVVT7v0AhLTraUMdIx0THWMc0NpYLLmAMFIILmILljXQMY2P/AwA) recursively

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
m2$⁻Ṣ$¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//bTIk4oG74bmiJMK//8OHxZLhuZj//1sxLCAyLCA0LCAzLCA1XQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
eo₌⟨2%⟩↻
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0/MTPz/PzX/UVPPo/krjFQfzV/5qG33///RhgpGCsYKJgrGsQA)

Explanation:

```
e		| eval input as a list
       ↻	| until
 o		| the list is sorted
  ₌		| push additional copy
   ⟨2%⟩  	| and take every 2nd element
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 49 bytes

```matlab
l=input('');while(~issorted(l))l=l(1:2:end);end;l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/xzYzr6C0RENdXdO6PCMzJ1WjLrO4OL@oJDVFI0dTM8c2R8PQysgqNS9F0xpIWOf8/x9tqGCkYKxgpmCuYBQLAA) This was a journey where more boring is better. Note the two much more interesting entries below:

#### 50 bytes

```matlab
function l=q(l)if(~issorted(l))l=q(l(1:2:end));end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/rTQvuSQzP08hx7ZQI0czM02jLrO4OL@oJDUFyNUEi2oYWhlZpealaGpaA8n/QMzFVagRbapgqGAYq/kfAA) Instead of the uninteresting imperative solution, we can do a recursive solution, for only one additional byte.

#### 53 bytes

```matlab
f(f=@(g)@(l){l,@()g(g)(l(1:2:end))}{2-issorted(l)}())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/V9oq6en9z9NI83WQSNd00EjR7M6R8dBQzMdyNPI0TC0MrJKzUvR1KytNtLNLC7OLypJTQEqqtXQ1PxfqBFtqGCkYKxgomAaq/kfAA) Yep. A recursive anonymous function, thanks to @ceilingcat's [brilliant answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164483/32352) on my [tips](/questions/tagged/tips) question. An anonymous function that returns a recursive anonymous function by defining itself in its argument list. I like anonymous functions. Mmmmm.

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>57</s> 55 bytes (thanks to ASCII-only)

```hs
f x|or$zipWith(>)x$tail x=f$take(div(length x)2)x|1>0=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia/SKUqsyA8syRDw06zQqUkMTNHocI2DcjITtVIySzTyEnNSy/JUKjQNNKsqDG0M7Ct@J@bmJmnYKuQkq9QUFoSXFLkk6egolCckV8OpNIUog11jHRMdIx1TGO5FOAAp0pjoFrCKk3BJhrpGMb@BwA)

---

Original Code:

```hs
f x|or$zipWith(>)x(tail x)=f(take(div(length x)2)x)|1>0=x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia/SKUqsyA8syRDw06zQqMkMTNHoULTNg3Iyk7VSMks08hJzUsvyQAKGmlWaNYY2hnYVvzPTczMU7BVSMlXKCgtCS4p8slTUFEozsgvB1JpCtGGOkY6JjrGOqaxXApwgFOlMVAtYZWmYBONdAxj/wMA)

---

Ungolfed:

```hs
f xs | sorted xs = f (halve xs)
     | otherwise = xs

sorted xs = or (zipWith (>) xs (tail xs))

halve xs = take (length xs `div` 2) xs
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: [56](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia/SKUqsyA8syRDw06zQqUkMTNHocI2TaMkMTtVIyWzTCMnNS@9JEOhQtNIs0KzxtDOwLbif25iZp6CrUJKvkJBaUlwSZFPnoKKQnFGfjmQSlOINtQx0jHRMdYxjeVSgAOcKo2BagmrNAWbaKRjGPsfAA)

Comment: [57 :(](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia/SKUqsyA8syRDw07TRsuuJDEzR6XCNk2jJDE7VSMls0wjJzUvvSRDoULTSLNCs8bQzsC24n9uYmaegq1CSr5CQWlJcEmRT56CikJxRn45kEpTiDbUMdIx0THWMY3lUoADnCqNgWoJqzQFm2ikYxj7HwA)

Comment: [55](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hoia/SKUqsyA8syRDw06zQqUkMTNHocI2DcjITtVIySzTyEnNSy/JUKjQNNKsqDG0M7Ct@J@bmJmnYKuQkq9QUFoSXFLkk6egolCckV8OpNIUog11jHRMdIx1TGO5FOAAp0pjoFrCKk3BJhrpGMb@BwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
-x=x>sort(x) ? -x[1:2:end] : x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/X7fCtsKuOL@oRKNCU8FeQbci2tDKyCo1LyVWwUqh4n9BUWZeSU6ehm60oY6RjrGOSawmF7IYRBRIo4kb6xjFav4HAA)

Takes every second element of the array if not sorted.

Comment: use an ASCII operator like `-` for 20 bytes. also we almost always don't count chars :| so it'd be nice if that was removed from the header

Comment: Changed that. Thanks for 2 bytes!

Answer (score 3):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>22</s> 20 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{(*2 0N#x;x)x~x@<x}/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v1pDy0jBwE@5wrpCs6KuwsGmolbfUsEQBP//BwA)

Iterate over the input until it's sorted... if it's not sorted take first n/2 items.

```
{(*2 0N#x;x)x~x@<x}/ / the solution
{                 }/ / lambda that iterates
                <x   / indices that sort x ascending (<)
              x@     / apply (@) these indices back to x
            x~       / matches (~) x? returns 0 or 1
 (       ; )         / 2-item list which we index into
          x          / original input (ie if list was sorted)
       #x            / reshape (#) x
   2 0N              / as 2 rows
  *                  / take the first one
```

**Edits:**

- **-2** bytes thanks to ngn

Comment: `(.5*#x)#x` -> `*2 0N#x`

Comment: I considered doing `2 0N` but assumed it would be longer (without testing), thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 11 bytes

```
tv`1L)ttS-a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v6QswdBHs6QkWDfx//9oQx0FIx0FYx0FEx0F01gA)

This works by removing every second item.

#### Explanation

```
t      % Take a row vector as input (implicit). Duplicate
v      % Vertically concatenate the two copies of the row vector. When read with
       % linear indexing (down, then across), this effectively repeats each entry
`      % Do...while
  1L)  %   Keep only odd-indexed entries (1-based, linear indexing)
  t    %   Duplicate. This will leave a copy for the next iteration
  tS   %   Duplicate, sort
  -a   %   True if the two arrays differ in any entry
       % End (implicit). A new iteration starts if the top of the stack is true
       % Display (implicit). Prints the array that is left on the stack
```

Comment: Broken for initially sorted list: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] should remain [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: @Falco Thanks! Corrected now

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>10</s> 9 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
£=ëÃæÈeXñ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=oz3rw%2bbIZVjx&input=WzEgMiA0IDMgNV0)

```
£=ëÃæÈeXñ     :Implicit input of array U
£             :Map
 =            :  Reassign to U
  ë           :  Every second element, starting with the first
   Ã          :End map
    æ         :Get the first element that returns true
     È        :When passed through the following function as X
      e       :  Test for equality with
       Xñ     :  X sorted
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 102 bytes

```java
n->{for(;n.stream().reduce((1<<31)+0d,(a,b)->a==.5|b<a?.5:b)==.5;n=n.subList(0,n.size()/2));return n;}
```

There's already a C# answer, so I decided to try my hand on a Java answer.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZPPb8IgFMfv/hUcIQNm1UY3WpclOzovHpcdaMEFV6kB6uJc//butWq2LNnNkgfh1/t@3nuEjdxLtlHvTV5I79GzNPY4QMjYoN1a5hot2yVCG7jHq2AKvjA@JE9llRV6jnL8z8GCCPCrBzD4IIPJ0RJZlDaWzY/r0mFhuQ9Oyy0m3GlV5RrjKEnGEbkZKoolzQibyzTl8VeWyAce32ekXQmbgmeVtTA8pDA3nxqT2xEhwulQOYusqBvRgncQCoDP/H1pFNpCfngVnLFvL69IklNyq4MPesvLKvAdHIXCYstzbPXHr7wfnZOHDvtnz3Ppu/1I0ZGiY0UnisaKQBPXl590hB7kQXh2fdWZoizqJdi4Kwfo9yA/7orc2dW148sbjnoJnUXwf9rO7hQFY7OuSGyq6LQn2pky/eGegBdaPaibbw)

Comment: Time to try [F#](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16116/tips-for-golfing-in-f/) :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to Zgarb*

```
ΩΛ<Ċ2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zKc7NtjnQZ/f//P9pQx0jHRMdYxzQWAA)

#### Explanation

```
ΩΛ<Ċ2
Ω         Repeat until
 Λ<         all adjacent pairs are sorted (which means the list is sorted)
   Ċ2         drop every second element from the list
```

Comment: This is 11 bytes, not 6.

› echo -n "ΩΛ<(←½" | wc --bytes
11

Comment: @MikeHoller https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage

Comment: @MikeHoller As many other golfing languages, Husk uses a custom code page, in order to have access to more different characters: https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/wiki/Codepage

Comment: Thank you, I learned something today :)

Comment: Use `Ċ2` instead of `(←½` to save a byte.

Answer (score 2):

## [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/), <s>59</s> 50 bytes

With `Array#sort` (**<s>59</s> 50 bytes**):

```rb
def f(a);while a!=a.sort;a.pop a.size//2;end;a;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/PyU1TSFNI1HTujwjMydVIVHRNlGvOL@oxDpRryC/QAHIyaxK1dc3sk7NS7FOBJH/CxTSFKINdRSMdBSMY7nAPBMwzxBCmQJZYIZJ7H8A)

Without `Array#sort` (**<s>102</s> 93 bytes**):

```rb
def f(a);while a.map_with_index{|e,i|e>a.fetch i+1,Int32::MAX}.any?;a.pop a.size//2;end;a;end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy6qLC5JzPn/PyU1TSFNI1HTujwjMydVIVEvN7EgvjyzJCM@My8ltaK6JlUnsybVLlEvLbUkOUMhU9tQxzOvxNjIysrXMaJWLzGv0t46Ua8gvwCotTizKlVf38g6NS/FOhFE/i9QSFOINtRRMNJRMI7lAvNMwDxDCGUKZIEZJrH/AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 103 bytes

I can't comment, but I improved the version from movatica by reducing the includes, and using auto.

-2 Bytes: ceilingcat
-2 Bytes: ASCII-only

```cpp
#include<regex>
auto f(auto l){while(!std::is_sorted(l.begin(),l.end()))l.resize(l.size()/2);return l;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5BTsMwEEXX9SmGIiRbcoMoohVJyTW6QULBHqeWpnZkOyEiytVJTViw@iPNn/dGdd2uVWpZ7q1T1Gs8BWxxrFnTJw@Gr0Fi@rpYQn4Xky5LGz@iDwk1p@ITW@u4kFSg01wIQUXAaL8x79YQj3tRBUx9cEDV/O9RmWV9zZh1Ca7NLwUmtlmFA7xl9yobUCUfTrlUT08S9hKeJbxKeJFwkHCcRcU2xgf4@3SEEobMgS7kC8O3D/rdbSWMooKZzcuPMtS0cdkZ5Z3CLuXx3BDdAA)

Comment: any reason you can't just use `l.size()/2`?

Comment: Yes, it does not work that way :)

Comment: what do you mean? returning a list of size `(n+1)/2` or `(n-1)/2` are both valid. hmm....

Comment: Ohh oops did'nt see that thanks

Answer (score 1):

## [VDM-SL](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/overturetool/documentation/master/documentation/VDM10LangMan/VDM10_lang_man.pdf), 99 bytes

```
f(i)==if forall x in set inds i&x=1or i(x-1)<=i(x) then i else f([i(y)|y in set inds i&y mod 2=0])
```

Never submitted in vdm before, so not certain on language specific rules. So I've submitted as a function definition which takes a `seq of int` and returns a `seq of int`

A full program to run might look like this:

```
functions
f:seq of int +>seq of int
f(i)==if forall x in set inds i&x=1or i(x-1)<=i(x) then i else f([i(y)|y in set inds i&y mod 2=0])
```

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 10 bytes

```
.W!SIHhc2Z
```

Try it online [here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.W%21SIHhc2Z&input=%5B1%2C2%2C4%2C3%2C5%5D&debug=0). This removes the second half on each iteration, rounding down. To change it to remove the first half, rounding up, change the `h` to `e`.

```
.W!SIHhc2ZQ   Q=eval(input())
              Trailing Q inferred
  !SIH        Condition function - input variable is H
   SIH          Is H invariant under sorting?
  !             Logical not
      hc2Z    Iteration function - input variable is Z
       c2Z      Split Z into 2 halves, breaking ties to the left
      h         Take the first half
.W        Q   With initial value Q, execute iteration function while condition function is true
```

Comment: Taking every other element of the list is shorter. Replace `hc` with `%`.
This also lets you delete the trailing lambda variable `Z` and let Pyth fill it implicitly, for a total 2 bytes saved.

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>139</s> <s>137</s> 116 bytes

*-2 bytes thanx to ceilingcat, -21 bytes thanx to PeterZuger*

```cpp
#include<regex>
auto f(std::vector<int>l){while(!std::is_sorted(l.begin(),l.end()))l.resize(-~l.size()/2);return l;}
```

Resize the vector to its first half until it's sorted.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5hS8MwGIQ/L7/i3BDyQlZxQ8V29pcMZCZvayAmJU2rWOpf77J@8dvB3T13uuv2rdbLsrNeu8HwKXLLP7W4DCmgkX0yZTmyTiGerE@1o@n70zqWd6tj@/c@xMRGuuKDW@slKVewN5KIXBG5t78s93@uWAU9HKiKnIbo4ar5f1Rnmg21EHkDX5cbB5PYrCdGvOUj06PCQeGo8KrwpPCs8DJTJTZNiJBrkFFizD10MWMaub03Z79VYKowi3m5Ag)

Comment: Imports are rquired to be included in the byte count, so you have to add the `include`s

Comment: Thanx, i'll add them.

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 33 bytes

```julia
-a=issorted(a) ? a : -a[1:end÷2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/XzfRNrO4OL@oJDVFI1FTwV4hUcFKQTcx2tAqNS/l8Haj2P8OxRn55Qq60YY6RjomOsY6prFcCCEFIx0FYx0FEyCJLGwEVAfCJjqmOmY65joWQGgJZBka6RgZgoRNkKQQGkHGG0I1mkPkY/8DAA)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 2, 51 bytes

```python
a=input()
while a!=sorted(a):a=a[:len(a)/2]
print a
```

nice!

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
ΩS=Oo←½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zKYFv//EdtEw7t/f//f7ShjpGOsY6JjnEsAA)

removes last half.

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
m⁻Ṣ$¿2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/3UePuhzsXqRzab/T/cPujpjX//0cb6hjpGOuY6JjG6ijAOcaxAA)

Very similar to [Erik](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/182256/66833)'s existing answer, but I came up with this independently, and Erik's no longer active.

### How it works

```
m⁻Ṣ$¿2 - Main link. Takes a list L on the left
    ¿  - Loop while the condition is false, updating L each time:
   $   -   Condition:
  Ṣ    -     L sorted
 ⁻     -     L ≠ L sorted
m    2 -   Body: Take every second element of L
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, <s>12</s> 11 bytes

```
$<=a?afVUWa
```

Takes the list as a command-line argument in Pip list format, e.g. `[1;2;4;3;5]`. The `-x` flag makes sure this is treated as a list rather than a string, and the `-p` flag formats the output list in the same way. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip)

(Pip Classic doesn't support the `-x` flag, but here's a simulated version: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@O@pkOhgY6Bga6ugpMSlkGilEJb4X8XGNtE@MS0sNDzx////ugX/ow2tjaxNrI2tTWMB))

#### Explanation

A recursive solution:

```lisp
$<=a?afVUWa
   a         ; First argument (the list)
$<=          ; Fold on <= (truthy if each element is <= the one after it)
    ?        ; If truthy, return:
     a       ;  The list unchanged
             ; Otherwise, return:
      f      ;  The main function
       V     ;  called with the following arglist:
        UWa  ;   Unweave the list into two sublists of every other element
```

For example, `UW[1;2;4;3;5]` returns `[[1;4;5];[2;3]]`. This list is passed as the arglist to the recursive call, as if we had called `f` with the arguments `[1;4;5]` and `[2;3]`. Since our function only uses its first argument, though, this is equivalent to simply recursing with an argument of `[1;4;5]`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), 38 bytes

```
\d+
*
/(_+),(?!\1)/+`,_+(,?)
$1
_+
$.&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/PyZFm0uLS18jXltTR8NeMcZQU187QSdeW0PHXpNLxZArXptLRU/t/39DHSMdEx1jHVMA) Takes comma-separated numbers. Explanation:

```
\d+
*
```

Convert to unary.

```
/(_+),(?!\1)/+`
```

Repeat while the list is unsorted...

```
,_+(,?)
$1
```

... delete every even element.

```
_+
$.&
```

Convert to decimal.

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 66 bytes

Snaps off the second half of the list each iteration (`n/2+1` elements if the length is odd).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc5Br4IwDADgO7@iITHZtOYxxIPWvT/C4zBGME10GMUT4bfzisvz5ktYD1varl/99uz9NPXKYUDWHPq1o@FybLu7YpsRn8LWkOZWuZKrb1duNlzpIXzZnM5d38GFRmcDjdPVcVAahkRmgCsrsDAYzHGHBe4lCnnlaEZ6NQQpz6jJNCUvTJIsyYzkOkEgEEknALe7lFqVrpqfkCLMa8iX27N/qNTKSXWcWP9HRq7Gw0Kt/qT5P20WirfgsVgo@E9CE4UDmhhvo8H9QqOJxjj9Ag)

Takes input as a pointer to the start of an array of `int` followed by its length. Outputs by returning the new length of the array (sorts in-place).

```c
t(a,n,i)int*a;{l:for(i=0;i<n-1;)if(a[i]>a[++i]){n/=2;goto l;}a=n;}
```

Ungolfed version:

```c
t(a, n, i) int *a; { // take input as a pointer to an array of int, followed by its length; declare a loop variable i
  l: // jump label, will be goto'ed after each snap
  for(i = 0; i < n - 1; ) { // go through the whole array …
    if(a[i] > a[++i]) { // … if two elements are in the wrong order …
      n /= 2; // … snap off the second half …
      goto l; // … and start over
    }
  }
  a = n; // implicitly return the new length
}
```

Comment: Suggest `~i+n` instead of `i<n-1`

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 65 bytes

```clj
(defn t[l](if(apply <= l)l(recur(take(/(count l)2)(shuffle l)))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VYo5DoQwEATzfcWE7QhxZfASRIC8Y3GMjOUdB/t6Y4d0UFKXysp9psg548vOky6y4nDYQpA/TTOJEUS2KUK3i9HA3slr0Z3Bb0/OCZdTlxHi4VU8QWlpqaN@NebzskOxbcVINRhKkB8)

Comment: [45?](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv3/XyMlNS1PoSQ6J1YjM00jsaAgp1LBxlYhRzNHo0SjJDE7VTevJEPBCCgABP81Cooy80py8hQ0ShSiDYHCxrGamlwooiZAUUMQYaoAUmACVPAfAA)

Comment: [43?](https://tio.run/##XYoxDoAgEAR7X3HlUVig2OlLCIVRiOgFCTkLX49H6xZbzMxG9/kUX3H3AbhiSMCWHMaAa870wrwAKUJGXi/fJz5gECCrqsNcYmJKgAxWixid@lEjVLeboAVGgvoB) [42?](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKaplDyX1kjM00jsaAgp1LBxlZB1VBT1VCjKDW5tEijJDE7VTevJEPBCCSsqflfk0ujoCgzryQnT0GjRCHaEChhHKuJJmoCFDUEEaYKIAUmQAX/AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## MATLAB, 57 bytes

Callable as `f(a)`, where `a=[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
f=@(x)eval('while~isequal(sort(x),x);x=x(1:end/2);end;x')
```

Example of usage:

```
>> a = [1, 2, 4, 3, 5];
>> f(a)

a =
     1     2
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 51 bytes

***56 (+5)** to call the function, **47 (-4)** if not a function, but saved as an executable with a proper `#!` header (replace the recursive `f` call with `$0`).*

```sh
f(){[ "$*" = "${${(n)@}[*]}" ]&&<<<$@||f $@[0,#/2]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrRCoIwAEXf9xWXNUQlSW2Z0YL9x/BBcKIgEzIK0n372iJ6uZdz7n0vg3sN46Rx122HaTT6im4m@tlOWPQDWQbKgqbE9XGyKo8pxc3XytbYJNKqtLEUTRQJIZjcth5Mqny/O5SNdQFINxvtCpQ4guOECmfUpPZZeeLelihI8Vs5Lsi/HP7/JB8)

There is no "is-sorted" builtin in zsh, but there are some "sort-array" builtins. We use the parameter expansion flag `n`, but `o` or `i` would also work. We then have to use `[*]` and quote to induce joining. This is shorter than alternatives (like zipping them together and comparing pairwise).

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic (TI-84), <s>29</s> <s>30</s> 36 bytes

```basic
Ans->L₁
While 1<dim(L₁
If 0≤min(ΔList(L₁:Then
L₁
Return:End
iPart(.5dim(L₁->dim(L₁
End
```

Input and output are through `Ans`.

Comment: L1 is not legal input; you need to either use Ans or write Input L1. Same for output, either Ans or display.

Answer (score 0):

## C++ 17 , 589 bytes

I used recursion to solve it. Submitted this solution in codeforces and got accepted. Btw, I still can't stop laughing! I mean seriously, Thanos sort!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std;int n, *a; int f(int start123, int end123){int start, end;start = start123; end = end123;if(start == end){    return 1; }int ret=0, temp=0;bool flag  = true;for(int i=start; i<end; i++){ if(a[i]<=a[i+1]){   ret++; }else{    flag=false; break; } }int mid = (start+end)>>1; if(flag){    ret=ret+1; }else{ int a,b; a =  f(start, mid);b = f(mid+1, end);ret = max( a, b );}return ret;}int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){    cin>>n;a = new int[n+10];for(int i=1; i<=n; i++){cin>>a[i];}int ans = f(1,n);cout<<ans<<"\n";if(!a)delete[] a;return 0;}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to PPCG, the criterion of this question is code-golf, that means we are trying to solve the problem in as few bytes as possible. Typically people will post the number of bytes for their answer along with the answer (so for yours: 1120 bytes), your aim should be to reduce this! May I recommend starting by removing all unneccesary whitespace, naming your variables with single characters and looking at [tips for golfing in c++](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/132/tips-for-golfing-in-c)

Comment: Thank you Expired Data. I'll try to do better next time

Answer (score 0):

## [F# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>67</s> 61 bytes

```fs
let rec t l=if l=(List.sort l)then l else t l.[0..l.Length/2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY1BCoMwFET3PcUgFMzCtBq7Ci107w3Elfxo4BMl@fdPbaGbkm5mMW8e41Izb5FyZhJEmiHgu3dH1INPotMWj0bJSgEM4kTvhR6vWrMeKCyyXrop79EHcQHV2Fp0Fsait7hNaB44PyvUgh@iTmXH/HVMwek/sPTzJSq/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 32 bytes

```perl6
{($_,*[^*/2]...{[<=] @$_})[*-1]}
```

*-2 bytes thanks to Jo King*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZm@79aQyVeRys6TkvfKFZPT6862sY2VsFBJb5WM1pL1zC29r81V3FipUKago2hgpGCsYKJgqkdhpCxnfV/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, 50 bytes

```perl
@b=sort{$a-$b}@F while"@b"ne"@F"&&($#F/=2);say"@F"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/98hybY4v6ikWiVRVyWp1sFNoTwjMydVySFJKQ9IuimpqWmoKLvp2xppWhcnVoJE/v83VDBSMFMwUTD9l19QkpmfV/xf19dUz8DQ4L9uIgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/) (2018 edition), <s>79</s> 78 bytes

```rust
|v:&mut Vec<_>|while{let q=&mut v.clone();q.sort();q<v}{v.resize(v.len()/2,0)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9BbsIwEEX3nGLKInIk45KklDbgdtUTgLpBEUKuQy0Zu9jGlRpy9aaOA1QaaUb/fc2fMSfrulrBYScUSqEZAUjuoAbanX2ZHE4O3jlbbl/O359C8qaHRxp1T5jUiqN0cSRWG9cPS982nhhuxQ9Hnkgelt7neJq23SKsZlpZB@u31XpVQrJJNqLIqwpomAOF0DIMOYYHDAWGWYUv6jOG7FY3dfAW0T7DMMfwGFnVR9XagOMhTaghMP42fNdfHxmNjTi99ZyF@6OjRsnVcFG@jFBOqjs0bsrXdoz/WTtqu19Wy93edpMJ/xBOaEXzafb0Bw)

This will be golfable if [`slice::is_sorted`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_sorted) gets stabilized, but right now the required feature flag offsets all gains.

Comment: feature flags are free though :P - they just count as a separate language

Comment: @ASCII-only for Rust, feature flags are not commandline arguments, but special syntax in the code itself.

Comment: Huh, no commandline option (like C# and Haskell) huh

Answer (score 0):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 86 bytes

```php
function t($a){for(;$n=$a[+$i++];$l=$n)$f|=$n<$l;return$f?t(array_slice($a,$i/2)):$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7dCoMwDIXvfYoggbVYGPu7sZO9w9idk1GkYodUaevFcD67y3QMxkIg4eTL4XR1Nx1PXd1FEQbtg4cM8gio8o2ArYCdgL2AQyH@xd2vuJ/1N1nIqeptGUxrITBUfKhaxyTaDFWeoEmSQmKToeVYPWkcsZFOh95ZrE6BKefU4@YbU2p6FmjWW85TVHKcyEersgb2Cas8zBuHYY6iy7qF1YWUFFYC7q2xjCb1ggmIr/asfd8QEH8BuofFki/I1cYyGqcX)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 60 bytes

```python
a=list(input())
while a!=sorted(a):a=a[0:len(a)//2]
print(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2J7O4RCMzr6C0RENTk6s8IzMnVSFR0bY4v6gkNUUjUdMq0TYx2sAqJzUPyNHXN4rlKijKzCsBcv7/jzbUMdIx1jHRMY0FAA)

If it has to be a list:

```python
a=[1,34,2,42,3,4,5,23,4,12,34,53,65]
while a!=sorted(a):a=a[0:len(a)//2]
print(a)
```

this one even has a self scrambling thingy!

```python
import random
a=list(input())
random.shuffle(a)
while a!=sorted(a):a=a[0:len(a)//2]
print(a)
```

---

#### Explanation:

```python
a=list(input())       #ask for a string(that will be converted to a list)
while a!=sorted(a):   #while the actual sorted list *isn't* sorted,
    a=a[0:len(a)//2]  #it now equals the first half of it.
print(a)              #print it out!
```

Comment: Welcome to the site and nice first answer! I've edited it slightly so that other users can run and test your code, and that the formatting's fixed. One thing to note: `list(input())` doesn't give you an actual list, it just converts the input *string* into a list (hence why the TIO link outputs `['[']`. Changing it to `eval(input())` works for no extra bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2tSwxRyMzr6C0RENTk6s8IzMnVSFR0bY4v6gkNUUjUdMq0TYx2sAqJzUPyNHXN4rlKijKzCsBcv7/jzbUMdIx1jHRMY0FAA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks! I doubt that this will win, but it was fun!

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 50 bytes

```factor
[ [ dup [ <= ] monotonic? ] [ halves nip ] until ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY69TsNAEIT7PMXQQQFRHGj4UegiGgoQlZXCctbxKne7l7u1EYry7GYtUdCsZkb6ZqdrWtM8fX2@vW8fcaQsFHDIOiSWAwqdBpKWClIms5@UWQyxsR5Pi8UZK1RY4x4PuABX@KCo48x1nIuhb0IH7WA9IbAH3@zgtdyubpYV2CgW5Bmh/b@uNS5/btbePNWosR@S3@cX7BBV1FS43bip5y@jDxRObgcxDtg5cvZJgY@EO49bjUkLwTK/Tr8)

Removes the first half of the list, where the first half is shorter when there's an odd number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 84 bytes

```scala
def q(t:List[Int]):List[Int]=if(t==t.sorted)t else q(t.grouped(2).map(_.max).toList)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY0xC8IwEIX3/oobc1ACbbdCBkdBJ3EqIrFNS6RN2uQEpfS3x0TByTc83vG94/lWjjLY2121BEepDawZQKd6mOLBpBt8DTvn5Ks5kdNmuGANZ6MJBKwh9RZG9UF7avaGIvxFoXtGQhD31pHqkECNXqU6H5x9zKpjJfJJzuwa/YmcbPrFAFFZsjnu0WjYwhJgRQ5lDhUi/qPVhxZfumVbeAM)