# AoCG2021 Day 23: Finding the best seat

Tags: code-golf, grid

Part of [**Advent of Code Golf 2021**](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/24068/78410) event. See the linked meta post for details.

Related to [AoC2020 Day 11](https://adventofcode.com/2020/day/11), Part 2.

---

You enter the waiting area for a ferry, and you see a bunch of people sitting at a bunch of seats. The seats form a grid like this (`.` is a floor, `L` is an empty seat and `#` is an occupied seat):

```
LL.#L
#.L.L
L.L.L
L.L#.
.#L#L
```

Now, since you value privacy a lot, you try to pick a seat that has the minimum number of people visible from it. A seat is visible from another seat if there is no other seat (empty or occupied; floor doesn't count) exactly on the straight line between the two.

For example (rows and columns are numbered from the top left, starting at 1):

- R1C1 sees R2C1 (directly below it) and the two occupied seats on R5 (because the slope does not allow any other seat in between) but does not see R1C4 (blocked by R1C2) or R4C4 (blocked by R3C3).
- R1C2 does not see R5C4 (due to R3C3 at slope 2/1) but sees the other four.
- R3C1 and R4C3 see all five occupied seats.
- R4C1 sees only two.

Therefore, R4C1 is the best choice for you, and the anti-privacy (the number of occupied seats you can see) of that seat is 2.

Given a grid like this, calculate the minimum anti-privacy over all empty seats.

**Input:** A rectangular grid with three distinct values (you can choose which values to use) for floor, empty seat, and occupied seat, respectively. It is guaranteed that the input contains at least one empty seat.

**Output:** The answer to the problem.

Standard [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) rules apply. The shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
L -> 0

LL# -> 0

####
####
####
###L -> 9

.#L.
L..L
#L#L
LL.# -> 3


LL.#L
#.L.L
L.L.L
L.L#.
.#L#L -> 2
```

Comment: [Loosely related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/162337/seats-in-a-finnish-cinema)

Answer (score 4):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 122 bytes

```javascript
a=>w=>Math.min(...a.map((x,i)=>a.map((y,j)=>t+=x|y&!a.some((z,k)=>z<2&(p=k-i)*(q=j-k)>0&p/(k%w-i%w)==q/(j%w-k%w)),t=0)|t))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NbsIwEIX3PkWqCDJTkgnqljq77lz1AICEFRJwfpyArQYQd08H2iLhxdjvezMjv0p/a5cfTe8T222LsZSjltkgs0/t99QaC0SkqdU9wCk2KLM/cY4rFn4mT9fz9EWT69oC4BLXTC/vb1PoZZ0YfIWDrJIas/m0T6GeDImZDCjlIYWKBQPE2Ms5Xj3i6Avnc@0KF8hgI5QQSoVChHyeCzsUKhKKSIlQsVaKuPN@MSHFXP3XkG7dzDfkj6YFJNc3xkO6sis7S/EeyAcyC5ae3z7fQ7rkqXW6@/XymxcxicjYbXH6KiHnbwf@IaOVjXCNCyEeEajsjh@ad8FSx8GwxtuSvLOuawpquh2UoBE4Pi7GHw)

Input flatten array and width. `L` -> 0, `#` -> 1, `.` -> 2.

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 89 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔⟦⟧θＦＬυＦ⌕Ａ§υιL⊞θΣＥυ↨¹Ｅ⌕Ａλ#⬤υ⬤π∨⁼ς.∨∧⁼ρι⁼σκ∨∧⁼ρμ⁼σξ∨⁻×⁻ρι⁻σξ×⁻ρμ⁻σκ∨⁻‹ρι‹μρ⁻‹σκ‹ξσＩ⌊θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZFLa8MwEITv/hWLfVmDaug5J7e0EFBoIL2VHkSsxqKSYuuR@t@7Kz9CUuqDrJn9ZgTSsRXueBZ6HH9apSXg1nYxHIJT9oRlCfvoW4wMVLnJau/VyeLHJ4Oe5NfZAXJpT4EIQif9qmxTa4112NpGDnOUQc7ztaxncIgGd6JLwyfhJT4ySHLNauKLnFJJxPnXMXhz@NJHoT1eCKgSQFZtm9V281mL8gy@y/8Yc8cMC7NTNnp8V0b6Zb/UzWIl/wDmFqDjbru49NeSaW8YuPIamKwptYwHBr68@zbZnt4h4LPwIZUqQxfXp8E4cl4VPCsqXvGMr2tRZeSSPz5c9C8) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a list of newline-terminated lines. Explanation:

```
ＷＳ⊞υι
```

Input the grid.

```
≔⟦⟧θ
```

Start building up the anti-privacy numbers.

```
ＦＬυＦ⌕Ａ§υιL
```

Loop over all of the empty seats. (These loops have to use `For` rather than `Map` because Charcoal only has 11 loop variables, I'm already using 10, and each `Map` uses up an extra loop variable. Also, taking the minimum of a doubly nested loop is tricky when the inner loop could be empty.)

```
⊞θΣＥυ↨¹Ｅ⌕Ａλ#⬤υ⬤π∨⁼ς.∨∧⁼ρι⁼σκ∨∧⁼ρμ⁼σξ∨⁻×⁻ρι⁻σξ×⁻ρμ⁻σκ∨⁻‹ρι‹μρ⁻‹σκ‹ξσ
```

Loop over all occupied seats, then check all seats, counting only those occupied seats that are visible.

```
Ｉ⌊θ
```

Output the minimum number of visible occupied seats.

To check whether a seat blocks the view between an empty seat and an occupied seat, I need to know:

- That the seat is on the line joining the empty and occupied seats
- That the seat is between the empty and occupied seats

Testing that the seat is on the line is done using the cross product of the displacements - `(s−e)×(s−o)` is zero in that case. Testing that the seat is between the other seats could have been done using the dot product - both `(s−e)⋅(o−e)` and `(s−o)⋅(e−o)` need to be strictly positive. Unfortunately this takes 94 bytes and it was golfier to test that the seat is in the minimal containing rectangle but is not actually either the empty or occupied seat under consideration.

80 bytes using the newer version of Charcoal on ATO:

```
ＷＳ⊞υιＩ⌊ΣＥυＥ⌕ＡιL↨¹ΣＥυＥ⌕Ａν#⬤υ⬤ς∨⁼τ.∨∧⁼σκ⁼δλ∨∧⁼σξ⁼δρ∨⁻×⁻σκ⁻δρ×⁻σξ⁻δλ∨⁻‹σκ‹ξσ⁻‹δλ‹ρδ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dZHNSsQwEIDx2qcY2ssEsgVvwp5WURCyuLDexENsuzaYxjWTrL37GF72oOhT-CA-jWmbLutfIJnMl28mgTy_F7W0xb3U2-2rd6vJ0efB02OtdAV4btbeLZ1V5hYZg4WnGj0HxabJIkCHJ5IczpVRjW9wGeZcrjujC2fKlDOtUXFIRco4HEuq8JDDP54JXtZ5XeKHsOFwYfH0wUtN6IKQd0JAM1OOmDjcBRizkoNmfzntN8dGJ7zdE16qpqK4j-2GZDR_CO2-EK7b7yUq2jXp9y0HYruCHvVV8dhyKNnvMX2hm4Lij7xdpZONTq8_hMgzkWS5yEUixjXLk0ADH-Qv) Link is to verbose version of code. Byte savings come from being able to use 12 loop variables (particularly useful for the outer loop as I get both the row and index) and being able to flatten a list of lists. A further byte could be saved if at least one seat was occupied.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 148 bytes

```
a->c=concat;[p,q]=[c([[[i,j]|j<-[1..#a],a[i,j]==t]|i<-[1..#a~]])|t<-[1,2]];vecmin([#[1|y<-q,![u*v~>0|z<-c(p,q),!matdet(Mat([u=x-z,v=z-y]~))]]|x<-p])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU5LasMwEL2Kk2ykMgpWtrJ8g55gmMWgJkGhcZWgmNgIX92V1Ba6CMOg99NjAt@9Oof11NiVVe@s@xocR4MBbmTRCUT0cKF06RTq/X7HBFwVayMl/6cuRDLFwuBAZMaju/pB4A51mjp1gw0@3salb9PcKSdyuYTNlePHMYp3jgIf9qlmGO2sJlqkJErPTgWSK4fwOQluVN@Eux9ihttCts1JsJTQYPmvM6g9GsoBRT5AHfP61ZQjbQHQmrx5tCksrykl2SuRX1jNtmJd4/9RdsxPVenNN38D)

Answer (score 1):

## TypeScript Types, 994 bytes

```ts
//@ts-ignore
type a<T,N=[]>=T extends`${N["length"]}`?N:a<T,[...N,0]>;type b<A,B>=A extends[...B,...infer X]?b<X,B>:A;type c<A,B>=[]extends A|B?Exclude<A|B,[]>:c<B,b<A,B>>;type d<A,B,X=0>=B extends[infer Y,...infer B]?d<e<A,[Y[],[1,0]][X][Y]>,B,X>:A;type e<T,P=0,N=[1,0][P]>=T extends[N,...infer T]?T:[...T,P];type f<T>=d<[],T,1>;type g<T,N=[]>=(T extends T?(x:()=>T)=>0:0)extends(x:infer U)=>0?U extends()=>infer V?g<Exclude<T,V>,[...N,0]>:N:0;type h<G,P,S,Q=[d<P[0],S[0]>,d<P[1],S[1]>],V=G[Q[0]["length"]][Q[1]["length"]]>=Q extends 0[][]?[2,V]extends[V,2]?Q:[0,V]extends[V,0]?h<G,Q,S>:never:never;type i<T,K=keyof T>=T extends T?keyof T extends K?T:never:0;type M<G,P={[X in keyof G]:G[X]extends infer R?{[Y in keyof R]:[a<X>,a<Y>]}:0}[number][number],S=(P extends P?c<P[0],P[1]>extends[0]?P|[f<P[0]>,P[1]]|[P[0],f<P[1]>]|[f<P[0]>,f<P[1]>]:never:0),>=i<{[X in keyof G]:G[X]extends infer R?{[Y in keyof R]:R[Y]extends 1?g<S extends S?h<G,[a<X>,a<Y>],S>:0>:never}:0}[number][number]>["length"]
```

[Try It Online!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTACBcGcFoEsHMB2B7ATgUwFDgJ4Ad0ACAQwB4AVAGgDkBeAbQF0A+W8w9AD3HUQBNIAAwAkAb2r0ARABte8cAAtJjAL6CA-NQBcZKvQB0h6pQAMLANy4ChAEakAgpQBCrex268BBw08qH9sIgAZuiohAAajOp24c7MWvaW+EQAxg5xDIxcPPyQhPYAPk7qAKKcKdIArnzoDkWUTPFpvnaOLsxJ1nzpvuG0JqxO7jlegSFhAJp+hmOhhE5R3bWO9BNMDQCMpoyM9JGrLM6U4fGJVkS1VAAK-TQMW2b0Vyxsw56Q9Mb+s2HkUeRabz6a6MTpEIIUVjddZUDYdc6EeAUO6NWgACnY2XehHI6jRnC0aIAlLRmOQScwTFoTESsbl8VofoQAKoUkzqZlvekUpkANXUSLKFWql0ovOYDX8xjM8W0JjBhAUpAA4pQrpQAMqUACKDG6V3oZk1hsO+voG0YxotzEtvNoyvo2pNUlkiHkSh2jvNuxkckUyhe2q5AkIJiYTHU9AATGKsh5cvReZQo1FtYCTLG6V4k2Z1ErVdrNfFEOgAG6hLQl8uoBWwZEAaVoAGt0DhkEEcaxMfGQ7iW22O92Rnl6+oAVWK-KEQBZFVq2iiPaEQKEfvtwjKxhaB2RLN5JkAJXUi4my8Qq9b64PW-oZBOlDIExtKmpKnoiEqAFsbKFdh-v7+mrolcwZ5Fc6hpAaRoGtae4muoVwFPQEJQYcME7EhqGUCh3o2khOEythpDoTalZlpORKUKwdaLuEZ4XgOG5bjucbDme4yEEeJ70WuHbXloB4HHuhAbAKpAaqBhAanmc63qQ96PjaRbUsW5GoC+Jhvv+P6oH+X46SwLp+h6mDYMkOImIQtCELO9CYCAhCOQAeuomCOd6lCYCwpkIuQGxWTZpB2Q5zmue5WxbCmnneWZ1jkFGAW2fZwCOYQLluYQ0bJtlUUZVlMYFZaeUFTlRXuSVMYWtFzA+eZ5AAMyJUFyWpel7kZpV2yeeFpi9VVxWUJFg1lZlEW9blMW+QALE1wUpaFeVjR1w3dZlMYZg8K2LX1fUjeaO3rXty1Df13lAA)

### Ungolfed / Explanation

````ts
// Convert a string literal representing a number to a `Nat`
type StrNumToNat<T, N=[]> = T extends `${N["length"]}` ? N : StrNumToNat<T, [...N, 0]>

type ModNat<A, B> = A extends [...B, ...infer X] ? ModNat<X, B> : A

// Calculate the GCD of two `Nat`s using the Euclidean algorithm
type GcdNat<A, B> = [] extends A | B ? Exclude<A | B, []> : GcdNat<B, ModNat<A, B>>

// Add if `X` is `0`, subtract if `X` is `1`
type AddOrSubInt<A, B, X=0> = B extends [infer Y, ...infer B] ? AddOrSubInt<IncOrDecInt<A, [Y[],[1,0]][X][Y]>, B, X> : A

// Increment if `P` is `0`, decrement if `P` is `1`
type IncOrDecInt<T, P=0, N=[1,0][P]> = T extends [N, ...infer T] ? T : [...T, P]

type NegInt<T> = AddOrSubInt<[], T, 1>

type CountUnion<T,N=[]>=(T extends T?(x:()=>T)=>0:0)extends(x:infer U)=>0?U extends()=>infer V?CountUnion<Exclude<T,V>,[...N,0]>:N:0;

// Filter a union of tuples for those with the shortest length
type Shortest<T, K=keyof T> = T extends T ? keyof T extends K ? T : never : 0

// Extrapolate the line of sight for a given slope.
// If the first seat is occupied, return its position; otherwise, return never.
type GetSeat<
  Grid,
  Pos,
  Slope,
  // Add Slope to Pos
  NextPos = [AddOrSubInt<Pos[0], Slope[0]>, AddOrSubInt<Pos[1], Slope[1]>],
  // Get the value at NextPos
  NextSeatVal = Grid[NextPos[0]["length"]][NextPos[1]["length"]],
> =
  // Both coordinates of NextPos are non-negative
  NextPos extends 0[][]
    // If NextSeatVal == 2
    ? [2, NextSeatVal] extends [NextSeatVal, 2]
      // Return NextPos
      ? NextPos
      // Otherwise, if NextSeatVal == 0
      : [0, NextSeatVal] extends [NextSeatVal, 0]
        // Continue down the line of sight
        ? GetSeat<Grid, NextPos, Slope>
        // Otherwise, return never
        : never
    : never

type Main<
  Grid,
  Positions = {
    // Map over the rows
    [X in keyof Grid]: Grid[X] extends infer Row ? {
      // Map over the cells
      [Y in keyof Row]:
        // Return the coordinate as a [Nat, Nat]
        [StrNumToNat<X>, StrNumToNat<Y>]
    } : 0
  // Collect a union of all results
  }[number][number],
  Slopes = (
    // Map over Positions
    Positions extends Positions
      // (note that Positions is now a singular [Nat, Nat])
      // If X and Y are coprime
      ? GcdNat<Positions[0], Positions[1]> extends [0]
        // Return a union of this slope and all reflections of it
        ? Positions
        | [NegInt<Positions[0]>, Positions[1]]
        | [Positions[0], NegInt<Positions[1]>]
        | [NegInt<Positions[0]>, NegInt<Positions[1]>]
        : never
      : 0
  ),
> =
// Get the shortest of:
Shortest<
  {
    // Map over the rows
    [X in keyof Grid]: Grid[X] extends infer Row ? {
      // Map over the cells
      [Y in keyof Row]:
        // If this seat is empty
        Row[Y] extends 1
          // Return the number of slopes where an occupied seat is visible
          ? CountUnion<Slopes extends Slopes ? GetSeat<Grid, [StrNumToNat<X>, StrNumToNat<Y>], Slopes> : 0>
          // Otherwise, return never
          : never
    } : 0
  // Unionize
  }[number][number]
// To number
>["length"]
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 95 bytes

```
Min[p=Position;Count[Or@@@#,1<0]&/@Outer[Det@{u=#-#3,v=#3-#2}==0<u.v&,#~p~1,#~p~2,p[#,1|2],1]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lU6xCoMwFNz9igcBp1iTONaUQLsW3UMGKUozVMVGF6u/blNjFZdC4XjcO@6Oe2Tmnj8yo2/ZVACfrrqUNU@rpza6Ko/nqi2NTBohBMI0JsoPRdKavJGX3Ii@5ShAEe44igLEBs5J3B46H6OxHul8Ga6lTb6YwlQpf0obbQsRBCcoJFIKfAiFB33f02HAHlhGMViw78ssd5gF@EdYO4l7MZDF8qEz6JahS2Z1OBPbDyM7F3Mluyr6S2PbhnWUWzpMbw)

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 363 bytes:

```
from math import*
r=range
k=lambda x,y:(x//(c:=gcd(x,y)),y//c) 
def p(i,t,b,x,y):
 if i==t:return 1
 return((u:=b[(n:=i[0]+x)][(m:=i[1]+y)])!='L'or(n,m)==t)and u!='#'and p((n,m),t,b,x,y)
g=lambda b,d:min([sum([p(i,j,b,*k(j[0]-i[0],j[1]-i[1]))for i in d if d[i]=='#'])for j in d if d[j]=='L'])
f=lambda b:g(b,{(x,y):b[x][y]for x in r(len(b))for y in r(len(b[x]))})
```

[try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDLboMwEDzXX@GGA@vEIY16qSz5D6z@AEUVhEdMsEHGSKCq305t0lSpVBUfrN2d3Z3Z6SZ7bvXzS2fmuTStwiq1ZyxV1xq7RYabVFcFuvAmVVme4pFODMbDAU6MV6ccXE4InQ6HE8EoL0rcgaSWZtQDDGFZYsm5Zaawg9H4iPA1AhgYz2LQjMv4KdmNJIlB@eSY7CaSkEceirA1oKkibgFJdY4HVwxCH3WwAD9MqLoJzGjOlNQQ94OC2KupXc/2ArWj2XsuWjuOvScipGwNllhqnHuleSwT7imSBajvgNoDwgGo/GFiFWT0Y7GAZfGYxFPix0Y/ZqApNGRXhumu4voI@SRzzzebjRBRIFAQiUggcfuDCLlqIBy@OGrb96xNTQ69N/Th28lG9hZU2oEPKC5lYwsDr60uKO6jvmukhfBNh8Q9hDojtYUS7na58lWD5/kPF8FKR@Ae@vWt7XT3Re5Ud68/FHkbVlWsOPXn7PwF)