# The prime frog 

Tags: code-golf, sequence, primes

The "prime frog" is a strange animal that jumps between integers, until it arrives on 3 or 19...

---

Your program should accept an integer `n` as input and output the result of the below algorithm (`3` or `19`).

For a given integer `n >= 2`:

1. Let `f` be the position of the frog. It is initially set to `n`
2. if `f = 3` or `f = 19` : the frog stops jumping - halt the program and output `f`.
3. if `f` is prime : the frog jumps to the position `2×f-1`. Go back to step 2.
4. if `f` is composite : let `d` be `f`'s biggest prime divisor. The frog jumps to the position `f-d`. Go back to step 2.

**Examples:**

An example with `n = 5`:

```
5 > 9 > 6 > 3 stop
```

The program should output `3`.

Another example with `n = 23`:

```
23 > 45 > 40 > 35 > 28 > 21 > 14 > 7 > 13 > 25 > 20 > 15 > 10 > 5 > 9 > 6 > 3 stop
```

Again, the program should output `3`.

**Test cases:**

```
10 => 3
74 => 19
94 => 3
417 => 3
991 => 19
9983 => 19
```

You can assume `1 < n < 1000000` (I have checked the program ends for these values).

Comment: A comment on why I've chosen 3 and 19 as stop criteria : once the frog arrives on one of these numbers, it starts to loop back after a few iterations. 3 and 19 form two distinct loops. It seems all integers eventually arrive to the 3 loop or the 19 loop.

Comment: 3 loop is [3 5 9 6 3] and 19 loop is [19 37 73 145 116 87 58 29 57 38 19]

Comment: Cool Collatz variation.

Comment: I wonder whether there is a mathematical proof or something alike on the topic

Comment: @SuperChafouin I wonder if there's higher primes that fall into a loop.

Comment: @kamoroso94 I haven't checked for bigger values. For n < 1000000, 62% of numbers return 3 and 38% return 19.

Comment: If we cannot prove that the frog always comes to `3` or `19`, we could change item 2. in the algorithm to say that if the frog has entered any loop (encountered a position it has seen before), then it ceases the jumping and returns the smallest member of that loop.

Comment: @Jeppe That was my original algorithm, it would stop whenever it entered a loop. As I noticed it was always the 3-loop or the 19-loop, I thought it would be funnier for golfing to add 3 and 19 as stop conditions.

Comment: @SuperChafouin what should the program do if reaches neither 3 nor 19? Or can we assume the input will?

Comment: @PyRulez If it reaches that, you should probably tell the OP.

Comment: @KeyuGan Maybe this would be a good thing to post about on Math.SE.

Comment: Hold true for first 10^8 primes

Comment: @Abigail Absolutely! If there is a number that never loops, then the frog will tend towards positive infinity; however, I do not see how the frog could ever realize that this was the case, so I do not see how that would change the frog "rules". But it would still be very interesting if someone could prove that all frog sequences are bounded (the prime frog halting problem).

Comment: please add link to math.se if someone posts it there.

Answer (score 15):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>101</s> <s>93</s> <s>92</s> <s>90</s> <s>88</s> <s>87</s> 85 bytes

```python
import sympy
n=input()
while~16&n-3:m=max(sympy.factorint(n));n-=[1-n,m][m<n]
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BDoMgFET3/xTERSNNbaSSKm05iXFhKI0k8iGWprLp1an4kpnNTGZ8DJPDS1LuqWVRFMlY75ZA3tH6CCgN@k8oKXwnM@sfux6wam5W2nEt98r5NargFoOhRErvWMmeVXiyQ28fOIDPCcG0LQPoVSuSj45dYjW0HAQHzloQgm3qms0ywOqdPw)

Comment: `while~16&n!=3` saves a byte.

Comment: Oh, `~16&n-3` even works!

Answer (score 12):

## C (gcc),  <s>87</s>  65 bytes

```
i,k;f(n){for(i=n;i>1;)for(k=i;k%--i;);n=~16&n-3?f(n-k?:n+n-1):n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCsIwEAXQfU8RCpUMdsDQYm2H2Iu4kUhkCB2luCv16jF1q5nd/@@Pw7tzMXIdyGuBxT9mzVaIz4ZgC8EyhQqRCUjs2xx3gs2YthjGQfaCBgahNbK81HRl0VAshUr3nFPldVndLlLWymtzAKD/1LVZ6vPUmi7/1ptfS6K@dmo2XOMH)

**Explanation:**

```
i,k;
f(n)
{
    for (i=n; i>1;)              // Loop until `k` is prime (the largest positive
                                 // `i` inequal to `k` that divides `k` is 1).
        for (k=i; k%--i;);       // Find the largest factor `k`

    n =                          // Returning like this is undefined behaviour,
                                 // but happens to work with gcc. This can be
                                 // replaced with `return` at the cost of 4 bytes.

        ~16&n-3                  // If `n` is 3 or 19, this expression equals 0 and
                                 // the algorithm halts. Otherwise the function
                                 // calls itself to perform the next iteration.

        ? f(n-k ?: n+n-1)        // If `n-k` is non-zero, n is not prime.
                                 // In this case call `f` with the value of `n-k`.
                                 // (Omitting the second `n-k` between `?` and `:`
                                 // is a gcc extension)
                                 // Otherwise call `f` with `2*n-1`.

        : n;                     // All done, `n` is returned.
}
```

**Portable version (72 bytes):**

```
i,k;f(n){for(i=n;i>1;)for(k=i;k%--i;);return~16&n-3?f(n-k?n-k:n+n-1):n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dcvBCoJAEAbgu0@xCMYOudCgZDqYL9JFrI1ha4rFTmKvvq1dy4E5/PP9M5jh1ss1BM4dWS0w2YfX3ArxEQmW4FomlxnDBOQv48vLG/cbMUUX@8Z1cRvZikFohObAMqp7z6IhmRIV5@njyeo0O58kzZXVuAOg/1SVq1SvU4nV@luNvxZFfe1QLDiHDw)

**With more appropriate variable names:**

```
f,r;o(g){for(f=g;f>1;)for(r=f;r%--f;);g=~16&g-3?o(g-r?:g+g-1):g;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dctBCoMwEAXQvacIgiVDDTQotTqkXqSbkjKDixoZuhN79TR222Z2/78/3rD3MVItGDTDSkE0OUa6WoQ9iCOUyhhCQHZvez6waca0NTIOfGRjYWDc4jS/1PM@zRqKtVDpFkkV6bJ63OayVkHbEwD@p67NUp@n1nb5t97@WhL1tUuz4xY/)

Comment: Totally love the play with the word frog and your variables. +1.

Answer (score 10):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

*Thanks to Neil for saving 1 byte.*

```
{`^(11+)(?<!^\2+(11+))(?=\1+$)

^(?!(11+)\1+$|111$|1{19}$)1
$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcixCoAgAEXR/f2FYKAJ0QtBhKKxnxCzoaGlIdqqb7dyuXDusZ7bvuRKpcZA1vlKUZFGq7EXMXSm4NMQaKQGohpFeb9vkl8u@kdqQs5ZTwnMbOEsvIWlg/d8AQ)

Input and output in unary (the test suite uses decimal for convenience). This solution gets incredibly slow for larger inputs. The `9983` test case times out on TIO.

#### Explanation

Due to the `{`, both stages of the program are simply run in a loop until they no longer affect the string. We alternate between a stage processing composites and a stage processing primes. That lets us avoid an actual conditional (which doesn't really exist in Retina). If the current value is the wrong kind for the stage, the stage simply does nothing.

```
^(11+)(?<!^\2+(11+))(?=\1+$)
```

This processes composites. We match a potential divisor with `(11+)`, but then we check that it's not composite with `(?<!^\2+(11+))`, so we only consider prime factors. Due to the greediness of `+`, this prioritise the largest factor. Then we check that this potential divisor is an *actual* divisor by trying to match the rest of the string with repetitions of it, `(?=\1+$)`. This divisor is simply removed from the string, which is how you subtract something in unary.

```
^(?!(11+)\1+$|111$|1{19}$)1
$_
```

This processes primes, except **3** and **19**. The negative lookahead makes sure that the input is not composite, not **3** and not **19**. Then we match a single `1` and replace it with the entire string. This is a unary form of computing **n - 1 + n**, which of course is **2n-1**.

Once we hit **3** or **19**, neither stage can match the string and it will no longer be changed.

Comment: Isn't `1$'` the same as `$_`?

Comment: @Neil Yes......

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 bytes

```
_ÆfṂoḤ’$µÐḶṂ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cFvaw51N@Q93LHnUMFPl0NbDEx7u2AYU@X90z@H2R01r3P//NzTQUTA30VGwNNRRMDE0BzJALEtLC2MA)

#### How it works

```
_ÆfṂoḤ’$µÐḶṂ  Maink link. Argument: n

        µ     Combine the links to the left into a chain.
         ÐḶ   Repeatedly call the chain monadically until the results are no longer
              unique. Yield the loop, i.e., the first occurrence of the first
              repeated integer, up to and excluding the repetition.
              Let's call the argument of the chain k.
_Æf             Subtract all prime factors of k from k.
   Ṃ            Take the minimum of the differences. This yields 0 iff k is prime.
     Ḥ’$        Compute 2k-1.
    o           Take the logical OR of the results.
              The result is now a rotation of either [3, 5, 9, 6] or
              [19, 37, 73, 145, 116, 87, 58, 29, 57, 38].
          Ṃ   Take the minimum, yielding either 3 or 19.
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 65 <del>66</del> <del>68</del> bytes

```
#//.i:Except[3|19]:>If[PrimeQ@i,2i-1,i-#&@@Last@FactorInteger@i]&
```

- *-1 bytes, thanks to Misha Lavrov!*
- *-2 bytes, thanks to Martin!*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7X1lfXy8zXt86U9HWWE0NSBpaWtl5pkUHFGXmpgY6ZOoYZeoa6mTqKqs5OPgkFpc4uCUml@QXeeaVpKanFjlkxqr9ByrNK4lOizY0iI3lgnHMTZA4lsgcE0NzZClLQxSehXFs7H8A)

Inspired by [the tip](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/106652/59292). Basically, it just recreates the algorithm.

`//.` is `RepeatedReplace` and `/;` is `Condition`. So, the code will replace `i_` (a single quantity) with `If[PrimeQ@i,2i-1,i-#&@@Last@FactorInteger@i]`, until `i!=3&&!=19` evaluates `True`.

Benchmark:

[image: benchmark]

Comment: fun fact: this code would not work for larger numbers like `10000000010` because `maximum number of iterations is 2^16 (= 65536)`

Comment: A slightly shorter way to check for 3 and 19 is `#//.i:Except[3|19]:>If[PrimeQ@i,2i-1,i-#&@@Last@FactorInteger@i]&`

Comment: @MishaLavrov but the result is incorrect?

Comment: @KeyuGan For me, the two functions give exactly the same result for integers 1 through 1000.

Comment: Possibly the issue you're having is unprintable characters inserted when you copy and paste from the comments, which sometimes happens.

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
Ω€p57§|o←DṠ-o→p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/51Y@alpTYGp@aHlN/qO2CS4Pdy7QBTImFfz//9/QgMvchMvShMvE0JzL0tIQiC2MAQ)

### Explanation

```
Ω€p57§|o←DṠ-o→p  Implicit input n.
Ω                Do this to n until
 €p57            you get a prime factor of 57 (which are 3 and 19):
            o→p   Take last element of the prime factors of n
          Ṡ-      and subtract it from n,
     §|           or if this gives 0 (so n is prime),
       o←D        double and decrement n.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

```
[ÐƵηfså#pi·<ëDfθ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/8wNWFiMWX//1vDkMa1zrdmc8OlI3Bpwrc8w6tEZs64Lf//MjM)

**Explanation**

```
[      #            # loop until
 Ð   så             # a copy of the current value is contained in
  Ƶηf               # the unique prime factors of 171
        pi          # if the current value is prime
          ·<        # double and decrement
            ë   -   # else subtract
             Dfθ    # the largest prime factor of a copy of the current value
```

Comment: +1 for having an actual frog in your source code `<ë`

Comment: For 57991 more than 1 minute

Comment: @RosLuP: You're better off running very long test cases offline ;)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```js
f=n=>57%n?f(n-(g=(k,d=1)=>++d<k?k%d?g(k,d):g(k/d):d<n?d:1-n)(n)):n%38
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=n=>57%n?f(n-(g=(k,d=1)=>++d<k?k%d?g(k,d):g(k/d):d<n?d:1-n)(n)):n%38

console.log('10   -> ' + f(10))   // 3
console.log('74   -> ' + f(74))   // 19
console.log('94   -> ' + f(94))   // 3
console.log('417  -> ' + f(417))  // 3
console.log('991  -> ' + f(991))  // 19
console.log('9983 -> ' + f(9983)) // 19
```

#### Formatted and commented

```js
f = n =>                 // given n
  57 % n ?               // if n is neither 3, 19 or 57 (and assuming that n is > 1):
    f(                   //   do a recursive call to f() with:
      n -                //     n minus
      (g = (k, d = 1) => //     the result of the recursive function g():
        ++d < k ?        //       increment d; if d is less than k:
          k % d ?        //         if d is not a divisor of k:
            g(k, d)      //           recursive call to g() with k and d unchanged
          :              //         else:
            g(k / d)     //           recursive call to g() with k = k / d, d = 1
        :                //       else, d is now the highest prime divisor of n:
          d < n ?        //         if d is less than n:
            d            //           n is composite: return d, which results in f(n - d)
          :              //         else:
            1 - n        //           n is prime: return 1 - n, which results in f(2n - 1)
      )(n)               //     initial call to g()
    )                    //   end of recursive call to f()
  :                      // else:
    n % 38               //   return n % 38 (gives 19 as expected if n = 57)
```

Comment: Smart, using `57%n` and `n%38` instead of `n==3|n==19`. Saved 1 byte in [my Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145754/52210) as well, so thanks!

Comment: In ideone 57991 input generate prog.js:2:26 InternalError: too much recursion

Comment: In tio f=n=>57%n?f(n-(g=(k,d=1)=>++d<k?k%d?g(k,d):g(k/d):d<n?d:1-n)(n)):n%38

print(f(57991))
generate stop program not output, it seems to me

Comment: @RosLuP This is a code-golf challenge without any specific constraint. [The current consensus](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2282/58563) is that speed or memory limitations (such as the call stack size) can be disregarded unless explicitly stated otherwise in the question. I take it for granted that the 1000000 limit is just informative because the sequence was not tested beyond that. Incidentally, your 70-byte solution is perfectly fine and is probably more relevant than the 93-byte version for a code-golf challenge.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>23</s> 19 bytes

*-4 bytes from [miles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/6710/miles).* Still longer than 05AB1E, though.

```
Ḥ’$_Æf$ÆP?Ṫµḟ3,19$¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASsA1P9qZWxsef//4bik4oCZJF/DhmYkw4ZQP@G5qsK14bifMywxOSTCv////zIz)

Comment: ``Ḥ’$_Æf$ÆP?Ṫµḟ3,19$¿`` using a while loop instead and some re-ordering

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>110</s> <s>105</s> <s>103</s> 101 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to @Lynn*

```python
f=lambda n,i=2,k=0:i/n and(n*(n&~16==3)or f((2*i-1,k-i)[k>0]))or n%i and f(n,i+1,k)or f(n/i,2,k or n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3PDoIwDMbve4peNJtO2SYRIZkvYjjgv9gghWzzwMVXxy42@dqm/fXrNKfXSG7BYRpDgjhHwdrHRwqP2ydEHOmNAybpDIdanv7dDdd7B6TRO91702BB0NFd0kbS@muP3h/UGOAppdvgzup@h@rSn02r8phWmGles8OWt3@WCtRsB5ngL1wQkOBijYaq1FCzSltxU9ucToe2EQBTQEp8jmqxRlSlqEvBmGBKZOgH)

---

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>116</s> <s>112</s> 105 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,i=2:i/n*i or n%i and f(n,i+1)or f(n/i)
n=input()
while~16&n-3:n=[2*n-1,n-f(n)][f(n)<n]
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY3BCoMwGIPv/1MUYcM6xVVFp6xPIh6cVvzBpSKObZe9elcPCSEJfOt3ny0yN9jR6CAI3KSX/vkYe4GYddZwioiF3QROLHqMYgr9cFHSVz6mLAmasb72UNJ75sX8VHlGkjfQbRYhUTESf5Rde/gdHa0bYxdwnkbmYwZxsKPSqStVBdUFFaqiulZet/wP)

Comment: `…n*(n&~16==3)or…` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: For input 57991 sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

*Thanks to [@Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) for removing 1 byte!*

```
`tZp?Eq}tYfX>-]tI19h-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6EkqsDetbC2JDItwk43tsTT0DJD9/9/S0sLYwA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@hJKrA3rWwtiQyLcJON7bE09AyQ/d/rEvIf0MDLnMTLksTLhNDcy5LS0MgtjAGAA).

#### Explanation

```
`           % Do...while
  t         %   Duplicate. Takes (implicit) input the first time
  Zp        %   Is it prime? 
  ?         %   If so
    Eq      %     Times 2, minus 1
  }         %   Else
    t       %     Duplicate
    YfX>-   %     Prime divisors, maximum, subtract
  ]         %   End
  t         %   Duplicate
  I19h      %   Push array [3 19]
  -         %   Subtract, element-wise. The result is truthy if and only if
            %   it doesn't contain any zero
            % End (implicit). Next iteraton if top of the stack is truthy
            % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell - 154 bytes

```
f 3=3
f 19=19
f n
 |(c==[1])=f$2*n-1
 |True=f$n-head c
 where c=z n;v b=reverse[x|x<-[1..(b-1)],b`rem`x==0];z j=case v j of[1]->[1];s->filter((==[1]).v)$s
```

Probably missing some golf tricks here, this is my first attempt at haskell golf.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  You don't need the newlines and spaces for pattern guards.  You can also use `1>0` for `True` most times but often it might be better to use an assignment, for example `c<-z n`.

Comment: `[x|x<-[b-1,b-2..1],rem b x==0]` is also short than `reverse[x|x<-[1..(b-1)],b`rem`x==0]`.

Comment: And one last thing, if you would like to discuss haskell golfing you can join us in [Of Monads and Men](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66515/of-monads-and-men).

Answer (score 3):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
ͻY÷DΞᚫ<#D
```

Explanation:

```
ͻ                   Start infinite loop
 D                  Duplicate
  Y                 Push 57
                   Prime factors: [3 19]
                   If the second-to-top of stack is in the list
      ÷             Break the loop
       D            Duplicate
        Ξᚫ<       If prime, double and decrement
            #D   Otherwise, subtract the largest prime factor
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@xul8gPcyf0f5g7ddbh7S5AZs@5eQ9nrbZRdoEIT1gAlOr6/9/S0sIYAA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>140</s> <s>135</s> <s>134</s> 94 bytes

```java
n->{for(int f,t,m=0;57%n>0;n=f>n?2*n-1:n-m)for(t=n,f=1;f++<t;)for(;t%f<1;t/=m=f);return n%38;}
```

-5 bytes converting recursive Java 7 method to Java 8 lambda with loop.
-1 byte implicit thanks to [*@Arnauld*'s JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145759/52210) by changing `n!=3&n!=19` and `return n;` to `57%n>0` and `return n%38;`.
<s>I think it should be possible to somehow combine the two loops and check if `n` is a prime, and get it's largest prime factor at the same time, but I can't figure it out (yet). So this will be the initial version for now.</s>
-40 whopping bytes thanks to @Nevay, by doing what I couldn't do: combining the loops to check for primes and largest prime factor at once.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here](https://tio.run/##dZLNboJAEMfvPsWExAQKWCkapevaJ6gXj7WH7brbYGEgMJg2hmenC0pqsQWyyfzmk//sQRyFn@UKD/uPRiaiLOFZxHgaAcRIqtBCKti0ZgdA2u2JDjOkHpmjJEGxhA0gcGjQX590VnRB2iMv5VM2X4xxPWXI9RqfHu7QDx7RT502jDh6mgdMu@6KWIcYjfUqYHTPU64dViiqCgQch0tWN6ztmFdviel4aXzM4j2kZmR7S0WM7y@vIJzzvNuvklQ6ySqa5MZFCdpWjHlFO/Oqz1xJUvsdCUmVSFpGqiQoKylVWeoqsbq//LPOxdMm2HMPwms7mA7AQzgAi5kHQXRNotkgZBYsBiSKgpusaBnesvbpc2uAUfeZwY@C1C/VuvhunYXXLbfXxPnZ91kcs1qcSBuL/xXBwrVaDS23r9Lb5xK9Zfduzs8O53KX6uYb) (executes even `999999` in under 1 second).

```java
n->{                  // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  for(int f,          //  Flag-integer
          t,          //  Temp-integer
          m=1;        //  Max prime factor integer, starting at 0
      57%n>0;         //  Loop (1) as long as `n` is not 3, not 19 and not 57:
      n=f>n?          //    After every iteration: if `f` is larger than `n`:
         2*n-1        //     Change `n` to `2*n-1`
        :             //    Else:
         n-m)         //     Change `n` to `n-m`
    for(t=n,          //   Reset `t` to `n`
        f=1;          //   Reset `f` to 1
        f++<t;)       //   Inner loop (2) from 2 to `t` (inclusive)
      for(;t%f<1;     //    Inner loop (3) as long as `t` is divisible by `f`
        t/=m=f;       //     Set `m` to `f`, and set `t` to `t/f`
      );              //    End of inner loop (3)
                      //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                      //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  return n%38;        //  Return `n%38`, which is now either 3 or 19
}                     // End of method
```

Comment: 1 character short of being a C# polyglot :(

Comment: @IanH. Hehe, yes, that's usually the case: `n=>` instead of `n->`. And sometimes lowercase/uppercase calls. ;)

Comment: 94 bytes: `n->{for(int f,t,m=0;57%n>0;n=f>n?2*n-1:n-m)for(t=n,f=1;f++<t;)for(;t%f<1;)t/=m=f;return n%38;}`

Comment: @Nevay Thanks! I just knew it should be possible to combine the loops, but couldn't figure it out. A whopping 40 bytes saved thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [numbers](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/numbers/numbers.pdf), <s>102</s> 99 bytes

```r
function(n){while(!n%in%c(3,19))n="if"(isPrime(n),2*n-1,n-max(primeFactors(n)))
n}
library(numbers)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpBCsIwEADv/YWFwq5swNhCDejVs19IQ4ML7TYkLVrEt8d4mMvMxOyvKvtN3MqLgODn9eRphIM0LI2DlrRBlFvNvgZOj8jzWC46H0VpEjXbN4S/vFu3LjGVhljJt5p4iDbuINs8jDFhTjaEaQcH@kR9R6ajTvdkjC5cWiSP@Qc)

R isn't known for short built-ins, and even the packages follow suit!

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 73 bytes

```bash
((57%$1))&&$0 $[(x=$1-`factor $1|sed 's/.* //'`)?x:2*$1-1]||echo $[$1%38]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifb6uUBKQVVAyUFJQV0jIrFNLyi4A8hZJ8hfL8omyF/DyFEE///xoapuaqKoaammpqKvkKKtEaFbYqhroJaYnJJSD1hjXFqSkK6sX6eloK@vrqCZr2FVZGWkAVhrE1NanJGSAtKoaqxhax////t7S0MAYA) Modified slightly to work on TIO.

Recursively calls its own script file using `$0`, <s>which does not work in TIO because it must be ran as `./filename.sh`</s>. Accepts input as command-line argument.

Uses the same modulus trick as [@Arnauld's JS answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145759/69583).

### Test Cases

```
$ for t in 5 23 10 74 94 417 991 9983;{ echo -n "$t -> "; ./prime-frog.sh $t; }
5 -> 3
23 -> 3
10 -> 3
74 -> 19
94 -> 3
417 -> 3
991 -> 19
9983 -> 19
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 97 bytes

```python
f=lambda n:n*(n&-17==3)or f(n-max(k*all(n%k<k%j for j in range(2,k))for k in range(n+1))or 2*n-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7BDoIwDIbP@hS9IC0O44AEWZzvMqMoDAohO2gIzz63k4f@ab4vbf75694Tl963ejDj/WGAFWfIh1zWWpc0LdAi56P5oM3MMCAn9mqTHtpgeugYFsOvJxbCEkVm/4yPkuKDIuNcko@Wo5VnAXUloAlTyTosjYxxKdV@Ny8dO0xXVW2gb7CqYktP4XQ0DlnEMkTkfw)

Comment: For 57991 input 1 minute was not sufficient

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 19 bytes

```
.W!/P57H?P_ZtyZ-ZeP
```

**[Verify all the test cases!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.W%21%2FP57H%3FP_ZtyZ-ZeP&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=10%0A74%0A94%0A417%0A991%0A9983&debug=0)**

The [Husk answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145755/59487) inspired me to save 2 bytes (`,3 19` to `P57`).

### How this works

```
.W!/P57H?P_ZtyZ-ZeP  - Full program.

.W                   - Functional while. While A(value) is truthy, value = B(value). Returns the last value.
    P57              - The prime factors of 57 ([3, 19]).
   /   H             - Count the occurences of the current value.
  !                  - Logical NOT. 0 -> Truthy, anything else -> Falsy.
        ?P_Z         - If the current value is prime, then:
            tyZ        - Double the current value, decrement.
               -ZeP    - Else, Subtract the maximal prime factor of the current value from itself.
                     - Print implicitly.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>150</s> 126 bytes

```powershell
for($n="$args";57%$n){$a=$n;$d=for($i=2;$a-gt1){if(!($a%$i)){$i;$a/=$i}else{$i++}};if($n-in$d){$n+=$n-1}else{$n-=$d[-1]}}$n%38
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcxBCsMgFATQszSMoAQpNpQmyD9J6ULQpIL8FC10ETy7ldLlzDzmtX9CLs@QUmvrniWYBri8lcFebwKsDjgCW3j6zZEuFk5vb6OOuMqThBOIqrPY@zMh1pBK6HEca7WdgHVk@C547E/a/AFrgr9r86gVLKa5tbYs8/QF) (warning: slow for bigger numbers)

Iterative method. PowerShell doesn't have any prime factorization built-ins, so this borrows code from my answer on [Prime Factors Buddies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94323/42963).

First is our `for` loop. The setup sets `$n` to be the input value, and the conditional keeps the loop going so long as `57%$n` is non-zero (thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145759/42963) for that trick). Inside the loop we first get a list of prime factors of `$a` (set to `$n`). This is the code borrowed from Prime Factors Buddies. If the input `$a` is already prime, this will return just `$a` (important later). That (potentially just `$a`) gets stored into `$d`.

Next is an `if`/`else` conditional. For the `if` part, we check whether `$n` is `-in` `$d`. If it is, that means that `$n` is prime, so we take `$n=2*$n-1` or `$n+=$n-1`. Otherwise, it's composite, so we need to find the largest prime factor. That means we need to take the last one `[-1]` of `$d` and subtract that from `$n` with `$n-=`. This works because we're looping up from `2` and thus the last element of `$d` is already going to be the largest.

Once we're done looping, we just place `$n%38` (again, thanks Arnauld) on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>113</s> <s>90</s> 59 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9428/when-can-apl-characters-be-counted-as-1-byte-each/9429#9429)

```apl
⎕CY 'dfns'
g←{1pco ⍵:f(2×⍵)-1⋄f⍵-⊃⌽3pco ⍵}
f←{⍵∊3 19:⍵⋄g ⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBI/6pjpHKqinpOUVq3OlP2qbUG1YkJyv8Kh3q1WahtHh6UCGpq7ho@6WNCBL91FX86OevcZQFbVcaSANQNajji5jBUNLKxCzuyUdLAkA)

<s>TIO works with values up to ~3200. Tested on my PC for the last test case. To test on TIO, just add `f value` to the bottom of the code.</s>
Doesn't apply anymore, thanks to @Adám for pointing out that my primality checking algorithm was really bad and supplying me with a replacement; also for the 23 byte save.

Edited to fix byte count.

#### How it works

```apl
⎕CY 'dfns'                      # Imports every Defined Function, which is shorter than importing just the function I used (pco).

g←{1pco ⍵:f(2×⍵)-1⋄f⍵-⊃⌽3pco ⍵} 
g←                              # define g as
   1pco ⍵:                      # if the argument ⍵ is prime
          f(2×⍵)-1              # Call f over 2×⍵-1
                  ⋄f            # else, call f over
                    ⊃           # the first element of the
                      3pco ⍵    # list of prime factors of ⍵
                     ⌽          # reversed

f←{⍵∊3 19:⍵⋄g ⍵}
f←                              # Define f as
   ⍵     :                      # if the argument ⍵
    ∊                           # is in
     3 19                       # the list [3, 19]
          ⍵                     # return the argument ⍵
           ⋄                    # else
            g ⍵                 # call g over the argument ⍵
```

Answer (score 1):

## Axiom, 93 bytes

```
h(n)==(repeat(n=3 or n=19 or n<2=>break;prime? n=>(n:=2*n-1);n:=n-last(factors(n)).factor);n)
```

test:

```
(4) -> [[i,h(i)] for i in [10,74,94,417,991,9983]]
   (4)  [[10,3],[74,19],[94,3],[417,3],[991,19],[9983,19]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
```

There would be 68 bytes function

```
q x==(n<4=>3;n=19=>n;prime? n=>q(2*n-1);q(n-last(factors n).factor))
```

but for n=57991 (if I remember well) it goes out the stack space reserved.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 93 bytes

Port from [TFeld's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145748/66418) without external libs.

```python
n=input()
while~16&n-3:
 f=n;i=2
 while i<f:
	if f%i:i+=1
	else:f/=i
 n-=[1-n,f][f<n]
print n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU67CsJAEKyzX7EEFEWDnglqTq@MrY1dsJC4hwuyOS4nxsZfj6cWU8wM83CvcGtlNTTtlUyapoMYFvcIkyk8b3ynt1qPJcs1oDWyY7MC/OnIe6shYYt2xJpnRkFC9460XRgGlMzUKpO5Pdd2L2dwniWgDHEBIPhXjP5rTv5BkSTUU4PfE0B9Qy5gdTxU3rc@mu7SdYNa5rApoCygUBsoSxWxzT8)