# Minimise the count of prime factors through insertion

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, primes, integer

Given two positive integers **A** and **B**, return the position **p** that *minimises* the number of prime factors (counting multiplicities) of the resulting integer, when **B** is *inserted* in **A** at **p**.

For example, given **A = 1234** and **B = 32**, these are the possible insertions (with **p** being 0-indexed) and the corresponding information about their prime factors:

```
p | Result | Prime factors         | Ω(N) / Count

0 | 321234 | [2, 3, 37, 1447]      | 4
1 | 132234 | [2, 3, 22039]         | 3
2 | 123234 | [2, 3, 19, 23, 47]    | 5
3 | 123324 | [2, 2, 3, 43, 239]    | 5
4 | 123432 | [2, 2, 2, 3, 37, 139] | 6
```

You can see that the result has a minimal number of prime factors, 3, when **p** is 1. So in this particular case, you should output **1**.

#### Specs

- If there are multiple positions **p** that minimise the result, you can choose to output all of them or any one of them.
- You may choose 0-indexing or 1-indexing for **p**, but this choice must be consistent.
- **A** and **B** can be taken as integers, strings or lists of digits.
- You can compete in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/59487) and can take input and provide output through any [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), while taking note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default. This is code-golf, so the shortest submission (scored in bytes) wins!

#### Test cases

```
A, B -> p (0-indexed) / p (1-indexed)

1234, 32           -> 1 / 2
3456, 3            -> 4 / 5
378, 1824          -> 0 / 1
1824, 378          -> 4 / 5
67, 267            -> Any or all among: [1, 2] / [2, 3]
435, 1             -> Any or all among: [1, 2, 3] / [2, 3, 4]
378100, 1878980901 -> Any or all among: [5, 6] / [6, 7]
```

For convenience, here is a list of tuples representing each pair of inputs:

```
[(1234, 32), (3456, 3), (378, 1824), (1824, 378), (67, 267), (435, 1), (378100, 1878980901)]
```

Comment: I get the feeling this is biased towards 05AB1E...

Comment: Can we output the resulting number that has minimized prime factors instead of the index of the insertion? e.g. in your first test case `132234` instead of `1`.

Comment: @dylnan I am going to say no this time.

Answer (score 8):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 16 bytes

```
§◄öLpr§·++⁰↑↓oΘŀ
```

Expects input as strings, [try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9odXNr///Cp@KXhMO2THBywqfCtysr4oGw4oaR4oaTb86YxYD///8iMzIi/yIxMjM0Ig)

#### Explanation

```
§◄(öLpr§·++⁰↑↓)(Θŀ)  -- input A implicit, B as ⁰ (example "1234" and "32")
§ (           )(  )  -- apply A to the two functions and ..
  (ö          )      --   | "suppose we have an argument N" (eg. 2)
  (    §      )      --   | fork A and ..
  (         ↑ )      --     | take N: "12"
  (          ↓)      --     | drop N: "34"
  (     ·++⁰  )      --   | .. join the result by B: "123234"
  (   r       )      --   | read: 123234
  (  p        )      --   | prime factors: [2,3,19,23,47]
  ( L         )      --   | length: 5
  (öLpr§·++⁰↑↓)      --   : function taking N and returning number of factors
                            in the constructed number
               ( ŀ)  --   | range [1..length A]
               (Θ )  --   | prepend 0
               (Θŀ)  --   : [0,1,2,3,4]
 ◄                   -- .. using the generated function find the min over range
```

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 25 bytes

```
sh"2GX@q:&)1GwhhUYfn]v&X<
```

Inputs are strings in reverse order. Output is 1-based. If there is a tie the lowest position is output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vzhDycg9wqHQSk3T0L08IyM0Mi0vtkwtwub/f3VjI3UudUMjYxN1AA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L84Q8nAPcKh0EpN0zDevTwjIzQyLS@2TC3C5r9LyH91YyN1LnVDI2MTIGUMwiamZiARCyOwiLkFnIQKGZmZA0kwYQjEJsamYDlzC0sLA0sDQ4hyQwMDdQA).

#### Explanation

```
s         % Implicitly input B as a string. Sum (of code points). Gives a number
h         % Implicitly input A as a string. Concatenate. Gives a string of length
          % N+1, where N is the length of A
"         % For each (that is, do N+1 times)
  2G      %   Push second input
  X@      %   Push 1-based iteration index
  q       %   Subtract 1
  :       %   Range from 1 to that. Gives [] in the first iteration, [1] in
          %   the second, ..., [1 2 ... N] in the last
  &)      %   Two-output indexing. Gives a substring with the selected elements,
          %   and then a substring with the remaining elements
  1G      %   Push first input
  whh     %   Swap and concatenate twice. This builds the string with B inserted
          %   in A at position given by the iteration index minus 1
  U       %   Convert to string
  Yf      %   Prime factors
  n       %   Number of elements
]         % End
v         % Concatenate stack vertically
&X<       % 1-based index of minimum. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 6):

## Pyth, <s>20</s> <s>13</s> 11 bytes

```
.mlPsXbQzhl
```

[Try it online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.mlPsXbQzhl&input=%22378100%22%0A1878980901%0A&debug=0)

#### Explanation

```
.mlPsXbQzhl
.m    b         Find the minimum value...
         hl     ... over the indices [0, ..., len(first input)]...
  lP            ... of the number of prime factors...
    sX Qz       ... of the second input inserted into the first.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 21 bytes

```
D©L‘Ṭœṗ¥€®żF¥€VÆfL€NM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/l0EqfRw0zHu5cc3Tyw53TDy191LTm0Lqje9zArLDDbWk@QNrP9//h5UcnPdw54/9/Y3MLQwOD/4YW5haWFgaWBoYA)

-1 thanks to [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder).

Returns all possible positions.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>22</s> 21 bytes

This felt far too long as I was writing it up but, looking at some of the other solutions, it actually seems somewhat competitive. Still, there's probably a bit of room for improvement - The `cNq)` in particular is annoying me. Explanation to follow.

Takes the first input as a string and the second as either an integer or a string. Result is 0-indexed and will return the first index if there are multiple solutions.

```
ÊÆiYVÃcNq)®°k Ê
b@e¨X
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=ysZpWVbDY05xKa6wayDKCmJAZahY&input=IjM3ODEwMCIsMTg3ODk4MDkwMQ==)

---

### Explanation

```
      :Implicit input of string U and integer V.
Ê     :Get the length of U.
Æ     :Generate an array of the range [0,length) and map over each element returning ...
iYV   :  U with V inserted at index Y.
Ã     :End mapping
c     :Append ...
Nq    :  The array of inputs joined to a string.
®     :Map over the array.
°     :Postfix increment - casts the current element to an integer.
k     :Get the prime divisors.
Ê     :Get the length.
\n    :The newline allows the array above to be assigned to variable U.
b     :Get the first index in U that returns true ...
@     :  when passed through a function that ...
e     :    checks that every element in U...
¨     :    is greater than or equal to...
X     :    the current element.
      : Implicit output of resulting integer.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 228 bytes

```powershell
param($a,$b)function f($a){for($i=2;$a-gt1){if(!($a%$i)){$i;$a/=$i}else{$i++}}}
$p=@{};,"$b$a"+(0..($x=$a.length-2)|%{-join($a[0..$_++]+$b+$a[$_..($x+1)])})+"$a$b"|%{$p[$i++]=(f $_).count};($p.GetEnumerator()|sort value)[0].Name
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BboMwEETv/QqKNsIrByck7Qkh9VL11h9ACC2RnbgC2wLTViL@dtfNcWaeZsbZHzkvNzmOMTqaaWJAexhQrebitTWZSgZuys4MdHOqgcqrr3DTij2nZAcacQOd/EMDOshxkUlyHkJ4Ate8baHe5zAA5ZwdhWDw2wCJUZqrv5UnvO@28stqk6raFEPPecdh4ElC/8B5hR0G5DkQDHniwbX/A13DVAY9iotdjQ81Ayc@pH836yRn8ukv3hc7@@ybxlVie@zEJ00yxli8nF@LWFTFHw)

*(Seems long / golfing suggestions welcome. Also times out on TIO for the last test case, but the algorithm should work for that case without issue.)*

PowerShell doesn't have any prime factorization built-ins, so this borrows code from my answer on [Prime Factors Buddies](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/94323/42963). That's the first line's `function` declaration.

We take input `$a,$b` and then set `$p` to be an empty hashtable. Next we take the string `$b$a`, turn it into a singleton array with the comma-operator `,`, and array-concatenate that with *stuff*. The *stuff* is a loop through `$a`, inserting `$b` at every point, finally array-concatenated with `$a$b`.

At this point, we have an array of `$b` inserted at every point in `$a`. We then send that array through a for loop `|%{...}`. Each iteration, we insert into our hashtable at position `$i++` the `.count` of how many prime factors `f` that particular element `$_` has.

Finally, we `sort` the hashtable based on `value`s, take the `0`th one thereof, and select its `Name` (i.e., the `$i` of the index). That's left on the pipeline and output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>27</s> 21 bytes

```
ηõ¸ì¹.sRõ¸«)øεIýÒg}Wk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//3PbDWw/tOLzm0E694iAQ89BqzcM7zm31PLz38KT02vDs//8NjYxNuIyNAA)

It returns the lowest 0-indexed *p*.

Thanks to @Emigna for -6 bytes !

#### Explanation

```
ηõ¸ì                  # Push the prefixes of A with a leading empty string -- [, 1, 12, 123, 1234]
    ¹.sRõ¸«)          # Push the suffixes of A with a tailing empty space. -- [1234, 123, 12, 1, ]
            ø         # Zip the prefixes and suffixes
             ε    }   # Map each pair with...
              IýÒg    # Push B, join prefix - B - suffix, map with number of primes
                   Wk # Push the index of the minimum p
```

Comment: Using the same method, you could save 6 bytes by rewriting this as `ηõ¸ì¹.sRõ¸«)øεIýÒg}Wk`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 18 bytes

```
gƒ¹õ«N¹g‚£IýÒg})Wk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v8wNWFiMWX//2fGksK5w7XCq07CuWfigJrCo0nDvcOSZ30pV2v//zEyMzQKMzI)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>165</s> 146 bytes

- Saved nineteen bytes thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer).

```python
O=lambda n:n>1and-~O(n/min(d for d in range(2,n+1)if n%d<1))
def f(A,B):L=[int(A[:j]+B+A[j:])for j in range(len(A)+1)];print L.index(min(L,key=O))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Zc7NbsIwDAfwO09hRZoUq2Fb0vChsm4q50p9gKqHTklGOjCo4jAue/UuKYMeODmKf/7bp8t5dyQ1DFW@bw@fpgXK6F22ZOa/FaeXgyduwB17MOAJ@pa@LFeCEoneAT2ZN4k4M9aB44XYYlbmtaczL@qsa5JtUtRd1mCc76b5vSVeYIhoNqc@aCifPRn7w@O2UnzbS14hDmOPSfjImdg4zqRKNQMQwFIVKs6uQN9BqhfLfxDKHbxOYLWOjQDkWmn2mDB@XxMivYHphuUqBkSg4vMR6HRxWzHeMPwB)

Comment: [146 bytes](https://tio.run/##Zc7NbsIwDAfwO09hRZoUq2Fb0vChsm4q50p9gKqHTklGOjCo4jAue/UuKYMeODmKf/7bp8t5dyQ1DFW@bw@fpgXK6F22ZOa/FaeXgyduwB17MOAJ@pa@LFeCEoneAT2ZN4k4M9aB44XYYlbmtaczL@qsa5JtUtRd1mCc76b5vSVeYIhoNqc@aCifPRn7w@O2UnzbS14hDmOPSfjImdg4zqRKNQMQwFIVKs6uQN9BqhfLfxDKHbxOYLWOjQDkWmn2mDB@XxMivYHphuUqBkSg4vMR6HRxWzHeMPwB)

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>165</s> ... 154 bytes

```
import StdEnv,StdLib
@n h#d=hd[i\\i<-[2..h]|h rem i<1]
|d<h= @(n+1)(h/d)=n
?a b=snd(hd(sort[(@0(toInt(a%(0,i-1)+++b+++a%(i,size a))),i)\\i<-[0..size a]]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY69asQwEIR7P8XiENDin9i@lBbnIikOrrvS50L2OtGCtQ5nJZBwzx5F4BTDMF8xM9MyGwlupc9lBmdYAruP9ebh4ulVvvJoZx6TTsA@kLbU8/XKbdE3ZWmHu4Xb7IDbekju1FoNnZKsRmWfCLUkRwOj3oSUJbXF0l51lfLrSbwyj6rKuagxy7IxKmbON/6ZwSBizrjPVGW5w2FADBdv4jMNR0jr5vCcQnpo0vA7vS3mfQvF6RxevsU4nvawfw8F/cM/)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 16 bytes

```
;ṭJœṖ€$j€¥VÆfẈNM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/64c61XkcnP9w57VHTGpUsIHFoadjhtrSHuzr8fP@7HF5@aKnS0UkPd84AykT@/29oZGyio2BsYmoGJM0tdBQMLYyAAmbmOgomxqZgMUMDg//GRkAmTBKszgikxBAkZG5haWFgaWAIAA)

Takes `A` as a list of digits and returns all 1-indices

### How it works

```
;ṭJœṖ€$j€¥VÆfẈNM - Main link. Takes A on the left and B on the right
;                - Concatenate B to the end of A
         ¥       - Group the previous 2 links into a dyad f(A, B):
      $          -   Group the previous 2 links into a monad g(A):
  J              -     Indices of A; [1, 2, ..., len(A)]
     €           -     Over each index:
   œṖ            -       Partition A at that index
        €        -   Over each partition:
       j         -     Join with B
 ṭ               - Append the concatenated number to the end of this list
          V      - Evaluate each as a number
           Æf    - Calculate the prime factors of each
             ẈN  - Get the lengths of each and negate
               M - Indices of maximal elements, which gives the minimal indices when negated
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 120 bytes

Takes input as 2 strings. Returns a 0-indexed position.

```js
f=(a,b,i=0,m=a)=>a[i>>1]?f(a,b,i+1,eval('for(n=a.slice(0,i)+b+a.slice(i),x=k=2;k<n;n%k?k++:n/=x++&&k);x')<m?(r=i,x):m):r
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(a,b,i=0,m=a)=>a[i>>1]?f(a,b,i+1,eval('for(n=a.slice(0,i)+b+a.slice(i),x=k=2;k<n;n%k?k++:n/=x++&&k);x')<m?(r=i,x):m):r

console.log(f('1234','32'))   // 1
console.log(f('3456','3'))    // 4
console.log(f('378','1824'))  // 0
console.log(f('1824','378'))  // 4
console.log(f('67','267'))    // 1
console.log(f('435','1'))     // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 3, 128 bytes

0-indexed; takes in strings as parameters. -6 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech.

```
from sympy.ntheory import*
def f(n,m):a=[sum(factorint(int(n[:i]+m+n[i:])).values())for i in range(len(n)+1)];return a.index(min(a))
```

Comment: `:\n a` -> `:a`.

Answer (score 0):

## J, 60 Bytes

```
4 :'(i.<./)#@q:>".@(,(":y)&,)&.>/"1({.;}.)&(":x)"0 i.>:#":x'
```

Explicit dyad.
Takes B on the right, A on the left.

0-indexed output.

Might be possible to improve by not using boxes.

#### Explanation:

```
  4 :'(i.<./)#@q:>".@(,(":x)&,)&.>/"1({.;}.)&(":y)"0 i.>:#":y'  | Whole program
  4 :'                                                       '  | Define an explicit dyad
                                                     i.>:#":y   | Integers from 0 to length of y
                                                  "0            | To each element
                                     ({.;}.)&(":y)              | Split y at the given index (result is boxed)
                     (,(":x)&,)&.>/"1                           | Put x inbetween, as a string
                  ".@                                           | Evaluate
                 >                                              | Unbox, makes list
             #@q:                                               | Number of prime factors of each
      (i.>./)                                                   | Index of the minimum
```

Answer (score 0):

**Python, 122 bytes**

```
f=lambda n,i=2:n>1and(n%i and f(n,i+1)or 1+f(n/i,i))
g=lambda A,B:min(range(len(A)+1),key=lambda p:f(int(A[:p]+B+A[p:])))
```

In practice, this exceeds the default max recursion depth pretty quickly.